# How to skip certain database tables with mysqldump?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, dump, database-dump

Is there a way to restrict certain tables from the mysqldump command?

For example, I'd use the following syntax to dump *only* `table1` and `table2`:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database table1 table2 > database.sql
```

But is there a similar way to dump all the tables *except* `table1` and `table2`? I haven't found anything in the mysqldump documentation, so is brute-force (specifying all the table names) the only way to go?

Answer (score 1120, accepted):

You can use the [--ignore-table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table) option. So you could do

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE --ignore-table=DATABASE.table1 > database.sql
```

There is no whitespace after `-p` (this is not a typo).

To ignore multiple tables, use this option multiple times, this is documented to work since [at least version 5.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20151222055612/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table).

If you want an alternative way to ignore multiple tables you can use a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PASSWORD=XXXXXX
HOST=XXXXXX
USER=XXXXXX
DATABASE=databasename
DB_FILE=dump.sql
EXCLUDED_TABLES=(
table1
table2
table3
table4
tableN   
)
 
IGNORED_TABLES_STRING=''
for TABLE in "${EXCLUDED_TABLES[@]}"
do :
   IGNORED_TABLES_STRING+=" --ignore-table=${DATABASE}.${TABLE}"
done

echo "Dump structure"
mysqldump --host=${HOST} --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWORD} --single-transaction --no-data --routines ${DATABASE} > ${DB_FILE}

echo "Dump content"
mysqldump --host=${HOST} --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWORD} ${DATABASE} --no-create-info --skip-triggers ${IGNORED_TABLES_STRING} >> ${DB_FILE}
```

Comment: is there any way to just skip the table contents? the structure i want to backup.

Comment: You can use the --no-data=true option, but I don't know if you can do that on a per table level.

Comment: if the database name is not set for each --ignore-table then you will get a 'Illegal use of option --ignore-table=<database>.<table>' error. Make sure you always declare the database!

Comment: if you want to ignore some tables data, but still dump their structure, you can run mysqldump again fo those tables, and concatenate it onto the backup you just created

Comment: I've been constantly backing up a table that stores deleted info and it's taking up gigabytes of space... the deleted info tables aren't a necessity to backup and when I discovered this trick just now the backups went down to about 2 Megs total.  BEST... TRICK... EVER!

Comment: Is there a reason `--single-transaction` is used on the structure but not data dump?

Comment: *note:*  it is ok, if you add a `--ignore-table=db.table` where the table does not exist

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109993/mysqldump-data-only dump content (second command) should be


`mysqldump --host=${HOST} --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWORD} --no-create-info ${DATABASE} ${IGNORED_TABLES_STRING} >> ${DB_FILE}`

Comment: maybe you will use this instead loop `IGNORED_TABLES_STRING="$(IFS=" "; echo "${EXCLUDED_TABLES[*]/#/--ignore-table=$DATABASE.}")"`

Comment: compressed version, use `| gzip -c > ${DB_FILE}.gz` instead of `> ${DB_FILE}`

Comment: where is that AI? grep `man mysqldump` by `except`, then by `exclude`, but I forgot about `ignore`...

Comment: Instead of building up a bunch of --ignore-table options with a loop, it's much neater to use your shell's expansion. In Bash you could do `--ignore-table=mydb.{table1,table2,table3}`. Note for this to work you need to use `=` between option name and value rather than a space.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me as well. My use case is that I need to dump a db to a file and import it to my local sql server. The db has a few special tables that cannot be directly imported together with the rest in one go. I had to remove `--single-transaction` and `--routines` to get it to work. But it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend passing `--no-create-db` to the second command for data, so the database itself is not tried to be created a second time. Although this is just cosmetic with the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause.

Comment: For security reasons, It's better to leave empty the `-p` parameter so it'll ask that in the console, in this way the password will not be saved in the log of the console

Comment: Don't put passwords on command line or in scripts.  Create .my.cnf file mode 0600 with user = myuser \n password = mypassword.  Then in the command line use **--defaults-file=/home/myuser/.my.cnf** (or whatever).  That keeps your password secure.

Answer (score 173):

Building on the answer from @Brian-Fisher and answering the comments of some of the people on this post, I have a bunch of huge (and unnecessary) tables in my database so I wanted to skip their contents when copying, but keep the structure:

```
mysqldump -h <host> -u <username> -p <database> --no-data > db.sql
mysqldump -h <host> -u <username> -p <database> --no-create-info --skip-triggers --ignore-table=schema.table1 --ignore-table=schema.table2 >> db.sql
```

The resulting file is structurally sound but the dumped data is now ~500MB rather than 9GB, much better for me. I can now import the file into another database for testing purposes without having to worry about manipulating 9GB of data or running out of disk space.

Comment: Tested and used under MySQL 5.5.43 (for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64))
Thanks

Comment: great solution. I had to add  --skip-triggers to the second statement for the dump to work later (assuming you have triggers), but otherwise: perfect

Answer (score 81):

Another example for ignoring multiple tables

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -uUSER -pPASS --ignore-table={db_test.test1,db_test.test3} db_test> db_test.sql
```

using `--ignore-table` and create an array of tables, with syntaxs like

```
--ignore-table={db_test.table1,db_test.table3,db_test.table4}
```

#### **Extra:**

**Import database**

```
 # if file is .sql
 mysql -uUSER  -pPASS db_test < backup_database.sql
 # if file is .sql.gz
 gzip -dc < backup_database.sql.gz | mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD db_test
```

**Simple script to ignore tables and export in .sql.gz to save space**

```
#!/bin/bash

#tables to ignore
_TIGNORE=(
my_database.table1
my_database.table2
my_database.tablex
)

#create text for ignore tables
_TDELIMITED="$(IFS=" "; echo "${_TIGNORE[*]/#/--ignore-table=}")"

#don't forget to include user and password
/usr/bin/mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD --events ${_TDELIMITED} --databases my_database | gzip -v > backup_database.sql.gz
```

**Links with information that will help you**

- [mysqldump & gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278217/mysqldump-gzip-commands-to-properly-create-a-compressed-file-of-a-mysql-databa)
- [mysqldump to a tar.gz](https://serverfault.com/questions/106595/mysqldump-to-a-tar-gz)
- [How do I load a sql.gz file to my database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756585/how-do-i-load-a-sql-gz-file-to-my-database-importing/2756591)

> Note: tested in ubuntu server with mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.55

Comment: Great way to avoid using a script when you want to ignore multiple tables. That answer should receive more "+1"

Comment: My top tip for importing is to use `pv`. e.g. `pv db.sql.zst | unzst | mysql db` (swap out for gzip/xz/...) then you get a visual chart showing progress and ETA

Comment: @artfulrobot yes, you have a progress info, but it last more than without information.

Answer (score 74):

for multiple databases:

```
mysqldump -u user -p --ignore-table=db1.tbl1 --ignore-table=db2.tbl1 --databases db1 db2 ..
```

Comment: There's already a reply to this thread that says that, better.

Comment: Thats right, but this solution works with multiple databases.

Comment: Interesting - I first thought `mysqld` and `mysqldump` would be the same programs.

Comment: that's what i'm looking for - a one-liner answer with the solution which doesn't force me to read something for 2-3mins :P

Answer (score 14):

To exclude some table *data*, but not the table *structure*. Here is how I do it:

Dump the database structure of all tables, without any data:

```
mysqldump -u user -p --no-data database > database_structure.sql
```

Then dump the database with data, except the excluded tables, and do not dump the structure:

```
mysqldump -u user -p --no-create-info \
    --ignore-table=database.table1 \
    --ignore-table=database.table2 database > database_data.sql
```

Then, to load it into a new database:

```
mysql -u user -p newdatabase < database_structure.sql
mysql -u user -p newdatabase < database_data.sql
```

Comment: This is a nice way to do it. Just a quick tip: you could dump the structure to database.sql like you do using `> database.sql` and then for second dump statement simply append to that file using `>> database.sql` instead. That way you have only a single file to import.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `mysqlpump` command with the

```
--exclude-tables=name
```

command. It specifies a comma-separated list of tables to exclude.

Syntax of mysqlpump is very similar to mysqldump, buts its way more performant.
More information of how to use the exclude option you can read here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html#mysqlpump-filtering

Answer (score 1):

I like Rubo77's solution, I hadn't seen it before I modified Paul's. This one will backup a single database, excluding any tables you don't want. It will then gzip it, and delete any files over 8 days old. I will probably use 2 versions of this that do a full (minus logs table) once a day, and another that just backs up the most important tables that change the most every hour using a couple cron jobs.

```
#!/bin/sh
PASSWORD=XXXX
HOST=127.0.0.1
USER=root
DATABASE=MyFavoriteDB

now="$(date +'%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M')"
filename="${DATABASE}_db_backup_$now"
backupfolder="/opt/backups/mysql"
DB_FILE="$backupfolder/$filename"
logfile="$backupfolder/"backup_log_"$(date +'%Y_%m')".txt

EXCLUDED_TABLES=(
logs
)
IGNORED_TABLES_STRING=''
for TABLE in "${EXCLUDED_TABLES[@]}"
do :
   IGNORED_TABLES_STRING+=" --ignore-table=${DATABASE}.${TABLE}"
done

echo "Dump structure started at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')" >> "$logfile"
mysqldump --host=${HOST} --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWORD} --single-transaction --no-data --routines ${DATABASE}  > ${DB_FILE} 
echo "Dump structure finished at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')" >> "$logfile"
echo "Dump content"
mysqldump --host=${HOST} --user=${USER} --password=${PASSWORD} ${DATABASE} --no-create-info --skip-triggers ${IGNORED_TABLES_STRING} >> ${DB_FILE}
gzip ${DB_FILE}

find "$backupfolder" -name ${DATABASE}_db_backup_* -mtime +8 -exec rm {} \;
echo "old files deleted" >> "$logfile"
echo "operation finished at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')" >> "$logfile"
echo "*****************" >> "$logfile"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

For sake of completeness, here is a script which actually could be a one-liner to get a backup from a database, excluding (ignoring) all the views. The db name is assumed to be employees:

```
ignore=$(mysql --login-path=root1 INFORMATION_SCHEMA \
    --skip-column-names --batch \
    -e "select 
          group_concat(
            concat('--ignore-table=', table_schema, '.', table_name) SEPARATOR ' '
          ) 
        from tables 
        where table_type = 'VIEW' and table_schema = 'employees'")

mysqldump --login-path=root1 --column-statistics=0 --no-data employees $ignore > "./backups/som_file.sql"
```

You can update the logic of the query. In general using `group_concat` and `concat` you can generate almost any desired string or shell command.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to use this feature when you don't want or don't have time to deal with a huge table. If this is your case, it's better to use --where option from mysqldump limiting resultset. For example, `mysqldump -uuser -ppass database --where="1 = 1 LIMIT 500000" > resultset.sql`.

Answer (score 0):

**Dump all databases with all tables but skip certain tables**

on github: https://github.com/rubo77/mysql-backup.sh/blob/master/mysql-backup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# mysql-backup.sh

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
  echo
  echo "ERROR: root password Parameter missing."
  exit
fi
DB_host=localhost
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=$1
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
#MYSQL_CONN=""

BACKUP_DIR=/backup/mysql/

mkdir $BACKUP_DIR -p

MYSQLPATH=/var/lib/mysql/

IGNORE="database1.table1, database1.table2, database2.table1,"

# strpos $1 $2 [$3]
# strpos haystack needle [optional offset of an input string]
strpos()
{
    local str=${1}
    local offset=${3}
    if [ -n "${offset}" ]; then
        str=`substr "${str}" ${offset}`
    else
        offset=0
    fi
    str=${str/${2}*/}
    if [ "${#str}" -eq "${#1}" ]; then
        return 0
    fi
    echo $((${#str}+${offset}))
}

cd $MYSQLPATH
for i in */; do
    if [ $i != 'performance_schema/' ] ; then 
    DB=`basename "$i"` 
    #echo "backup $DB->$BACKUP_DIR$DB.sql.lzo"
    mysqlcheck "$DB" $MYSQL_CONN --silent --auto-repair >/tmp/tmp_grep_mysql-backup
    grep -E -B1 "note|warning|support|auto_increment|required|locks" /tmp/tmp_grep_mysql-backup>/tmp/tmp_grep_mysql-backup_not
    grep -v "$(cat /tmp/tmp_grep_mysql-backup_not)" /tmp/tmp_grep_mysql-backup
        
    tbl_count=0
    for t in $(mysql -NBA -h $DB_host $MYSQL_CONN -D $DB -e 'show tables') 
    do
      found=$(strpos "$IGNORE" "$DB"."$t,")
      if [ "$found" == "" ] ; then 
        echo "DUMPING TABLE: $DB.$t"
        mysqldump -h $DB_host $MYSQL_CONN $DB $t --events --skip-lock-tables | lzop -3 -f -o $BACKUP_DIR/$DB.$t.sql.lzo
        tbl_count=$(( tbl_count + 1 ))
      fi
    done
    echo "$tbl_count tables dumped from database '$DB' into dir=$BACKUP_DIR"
    fi
done
```

With a little help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016410/1069083

It uses lzop which is much faster, see:http://pokecraft.first-world.info/wiki/Quick_Benchmark:_Gzip_vs_Bzip2_vs_LZMA_vs_XZ_vs_LZ4_vs_LZO

Comment: Document you share says gzip is faster than lzop.

Answer (score 0):

**Skip certain tables with mysqldump**

Suppose there are some test tables in some databases and you want
to exclude them from the backup; you can specify using the --
exclude-tables option, which will exclude tables with the name
test across all databases:

`shell> mysqldump --exclude-tables=test --resultfile=backup_excluding_test.sql`

Comment: Doesn't look like this is available in later versions. But `--ignore-table=database.table` is.

Answer (score 0):

For example, using [--ignore-table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table), you can export the schema and data of the tables except `person` and `animal` tables of `apple` database to `backup.sql` as shown below. *You must use multiple `--ignore-table` to specify multiple tables and you must specify both a database and a table together `<database>.<table>` for `--ignore-table` otherwise there is error and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77363989#77363989) explains how to export the schema and data of the tables of a database:

```
mysqldump -u john -p apple --ignore-table=apple.person --ignore-table=apple.animal > backup.sql
```

And, using [-B(--database)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases) and `--ignore-table`, you can export the schema and data of `apple` and `orange` databases except `apple` database's `person` table and `orange` database's `animal` table to `backup.sql` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/#77403680) explains how to export the schema and data of multiple databases:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -B apple orange --ignore-table=apple.person --ignore-table=orange.animal > backup.sql
```

And, using [-A(--all-databases)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_all-databases) and `--ignore-table`, you can export the schema and data of all databases except `apple` database's `person` table and `orange` database's `animal` table to `backup.sql` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77417921#77417921) explains how to export the schema and data of all databases:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -A --ignore-table=apple.person --ignore-table=orange.animal > backup.sql
```