# How do I load a sql.gz file to my database? (importing)

Tags: mysql, database

is this right?

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword mydb < myfile.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

No, it isn't. The right way would be

```
zcat myfile.sql.gz | mysql -u root -ppassword mydb
```

Note there can be no space between the `-p` and `password` if using the -p syntax, refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password

Comment: NOTE: the space between -p and password must be removed

Comment: In case you run a limited bash shell (like "git bash", where zcat is missing) you might want to use instead:
`gzip -dc myfile.sql.gz | mysql -u root -ppassword mydb`

Comment: NOTE: please don't put the mysql password in the -p argument as shown before. It may be captured by bash history and pose a security risk on your server.

Comment: Use `mysql mydb -u root -p` to avoid confusion between db name and password

Comment: Also, mydb needs to be created before importing.  This doesn't create the db for you.

Comment: thats why I prefer the `--password=blahblah` syntax.

Comment: -1 for writing the password in the command line. Use `mysql -u root -p mydb` which asks for passwords interactively. So that the password is not saved in bash history.

Answer (score 63):

Use the following command:

```
gunzip < databasefile.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p dbname
```

Comment: This is the best answer, I don't know why it is not getting any upvotes.

Comment: the most coherent reply for me

Answer (score 8):

- You must not use the `password` directly in the terminal, use without it like follows

```
zcat YOUR_FILE.sql.gz | mysql -u YOUR_DB_USERNAME -p YOUR_DATABASE_NAME
```

- Hit enter and when terminal asked for your password, type your password and hope everything will work fine.

Answer (score 8):

Straight and clear:

`gunzip -c myfile.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -ppassword mydb`

-c option for gunzip writes to stdout, keeps original files

NOTE: You shouldn't put the password directly in the command. It's better to provide just -p and than enter the password interactively.

Comment: This is the actual best answer :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For Generating **dbName.sql.gz**

```
mysqldump -u <YOUR USERNAME> -p<YOUR PASSWORD> <YOUR DBNAME> | gzip > ~/mysqlBackup/dbName_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.sql.gz
```

For Loading **dbName.sql.gz**

```
zcat ~/mysqlBackup/<.SQL.GZ file> | mysql -u <YOUR USERNAME> -p<YOUR PASSWORD> <DATABASE NAME IN WHICH YOU WANT TO LOAD>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a **windows** user, I recommend you follow these steps:

1. The first step is to install gzip, I recommend you do it using **Chocolatey**. You can install it via the following link: https://chocolatey.org/install
2. After cholocatey installed, now just install gzip:

   `choco install gzip -y`
3. Once installed, you can now unzip and import your sql.gz files directly into the MySQL prompt with the following command:

   `gzip -cd backup.sql.gz > mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hLOCALHOST DATABASE`

Notes and useful:

- If you want to dump and compress it directly using gzip, just do it using the command below:

  `mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME DATABASE_NAME | gzip -a9 > PATH_TO_SAVE_FILE_SQL_GZ`
- The `-h` parameter in `mysqldump` does not require for using in localhost. Use this for remote MySQL server
- Use in `gzip` the `-9` parameter to the best compression level or `-1` parameter to fast compression.

Answer (score 0):

I have myfile.tar.gz in mysql_daly_backup so it run above like:

```sql
mysqldump -u <YOUR USERNAME> -p<YOUR PASSWORD> <YOUR DBNAME> | gzip > ~/mysqlBackup/dbName_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.tar.gz
```

Comment: mysql -uroot -ppasswd | gzip < ~/mysqlBackup/dbName_date +%Y%m%d%H%M.tar.gz

Answer (score -1):

You have to follow below steps:

- First check Mysql service should be running.
- Then if you have    compressed file, decompress it first.
- Then you    will find .sql file    after decompressing.
- Then find    import data in    left corner in Mysql.
- Select option    import from    self-contained    file and select
  your .sql    file    and specify a new    schema name.
- Then    click    on import data.
- After    importing you    will see    your new schema       in
  available schema    list.