# Check if a Bash array contains a value

Tags: arrays, bash

In Bash, what is the simplest way to test if an array contains a certain value?

Answer (score 881):

This approach has the advantage of not needing to loop over all the elements (at least not explicitly).  But since `array_to_string_internal()` in [array.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/array.c) still loops over array elements and concatenates them into a string, it's probably not more efficient than the looping solutions proposed, but it's more readable.

```
if [[ " ${array[*]} " =~ [[:space:]]${value}[[:space:]] ]]; then
    # whatever you want to do when array contains value
fi

if [[ ! " ${array[*]} " =~ [[:space:]]${value}[[:space:]] ]]; then
    # whatever you want to do when array doesn't contain value
fi
```

Note that in cases where the value you are searching for is one of the words in an array element with spaces, it will give false positives.  For example,

```
array=("Jack Brown")
value="Jack"
```

The regex will see "Jack" as being in the array even though it isn't.  So, you'll have to change `IFS` and the separator characters on your regex if you want still to use this solution, like this.

```
IFS="|"
array=("Jack Brown${IFS}Jack Smith")
value="Jack"

if [[ "${IFS}${array[*]}${IFS}" =~ "${IFS}${value}${IFS}" ]]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi

unset IFS # or set back to original IFS if previously set
```

This will print "false".

Obviously, this can also be used as a test statement, allowing it to be expressed as a one-liner.

```
[[ " ${array[*]} " =~ " ${value} " ]] && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

Since this solution relies on regular expressions to check the array, you must escape any regex characters in the needle. For example, if you were searching with this.

```
array=("valueToBeFound")
value=".*"
```

You would have to set `value` to `\.\*`, otherwise all array elements will be seen to match.

Comment: I added a space at the start of the first regex value match, so that it would only match the word, not something ending in the word.  Works great.  Howver, I don't understand why you use the second condition, wouldn't the first work fine alone?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo I'm not sure I'm following. Are you talking about arrays with dollar literals? If so, just make sure to escape the dollars in the value you're matching against with backslashes.

Comment: If someone wants to check if the element is not in the list without using the else. This will do: if [[  ! " ${arr[@]} " =~ " ${value} " ]]; then ...fi

Comment: Oneliner: 

`[[ " ${branches[@]} " =~ " ${value} " ]] && echo "YES" || echo "NO";`

Comment: Is there a reason you use `${array[@]}` instead of `${array[*]}`? It seems `=~` ends up coalescing the array into a single string anyways, so `*` would probably be more clear.

Comment: I used `@` instead of `*` because it keeps quoted words together, which is particularly useful if you are using a different IFS character.  See the examples at https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-arrays.

Comment: Shellcheck complains about this solution, SC2199 and SC2076. I couldn't fix the warnings without breaking the functionality. Any thoughts about that other than disabling shellcheck for that line?

Comment: [SC2076](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2076) is easy to fix, just remove the double quotes in the `if`. I don't think there's a way to avoid [SC2199](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2199) with this approach. You'd have to explicitly loop though the array, as shown in some of the other solutions, or [ignore](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/Ignore) the warning.

Comment: If the elements in the array might contain spaces, you can do something a little different to protect against that. Here, I use `:` as a safety character instead: `[[ $(printf ':%s:' "${array[@]}") =~ ":value:") ]]`

Comment: Why do you need space or tab wrapping around the matching word?

Comment: To protect against regex matches where your search term is a substring of one of the elements. If you took out the IFS spaces in the if, had something like "Jack Blackstone" in the array, and searched for "Jack Black", you'd still find a match.

Comment: **GOTCHA** This unexpectedly matches filenames which are substrings of other filenames. For example, if your haystack contains `".header"` and your needle is `"ad"` then ad will get matched even though there are no spaces in the filenames.

Comment: @JoshHabdas If that's happening you probably forgot the spaces around the values in quotes (or maybe you're using some other shell that has different behavior than Bash). I tested your scenario with Bash 4.4.12 and it doesn't get matched.

Comment: The literal spaces I did not use though in hindsight it makes sense why they might be required. Tested in GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release.

Comment: there is an issue with this command, if the you are comparing array of strings, with a string as value, and if the value is substring as well as complete string then output will true for both cases. So be aware.

Comment: The last example I have where the IFS character is changed should prevent this. If it's not (because the IFS character is in your haystack), then change IFS to a different character that's not.

Comment: A fuzzy search is too much of a risk if you are doing something important.

Comment: What characteristic of being "important" changes solution feasibility? Maybe I wouldn't use this if values are being provided by a user (depending on how it's used, how the input was sanitized, etc). But otherwise, I don't understand why the "importance" would affect your choice in solution. If there's a reason something is wrong for critical code, then it's always wrong (maybe with the exception of places cryptographically unsafe pseudorandom numbers might be used).

Comment: These array expansions should be using `[*]` instead of `[@]`, and the "spaces" example doesn't really work: `array` only contains one element since `\t` inside quotes is not the same as `$'\t'`. If you change `value` to `Jack Brown` it will print `true` and since there's only one value in the array it should have printed false. Replacing `\t` with an unescaped separator such as comma and removing `unset IFS`, besides fixing `@` vs `*`, will make it work correctly.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral You're right, I should have been using `*` and I did have issues with the tab character. It should still be possible to use that as a separator, but to keep things simple, I just picked another character.

Comment: Can someone explain what =~ exactly does?

Comment: It's a regular expression operator. See https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs.

Comment: I had problems with this approach due to white space characters that where not recognized. Using `[[ " ${array[*]} " =~ [[:space:]]${value}[[:space:]] ]]` solved it for me

Comment: `[[:space:]]${value}[[:space:]]` also fixes the shell check error.

Comment: @EdMorton That's a good point. I've added a note about this limitation.

Comment: I've done [some comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78070423/1765658), your method is the quickest!!

Answer (score 476):

Below is a small function for achieving this. The search string is the first argument and the rest are the array elements:

```
set +e #otherwise the script will exit on error
containsElement () {
  local e match="$1"
  shift
  for e; do [[ "$e" == "$match" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}
```

A test run of that function could look like:

```
$ array=("something to search for" "a string" "test2000")
$ containsElement "a string" "${array[@]}"
$ echo $?
0
$ containsElement "blaha" "${array[@]}"
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Works nicely! I just have to remember to pass the array as with quotes:  `"${array[@]}"`. Otherwise elements containing spaces will break functionality.

Comment: Nice.  I'd call it elementIn() because it checks if the first argument is contained in the second.  containsElements() sounds like the array would go first.  For newbies like me, an example of how to use a function that does not write to stdout in an "if" statement would help: `if elementIn "$table" "${skip_tables[@]}" ; then echo skipping table: ${table}; fi;`  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok I need a bit of explanation here. I don't understand the use of "&&" there.

Take the expression --- for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done ---

Now if you read the test bit and parse it yourself, you start taking the string "a string" and compare it with the first element of the array "something to search for" so that's your first do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] and obviously the output of that condition here is false. Now why telling bash "and return 0" (&& return 0) right after given that the previous "if" control returned false?

Comment: Hope my question makes sense.I understand what that script does but I don't really understand why it actually works.

Comment: @Bluz the && construct is a boolean AND operator. The use of boolean operators creates a boolean statement.Boolean logic says the whole statement can only be true if both the statements before and after the && evaluate to true. This is used as a shortcut insted of and if block.The test is evaluated and if false, there is no need to evaluate the return as it's irrelevant to the whole statement once the test has failed and is therefore not run. If the test is successfull then the sucess of the boolean statement DOES require the outcome of the return to be determined so the code is run.

Comment: after a lot of efforts, I wasn't able to get it work. It stopped my script whatever I did.

Comment: Thanks, sorted my problem out...Although, IMO you have the return  "0" and "1" the wrong way around. Return 1 if true/found in array in loop, else was not found in array within the loop so return 0  ;) (Or call the function "notContainsElement"

Comment: @James by convention the success code in bash is "0" and error is everything >= 1. This is why it returns 0 on success. :)

Comment: The below post was helpful to me when attempting to use the above function. Changing it to a index style loop would likely make it bullet proof. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084257/bash-array-with-spaces-in-elements#9084479

Comment: A more robust system would be to pass the array _name_, and then use indirection inside the function: for e in "${!2[@]}" ; do ...

Comment: Ignore my comment above: ${!name[@]} does something wildly different in bash.

Comment: The 0/1 convention is there so you can do this: `if containsElement "a string" "${array[@]}"; then echo "found it" ; else echo "didn't find it" ; fi`

Comment: @ChrisCogdon good idea - I got redirection to work by using another var in the function - `arr="$2[@]"` appends the array expansion to the passed-in array name, and then `for e in ${!arr}` iterates through the actual expanded array

Comment: But note that indirection like that confuses [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) _a little_ ([SC2034](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/Sc2034#exceptions)), so I ended up using that only where I use the array somewhere else as well - otherwise for one-time checks I use `elementIn` (renamed as suggested by @GlenPeterson above)

Comment: It also seems to sort-of work if you just provide the name with the expansion appended already - `containsElement ARRAY_NAME[@] match_val`, but this doesn't seem to work with things like `ARRAY_NAME[@]:3` (limiting the scope of the search in the array), so maybe it's best not to even allow that option...

Comment: Sorry for refloating this, but I'm using this code and works really well in a script to delete git branches, but now I want to refactor a bit and I'm not quite understanding the role of e, can someone please expand on this? Thanks!

Comment: @MauricioMachado `$e` is quite simply the element in the array against which you try to match the variable `$match` at the moment. (I keep coming back to this answer like twice a year. Excellent!)

Comment: I ve been trying to get my head around the `local e match=$1 shift` and `for e` but still can't understand how it works.

Comment: @Stelios `shift` shifts the argument list by 1 to the left (dropping the first argument) and `for` without an `in` implicitly iterates over the argument list.

Comment: The code is working like a charm and it is simple yet elegant. However, I don't understand one thing. I'm executing "echo $e" before the for loop and it appears to be empty as expected. How does for loop know it should traverse $1 which is the array after shift operation? Is it just supposed to read $1 argument out of nowhere? What am I missing here?

Comment: I prefer this to the [[ " ${array[@]} " =~ " ${value} " ]]; @Keegan solution below as does not appear sensitive to spaces (as thoughtfully pointed out by Keegan in his approach)

Comment: despite the comment by @Christian, i still don't understand how `e` is supposed to contain positional parameter indexes >1. i know what `shift` does, but nothing is actually looping over `$@` to add each parameter to `$e`. also, the function doesn't seem to work on bash v5.1

Comment: @ErinSchoonover `for` is implicitly looping over `"$@"` if no `in` part is specified. Yes, I'd call that a questionable syntactic shortcut but it is what it is.

Comment: @Christian Thank you! Running this through a shell after setting debugging mode (`set -x`), I can see that `for` is doing just what you say: `- for e in "$@"`

Comment: @Christian Do we need to declare `e`? I just ran `for elem; do [[ "$elem" == "$match" ]] && return 0; done` which worked fine. That variable `e` seems confusing at first sight.

Comment: @Burak No, variables never have to be defined but declaring them as `local` gives them a local scope.

Comment: This one didn't work for me as I had `set -e` so it would automatically exist the script is there wasn't a match.

Comment: What a bizarre and inverted logic! An boolean indicator function that returns 0 if a question is answered true (contains element?), and zero if not. Aren't you getting confused with the traditional bash codes: "no error=0, error=2" code?

Answer (score 147):

## One-line solution

```bash
printf '%s\0' "${myarray[@]}" | grep -F -x -z -- 'myvalue'
```

---

**Explanation**

The `printf` statement prints each element of the array, delimited by null characters.

The `grep` statement uses the following flags to match an item that contains *exactly* the string given as `myvalue` (no more, no less):

- `-z`/`--null-data` - Lines are terminated by a zero byte instead of a newline.
- `-F`/`--fixed-strings` - Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, not regular expressions.
- `-x`/`--line-regexp` - Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.
- `--` - marks the end of command-line options, making Grep process "`myvalue`" as a non-option argument even if it starts with a dash

Why do we use a null byte `\0` instead of a newline `\n`? Your array may actually contain newlines within its elements. (If you know that it doesn't, feel free to drop the `-z` grep option and substitude `%s\n` as your first printf arg.)

---

**Usage**

To put this into an `if ... then` statement:

```
if printf '%s\0' "${myarray[@]}" | grep -Fxqz -- 'myvalue'; then
    # ...
fi
```

I added a `-q` flag to the `grep` expression so that it won't print matches; it will just treat the existence of a match as "true."

**Update**: Thanks, presto8, for pointing out the `--line-regexp` flag. Thanks, Tino, for pointing out the case where newlines can exist within array items.

Comment: Nice solution! On GNU grep, there is also "--line-regexp" which could replace "-P" and the ^ and $ in the pattern: printf '%s\n' ${myarray[@]} | grep -q --line-regexp 'mypattern'

Comment: As great as this is, it doesn't work if the array values have spaces.

Comment: @Fmstrat I think you'll find that it does work in bash even if array values have spaces. 1. Did you specify `"${myarray[@]}"` with quotes? 2. Have you used `echo "${#myarray[@]}"` to verify that your array itself has the number of items you expect (and doesn't think that the spaces are separating items)?

Comment: wrong!  **your answer fasely returns `true`** for `myarray=($'not\nmypattern')` .  Following fixes that but needs a recent version of `grep` (which groks `-z`) and also correctly works for any `$mypattern` you might think of: `printf '%s\0' "${myarray[@]}" | grep -Fqxz -- "$mypattern"`

Comment: @Tino do you think you could express that correction in a polite way that improves the community?

Comment: A full example would be better. For example input and output etc.

Comment: Huge +1 :-)
`grep -P` only works on Linux using GNU tools, not on macOS / BSD; this can easily be worked around, though: install [brew](https://brew.sh) --> `brew install grep`

Comment: Associative arrays may give you unexpected problems, like false positives.

Comment: This solutions works very well and is elegant. In my issue, I have a list of files (arbitrary strings, lot's of spaces) so the simple `echo "${files[@]}" | grep "$element"` was enough. Excellent results.

Answer (score 76):

```
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    if [ "$i" -eq "$yourValue" ] ; then
        echo "Found"
    fi
done
```

For strings:

```
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    if [ "$i" == "$yourValue" ] ; then
        echo "Found"
    fi
done
```

Comment: That said, you can use an indexed for loop and avoid getting killed when an array element contains IFS: for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#array[@]} ; i++ ))

Comment: @Matt: You have to be careful using `${#}` since Bash supports sparse arrays.

Comment: @Paolo, if your array contains a space then just compare it as a string. a space is a string as well.

Comment: @Paolo: You can make that a function, but arrays can't be passed as arguments so you'll have to treat it as a global.

Comment: Dennis is right. From the bash reference manual: "If the word is double-quoted, ... ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a separate word"

Comment: I was pretty much sticking with the question, which said 'simplest'. This might not be the most efficient or best

Comment: I think after echo "Found"; we can add break;

Comment: Although you can't pass an array to a function, you can still pass all elements correctly quoted using the `[@]` syntax and achieve the same effect. The first argument is the string of interest and all the other args are the elements in the array. Such function can be called as follows: `array_contains foo "${the_array[@]}"`. Inside the function, fetch the first argument in a local variable, then do a `shift 1` and `"$@"` will contain exactly the elements of the original array.

Answer (score 57):

```
$ myarray=(one two three)
$ case "${myarray[@]}" in  *"two"*) echo "found" ;; esac
found
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't iterate over each element in the array separately... instead it simply concatenates the array and matches "two" as a substring. This could cause undesirable behavior if one is testing whether the exact word "two" is an element in the array.

Comment: I thought this was going to work for me in comparing file types but found that as the counters increased it was counting up too many values... boo!

Comment: wrong! Reason: ```case "${myarray[@]}" in  *"t"*) echo "found" ;; esac``` outputs: `found`

Comment: @MartyMacGyver, could you please have look on my addition to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52414872/1619950

Answer (score 44):

I typically just use:

```
inarray=$(echo ${haystack[@]} | grep -o "needle" | wc -w)
```

non zero value indicates a match was found.

... actually, to solve the problem mentioned with it not working with needle1 and needle2, if you only want an exact match, nothing more, nothing less, just add a `w` flag after the `-o` for a whole word match:

```
inarray=$(echo ${haystack[@]} | grep -ow "needle" | wc -w)
```

Comment: True, this is definitely the easiest solution - should be marked answer in my opinion. At least have my upvote! [:

Comment: That won't work for similar needles.  For example, `haystack=(needle1 needle2); echo ${haystack[@]} | grep -o "needle" | wc -w`

Comment: Very true. joining with a delimiter not present in any element and adding it to the needle would help with that. Maybe something like...
(untested)
`inarray=$(printf ",%s" "${haystack[@]}") | grep -o ",needle" | wc -w)`

Comment: Using grep -x would avoid false positives: 

`inarray=$(printf ",%s" "${haystack[@]}") | grep -x "needle" | wc -l`

Comment: Perhaps simply `inarray=$(echo " ${haystack[@]}" | grep -o " needle" | wc -w)` as -x causes grep to try and match the entire input string

Comment: awesome variable names, loved it :)

Comment: if you like me were overwhelmed by all the answers and their length then try this one as the one I ended up using cause it was a one liner and easy to understand and implement in a conditional.

Answer (score 25):

If you need performance, you don't want to loop over your whole array every time you search.

In this case, you can create an associative array (hash table, or dictionary) that represents an index of that array. I.e. it maps each array element into its index in the array:

```shell
make_index () {
  local index_name=$1
  shift
  local -a value_array=("$@")
  local i
  # -A means associative array, -g means create a global variable:
  declare -g -A ${index_name}
  for i in "${!value_array[@]}"; do
    eval ${index_name}["${value_array[$i]}"]=$i
  done
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```shell
myarray=('a a' 'b b' 'c c')
make_index myarray_index "${myarray[@]}"
```

And test membership like so:

```shell
member="b b"
# the "|| echo NOT FOUND" below is needed if you're using "set -e"
test "${myarray_index[$member]}" && echo FOUND || echo NOT FOUND
```

Or also:

```shell
if [ "${myarray_index[$member]}" ]; then 
  echo FOUND
fi
```

Notice that this solution does the right thing even if the there are spaces in the tested value or in the array values.

As a bonus, you also get the index of the value within the array with:

```shell
echo "<< ${myarray_index[$member]} >> is the index of $member"
```

Comment: +1 for the idea that you should be using an associative array. I think the code for `make_index` is a bit more contrived due to the indirection; you could have used a fixed array name with a much simpler code.

Comment: I like this the best - dictionaries are more efficient than linear search, and the solution uses Bash internal tools without external processes such as "grep" and "wc" like other solutions.

Answer (score 21):

Another one liner without a function:

```
(for e in "${array[@]}"; do [[ "$e" == "searched_item" ]] && exit 0; done) && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

Thanks @Qwerty for the heads up regarding spaces!

corresponding function:

```
find_in_array() {
  local word=$1
  shift
  for e in "$@"; do [[ "$e" == "$word" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}
```

example:

```
some_words=( these are some words )
find_in_array word "${some_words[@]}" || echo "expected missing! since words != word"
```

Comment: Why do we need a subshell here?

Comment: @codeforester this is old... but as it was written you need it in order to break from it, that's what the `exit 0` does (stops asap if found).

Comment: The end of the one liner should be `|| echo not found` instead of `|| not found` or the shell will try to execute a command by the name of *not* with argument *found* if the requested value is not in the array.

Answer (score 15):

## How to check if a Bash Array contains a value

---

### False positive match

```
array=(a1 b1 c1 d1 ee)

[[ ${array[*]} =~ 'a' ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
# output:
yes

[[ ${array[*]} =~ 'a1' ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
# output:
yes

[[ ${array[*]} =~ 'e' ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
# output:
yes

[[ ${array[*]} =~ 'ee' ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
# output:
yes
```

### Exact match

In order to look for an exact match, your regex pattern needs to add extra space before and after the value like `(^|[[:space:]])"VALUE"($|[[:space:]])`

```
# Exact match

array=(aa1 bc1 ac1 ed1 aee)

if [[ ${array[*]} =~ (^|[[:space:]])"a"($|[[:space:]]) ]]; then
    echo "Yes";
else
    echo "No";
fi
# output:
No

if [[ ${array[*]} =~ (^|[[:space:]])"ac1"($|[[:space:]]) ]]; then
    echo "Yes";
else
    echo "No";
fi
# output:
Yes

find="ac1"
if [[ ${array[*]} =~ (^|[[:space:]])"$find"($|[[:space:]]) ]]; then
    echo "Yes";
else
    echo "No";
fi
# output:
Yes
```

For more usage examples the source of examples are [here](https://www.mybluelinux.com/bash-guide-to-bash-arrays/#bash_array_contains_a_value_exact_match)

Comment: -1 as complete fail for `array=('not act1')`.  Such wrong implementations even created major PITA in the past:  A security adapter gets a list of all files in a directory and returns if access to the directory is allowed.  Directories with `dir_protect` are protected.  As uploads in directories always append an extension, you are safe, right?  A hacker uploads `dir_protect hack.txt` (with a space in it, as spaces are common in Windows) and thus creates a DoS (the security adapter has no direct access to the directory, only to the list of files transferred).

Comment: There are many answers but there is only a few with input and output. Thanks for sharing your sample with input output.

Comment: If your target array is associative, you may have an issue.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to do a quick and dirty test to see if it's worth iterating over the whole array to get a precise match, Bash can treat arrays like scalars. Test for a match in the scalar, if none then skipping the loop saves time. Obviously you can get false positives.

```
array=(word "two words" words)
if [[ ${array[@]} =~ words ]]
then
    echo "Checking"
    for element in "${array[@]}"
    do
        if [[ $element == "words" ]]
        then
            echo "Match"
        fi
    done
fi
```

This will output "Checking" and "Match". With `array=(word "two words" something)` it will only output "Checking". With `array=(word "two widgets" something)` there will be no output.

Comment: Why not just replace `words` with a regex `^words$` that matches only the entire string, which completely eliminates the need for checking each item individually?

Comment: @DejayClayton: Because `pattern='^words$'; if [[ ${array[@]} =~ $pattern ]]` will never match since it's checking the _whole_ array at once as if it were a scalar. The individual checks in my answer are to be done only if there's a reason to proceed based on the rough match.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to do.  I've proposed a variant answer that's more performant and secure.

Answer (score 12):

```
containsElement () { for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" = "$1" ]] && return 0; done; return 1; }
```

*Now* handles empty arrays correctly.

Comment: How is this different than @patrik's answer? The only difference I see is `"$e" = "$1"` (instead of `"$e" == "$1"`) which looks like a bug.

Comment: It is not. @patrik's merged my comment in his original answer back then (patch #4). Note: `"e" == "$1"` is syntactically clearer.

Comment: @CivFan In its current form this is shorter than the one in patrik's answer, because of the elegant ${@:2} and the self documenting $1. I would add that quoting is not necessary within [[ ]].

Answer (score 11):

Here is a small contribution :

```
array=(word "two words" words)  
search_string="two"  
match=$(echo "${array[@]:0}" | grep -o $search_string)  
[[ ! -z $match ]] && echo "found !"
```

Note: this way doesn't distinguish the case "two words" but this is not required in the question.

Comment: The question didn't explicitly say you had to give the correct answer but I think that's implicit in the question...

The array doesn't contain the value "two".

Comment: The above will report a match for 'rd'.

Answer (score 9):

```
a=(b c d)

if printf '%s\0' "${a[@]}" | grep -Fqxz c
then
  echo 'array “a” contains value “c”'
fi
```

If you prefer you can use equivalent long options:

```
--fixed-strings --quiet --line-regexp --null-data
```

Comment: This doesn't work with BSD-grep on Mac, as there is no --null-data. :(

Comment: Correct, but you should use `grep -Fqxz -- c` in case `c` is replaced with something starting with `-`.

Answer (score 9):

**Here's a compilation of several possible implementations, complete with integrated verification and simple benchmarking (requires Bash >= 4.0):**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Check if array contains item [$1: item, $2: array name]
function in_array_1() {
    local needle="$1" item
    local -n arrref="$2"
    for item in "${arrref[@]}"; do
        [[ "${item}" == "${needle}" ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

# Check if array contains item [$1: item, $2: array name]
function in_array_2() {
    local needle="$1" arrref="$2[@]" item
    for item in "${!arrref}"; do
        [[ "${item}" == "${needle}" ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

# Check if array contains item [$1: item, $2: array name]
function in_array_3() {
    local needle="$1" i
    local -n arrref="$2"
    for ((i=0; i < ${#arrref[@]}; i++)); do
        [[ "${arrref[i]}" == "${needle}" ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

# Check if array contains item [$1: item, $2..$n: array items]
function in_array_4() {
    local needle="$1" item
    shift
    for item; do
        [[ "${item}" == "${needle}" ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

# Check if array contains item [$1: item, $2..$n: array items]
function in_array_5() {
    local needle="$1" item
    for item in "${@:2}"; do
        [[ "${item}" == "${needle}" ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

# Check if array contains item [$1: item, $2: array name]
function in_array_6() {
    local needle="$1" arrref="$2[@]" array i
    array=("${!arrref}")
    for ((i=0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++)); do
        [[ "${array[i]}" == "${needle}" ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

# Check if array contains item [$1: item, $2..$n: array items]
function in_array_7() {
    local needle="$1" array=("${@:2}") item
    for item in "${array[@]}"; do
        [[ "${item}" == "${needle}" ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

# Check if array contains item [$1: item, $2..$n: array items]
function in_array_8() {
    local needle="$1"
    shift
    while (( $# > 0 )); do
        [[ "$1" == "${needle}" ]] && return 0
        shift
    done
    return 1
}


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# Generate map for array [$1: name of source array, $2: name of target array]
# NOTE: target array must be pre-declared by caller using 'declare -A <name>'
function generate_array_map() {
    local -n srcarr="$1" dstmap="$2"
    local i key
    dstmap=()
    for i in "${!srcarr[@]}"; do
        key="${srcarr[i]}"
        [[ -z ${dstmap["${key}"]+set} ]] && dstmap["${key}"]=${i} || dstmap["${key}"]+=,${i}
    done
}

# Check if array contains item [$1: item, $2: name of array map]
function in_array_9() {
    local needle="$1"
    local -n mapref="$2"
    [[ -n "${mapref["${needle}"]+set}" ]] && return 0 || return 1
}


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# Test in_array function [$1: function name, $2: function description, $3: test array size]
function test() {
    local tname="$1" tdesc="$2" tn=$3 ti=0 tj=0 ta=() tct=0 tepapre="" tepapost="" tepadiff=()
    local -A tam=()

    echo -e "\e[1m${tname} (${tdesc}):\e[0m"

    # Generate list of currently defined variables
    tepapre="$(compgen -v)"

    # Fill array with random items
    for ((ti=0; ti < ${tn}; ti++)); do
        ta+=("${RANDOM} ${RANDOM} ${RANDOM} ${RANDOM}")
    done

    # Determine function call type (pass array items, pass array name, pass array map)
    case "${tname}" in
        "in_array_1"|"in_array_2"|"in_array_3"|"in_array_6") tct=0; ;;
        "in_array_4"|"in_array_5"|"in_array_7"|"in_array_8") tct=1; ;;
        "in_array_9") generate_array_map ta tam; tct=2; ;;
        *) echo "Unknown in_array function '${tname}', aborting"; return 1; ;;
    esac

    # Verify in_array function is working as expected by picking a few random
    # items and checking
    echo -e "\e[1mVerification...\e[0m"
    for ((ti=0; ti < 10; ti++)); do
        tj=$(( ${RANDOM} % ${#ta[@]} ))
        echo -n "Item ${tj} '${ta[tj]}': "
        if (( ${tct} == 0 )); then
            "${tname}" "${ta[tj]}" ta && echo -en "\e[1;32mok\e[0m" || echo -en "\e[1;31mnok\e[0m"
            echo -n " "
            "${tname}" "${ta[tj]}.x" ta && echo -en "\e[1;31mnok\e[0m" || echo -en "\e[1;32mok\e[0m"
        elif (( ${tct} == 1 )); then
            "${tname}" "${ta[tj]}" "${ta[@]}" && echo -en "\e[1;32mok\e[0m" || echo -en "\e[1;31mnok\e[0m"
            echo -n " "
            "${tname}" "${ta[tj]}.x" "${ta[@]}" && echo -en "\e[1;31mnok\e[0m" || echo -en "\e[1;32mok\e[0m"
        elif (( ${tct} == 2 )); then
            "${tname}" "${ta[tj]}" tam && echo -en "\e[1;32mok\e[0m" || echo -en "\e[1;31mnok\e[0m"
            echo -n " "
            "${tname}" "${ta[tj]}.x" tam && echo -en "\e[1;31mnok\e[0m" || echo -en "\e[1;32mok\e[0m"
        fi
        echo
    done

    # Benchmark in_array function
    echo -en "\e[1mBenchmark...\e[0m"
    time for ((ti=0; ti < ${#ta[@]}; ti++)); do
        if (( ${tct} == 0 )); then
            "${tname}" "${ta[ti]}" ta
        elif (( ${tct} == 1 )); then
            "${tname}" "${ta[ti]}" "${ta[@]}"
        elif (( ${tct} == 2 )); then
            "${tname}" "${ta[ti]}" tam
        fi
    done

    # Generate list of currently defined variables, compare to previously
    # generated list to determine possible environment pollution
    echo -e "\e[1mEPA test...\e[0m"
    tepapost="$(compgen -v)"
    readarray -t tepadiff < <(echo -e "${tepapre}\n${tepapost}" | sort | uniq -u)
    if (( ${#tepadiff[@]} == 0 )); then
        echo -e "\e[1;32mclean\e[0m"
    else
        echo -e "\e[1;31mpolluted:\e[0m ${tepadiff[@]}"
    fi

    echo
}


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# Test in_array functions
n=5000
echo
( test in_array_1 "pass array name, nameref reference, for-each-loop over array items" ${n} )
( test in_array_2 "pass array name, indirect reference, for-each-loop over array items" ${n} )
( test in_array_3 "pass array name, nameref reference, c-style for-loop over array items by index" ${n} )
( test in_array_4 "pass array items, for-each-loop over arguments" ${n} )
( test in_array_5 "pass array items, for-each-loop over arguments as array" ${n} )
( test in_array_6 "pass array name, indirect reference + array copy, c-style for-loop over array items by index" ${n} )
( test in_array_7 "pass array items, copy array from arguments as array, for-each-loop over array items" ${n} )
( test in_array_8 "pass array items, while-loop, shift over arguments" ${n} )
( test in_array_9 "pre-generated array map, pass array map name, direct test without loop" ${n} )
```

**Results:**

```
in_array_1 (pass array name, nameref reference, for-each-loop over array items):
Verification...
Item 862 '19528 10140 12669 17820': ok ok
Item 2250 '27262 30442 9295 24867': ok ok
Item 4794 '3857 17404 31925 27993': ok ok
Item 2532 '14553 12282 26511 32657': ok ok
Item 1911 '21715 8066 15277 27126': ok ok
Item 4289 '3081 10265 16686 19121': ok ok
Item 4837 '32220 1758 304 7871': ok ok
Item 901 '20652 23880 20634 14286': ok ok
Item 2488 '14578 8625 30251 9343': ok ok
Item 4165 '4514 25064 29301 7400': ok ok
Benchmark...
real    1m11,796s
user    1m11,262s
sys     0m0,473s
EPA test...
clean

in_array_2 (pass array name, indirect reference, for-each-loop over array items):
Verification...
Item 2933 '17482 25789 27710 2096': ok ok
Item 3584 '876 14586 20885 8567': ok ok
Item 872 '176 19749 27265 18038': ok ok
Item 595 '6597 31710 13266 8813': ok ok
Item 748 '569 9200 28914 11297': ok ok
Item 3791 '26477 13218 30172 31532': ok ok
Item 2900 '3059 8457 4879 16634': ok ok
Item 676 '23511 686 589 7265': ok ok
Item 2248 '31351 7961 17946 24782': ok ok
Item 511 '8484 23162 11050 426': ok ok
Benchmark...
real    1m11,524s
user    1m11,086s
sys     0m0,437s
EPA test...
clean

in_array_3 (pass array name, nameref reference, c-style for-loop over array items by index):
Verification...
Item 1589 '747 10250 20133 29230': ok ok
Item 488 '12827 18892 31996 1977': ok ok
Item 801 '19439 25243 24485 24435': ok ok
Item 2588 '17193 18893 21610 9302': ok ok
Item 4436 '7100 655 8847 3068': ok ok
Item 2620 '19444 6457 28835 24717': ok ok
Item 4398 '4420 16336 612 4255': ok ok
Item 2430 '32397 2402 12631 29774': ok ok
Item 3419 '906 5361 32752 7698': ok ok
Item 356 '9776 16485 20838 13330': ok ok
Benchmark...
real    1m17,037s
user    1m17,019s
sys     0m0,005s
EPA test...
clean

in_array_4 (pass array items, for-each-loop over arguments):
Verification...
Item 1388 '7932 15114 4025 15625': ok ok
Item 3900 '23863 25328 5632 2752': ok ok
Item 2678 '31296 4216 17485 8874': ok ok
Item 1893 '16952 29047 29104 23384': ok ok
Item 1616 '19543 5999 4485 22929': ok ok
Item 93 '14456 2806 12829 19552': ok ok
Item 265 '30961 19733 11863 3101': ok ok
Item 4615 '10431 9566 25767 13518': ok ok
Item 576 '11726 15104 11116 74': ok ok
Item 3829 '19371 25026 6252 29478': ok ok
Benchmark...
real    1m30,912s
user    1m30,740s
sys     0m0,011s
EPA test...
clean

in_array_5 (pass array items, for-each-loop over arguments as array):
Verification...
Item 1012 '29213 31971 21483 30225': ok ok
Item 2802 '4079 5423 29240 29619': ok ok
Item 473 '6968 798 23936 6852': ok ok
Item 2183 '20734 4521 30800 2126': ok ok
Item 3059 '14952 9918 15695 19309': ok ok
Item 1424 '25784 28380 14555 21893': ok ok
Item 1087 '16345 19823 26210 20083': ok ok
Item 257 '28890 5198 7251 3866': ok ok
Item 3986 '29035 19288 12107 3857': ok ok
Item 2509 '9219 32484 12842 27472': ok ok
Benchmark...
real    1m53,485s
user    1m53,404s
sys     0m0,077s
EPA test...
clean

in_array_6 (pass array name, indirect reference + array copy, c-style for-loop over array items by index):
Verification...
Item 4691 '25498 10521 20673 14948': ok ok
Item 263 '25265 29824 3876 14088': ok ok
Item 2550 '2416 14274 12594 29740': ok ok
Item 2269 '2769 11436 3622 28273': ok ok
Item 3246 '23730 25956 3514 17626': ok ok
Item 1059 '10776 12514 27222 15640': ok ok
Item 53 '23813 13365 16022 4092': ok ok
Item 1503 '6593 23540 10256 17818': ok ok
Item 2452 '12600 27404 30960 26759': ok ok
Item 2526 '21190 32512 23651 7865': ok ok
Benchmark...
real    1m54,793s
user    1m54,326s
sys     0m0,457s
EPA test...
clean

in_array_7 (pass array items, copy array from arguments as array, for-each-loop over array items):
Verification...
Item 2212 '12127 12828 27570 7051': ok ok
Item 1393 '19552 26263 1067 23332': ok ok
Item 506 '18818 8253 14924 30710': ok ok
Item 789 '9803 1886 17584 32686': ok ok
Item 1795 '19788 27842 28044 3436': ok ok
Item 376 '4372 16953 17280 4031': ok ok
Item 4846 '19130 6261 21959 6869': ok ok
Item 2064 '2357 32221 22682 5814': ok ok
Item 4866 '10928 10632 19175 14984': ok ok
Item 1294 '8499 11885 5900 6765': ok ok
Benchmark...
real    2m35,012s
user    2m33,578s
sys     0m1,433s
EPA test...
clean

in_array_8 (pass array items, while-loop, shift over arguments):
Verification...
Item 134 '1418 24798 20169 9501': ok ok
Item 3986 '12160 12021 29794 29236': ok ok
Item 1607 '26633 14260 18227 898': ok ok
Item 2688 '18387 6285 2385 18432': ok ok
Item 603 '1421 306 6102 28735': ok ok
Item 625 '4530 19718 30900 1938': ok ok
Item 4033 '9968 24093 25080 8179': ok ok
Item 310 '6867 9884 31231 29173': ok ok
Item 661 '3794 4745 26066 22691': ok ok
Item 4129 '3039 31766 6714 4921': ok ok
Benchmark...
real    5m51,097s
user    5m50,566s
sys     0m0,495s
EPA test...
clean

in_array_9 (pre-generated array map, pass array map name, direct test without loop):
Verification...
Item 3696 '661 6048 13881 26901': ok ok
Item 815 '29729 13733 3935 20697': ok ok
Item 1076 '9220 3405 18448 7240': ok ok
Item 595 '8912 2886 13678 24066': ok ok
Item 2803 '13534 23891 5344 652': ok ok
Item 1810 '12528 32150 7050 1254': ok ok
Item 4055 '21840 7436 1350 15443': ok ok
Item 2416 '19550 28434 17110 31203': ok ok
Item 1630 '21054 2819 7527 953': ok ok
Item 1044 '30152 22211 22226 6950': ok ok
Benchmark...
real    0m0,128s
user    0m0,128s
sys     0m0,000s
EPA test...
clean
```

Comment: Worth to note, that pure putting of array to /dev/null with echo takes about half of the in_array_1 function. Also the solution which uses printf and grep (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47541882/31086, but adopted to be compatible with this benchmark) is only tiny bit faster than in_array_1

Comment: Timing of `generate_array_map`?

Comment: It gives error in this line readarray -t tepadiff < <(echo -e "${tepapre}\n${tepapost}" | sort | uniq -u)

Comment: @oiyio: what does the error message say? Are you using a very old Bash version (< 4.0)?

Comment: @Tino: negligible (<1s). If you are curious, just put 'time' before the call in function 'test'.

Comment: Yes, my bash version is 3.2.57

Comment: @oiyio: that version doesn't support readarray, namerefs etc. Script will only work with Bash >= 4.0.

Comment: So which one is the fastest? Could you kindly add some interpretation or results summary?

Comment: @KamilCuk: it's already there, have a look at the times within the results (i.e. lines below 'Benchmark...', lower is better). Functions `in_array_1` and `in_array_2` are pretty fast, if you are looking for a traditional solution. Of course, `in_array_9` is the fastest solution by far, but requires a pre-generated map. Note that performance might vary between different systems and/or Bash versions. It might be best to run the script yourself and check the results for your specific setup.

Answer (score 7):

Borrowing from [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3686262/111948), the following solution combines arrays, shell-safe quoting, and regular expressions to avoid the need for: iterating over loops; using pipes or other sub-processes; or using non-bash utilities.

```
declare -a array=('hello, stack' one 'two words' words last)
printf -v array_str -- ',,%q' "${array[@]}"

if [[ "${array_str},," =~ ,,words,, ]]
then
   echo 'Matches'
else
   echo "Doesn't match"
fi
```

The above code works by using Bash regular expressions to match against a stringified version of the array contents.  There are six important steps to ensure that the regular expression match can't be fooled by clever combinations of values within the array:

1. Construct the comparison string by using Bash's built-in `printf` shell-quoting, `%q`.  Shell-quoting will ensure that special characters become "shell-safe" by being escaped with backslash `\`.
2. Choose a special character to serve as a value delimiter.  The delimiter HAS to be one of the special characters that will become escaped when using `%q`; that's the only way to guarantee that values within the array can't be constructed in clever ways to fool the regular expression match.  I choose comma `,` because that character is the safest when eval'd or misused in an otherwise unexpected way.
3. Combine all array elements into a single string, using *two* instances of the special character to serve as delimiter.  Using comma as an example, I used `,,%q` as the argument to `printf`.  This is important because two instances of the special character can only appear next to each other when they appear as the delimiter; all other instances of the special character will be escaped.
4. Append two trailing instances of the delimiter to the string, to allow matches against the last element of the array.  Thus, instead of comparing against `${array_str}`, compare against `${array_str},,`.
5. If the target string you're searching for is supplied by a user variable, you *must* escape all instances of the special character with a backslash.  Otherwise, the regular expression match becomes vulnerable to being fooled by cleverly-crafted array elements.
6. Perform a Bash regular expression match against the string.

Comment: Very clever. I can see that most potential issues are prevented, but I'd want to test to see if there are any corner cases. Also, I'd like to see an example of handling point 5. Something like `printf -v pattern ',,%q,,' "$user_input"; if [[ "${array_str},," =~ $pattern ]]` perhaps.

Comment: `case "$(printf ,,%q "${haystack[@]}"),," in (*"$(printf ,,%q,, "$needle")"*) true;; (*) false;; esac`

Comment: If the target string you're searching for is supplied by a user variable, you must 1) escape *all* characters that were escaped by `%q` during the `printf` step (not just "the" special character), and 2) escape all regular expression special characters, including all the backslashes inserted during "1)".

Answer (score 6):

[The answer with most votes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15394738/8344060) is very concise and clean, but it can have false positives when a space is part of one of the array elements. This can be overcome when changing IFS and using `"${array[*]}"` instead of `"${array[@]}"`. The method is identical, but it looks less clean. By using `"${array[*]}"`, we print all elements of `$array`, separated by the first character in `IFS`. So by choosing a correct `IFS`, you can overcome this particular issue. In this particular case, we decide to set `IFS` to an uncommon character `$'\001'` which stands for *Start of Heading* ([`SOH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#SOH))

```
$ array=("foo bar" "baz" "qux")
$ IFS=$'\001'
$ [[ "$IFS${array[*]}$IFS" =~ "${IFS}foo${IFS}" ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
$ [[ "$IFS${array[*]}$IFS" =~ "${IFS}foo bar${IFS}" ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ unset IFS
```

This resolves most issues false positives, but requires a good choice of `IFS`.

**note:** If `IFS` was set before, it is best to save it and reset it instead of using `unset IFS`

---

**related:**

- [Accessing bash command line args $@ vs $*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12314451/8344060)

Answer (score 6):

### Stop the madness! Make your solution simple, clean, and reusable.

These functions account for indexed arrays and associative arrays. They can be improved upon by upgrading the search algorithm from a linear search to a binary one (for large data sets).

```
##
# Determines if a value exists in an array.
###
function hasArrayValue ()
{
    local -r needle="{$1:?}"
    local -nr haystack="{$2:?}"  # Where you pass by reference to get the entire array in one argument.

    # Linear search. Upgrade to binary search for large datasets.
    for value in "${haystack[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$value" == "$needle" ]]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done

    return 1
}

##
# Determines if a value exists in an associative array / map.
###
function hasMapValue ()
{
    local -r needle="{$1:?}"
    local -nr haystack="{$2:?}"

    # Linear search. Upgrade to binary search for large datasets.
    for value in "${haystack[@]}"; do
        if [[ $value == $needle ]]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done

    return 1
}
```

Yes, same logic, but in dealing with bash, if might (might) be useful to have a function with a name that lets you know what is being iterated over (or not).

Comment: I am getting an error using your `hasArrayValue()` at the line `local -nr haystack="{$2:?}"`.  The error message is `local: -n: invalid option`.   Is it possible you can provide an example how to call your `hasArrayValue()` function (with both arguments pass by reference)?   Separately, I believe the `bash` that came with macOS Monterey version 12.4 is too old.  `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin21)` is the cause here.  Thank you for the nice functions.

Comment: I upgraded my bash to 5.x on my Mac.  Now I am contemplating between these 2 different approaches:   https://askubuntu.com/a/995110/1359413 or https://askubuntu.com/a/674366/1359413 
If you have any references or explanation on what the `-nr` options for `local` that help be very helpful too.  Thanks again!

Comment: @geekyj The `-r` is for readonly. The `-n` is so that you can  pass in a name reference. Thus, when using a `-n` for an input parameter to a bash function, in the client code (the code that calls the function), do not use the $var form of the variable, or array. **Only pass the name.** Example: `hasMapValue $targetValue myBashMapArray`

Comment: Thank you for the helpful explanation and the caller example by reference!  I learned something new today!

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me:

```
# traditional system call return values-- used in an `if`, this will be true when returning 0. Very Odd.
contains () {
    # odd syntax here for passing array parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082947/how-to-pass-an-array-to-a-bash-function
    local list=$1[@]
    local elem=$2

    # echo "list" ${!list}
    # echo "elem" $elem

    for i in "${!list}"
    do
        # echo "Checking to see if" "$i" "is the same as" "${elem}"
        if [ "$i" == "${elem}" ] ; then
            # echo "$i" "was the same as" "${elem}"
            return 0
        fi
    done

    # echo "Could not find element"
    return 1
}
```

Example call:

```
arr=("abc" "xyz" "123")
if contains arr "abcx"; then
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

#### One-line check without 'grep' and loops

```
if ( dlm=$'\x1F' ; IFS="$dlm" ; [[ "$dlm${array[*]}$dlm" == *"$dlm${item}$dlm"* ]] ) ; then
  echo "array contains '$item'"
else
  echo "array does not contain '$item'"
fi
```

This approach uses neither external utilities like `grep` nor loops.

What happens here, is:

- we use a wildcard substring matcher to find our item in the array that is concatenated into a string;
- we cut off possible false positives by enclosing our search item between a pair of delimiters;
- we use a non-printable character as delimiter, to be on the safe side;
- we achieve our delimiter being used for array concatenation too by temporary replacement of the `IFS` variable value;
- we make this `IFS` value replacement temporary by evaluating our conditional expression in a sub-shell (inside a pair of parentheses)

Comment: Eliminate dlm. Use IFS directly.

Comment: This is best answer. I liked it so much, [I wrote a function using this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61379914).

Comment: Thank you @RobinA.Meade, I get your point, and your suggestion may help to save a number of chars in the script for ones who care :)
Still I personally prefer to stay with current syntax, keeping in mind separation of concerns between custom delimitation and array concatenation...

Comment: The problem with this still is that array entries might contain the `$dlm` by accident!  You can protect against this by using something like `dlm="${array[*]}"; dlm=",=${dlm//?/=}=,"` which makes the delimiter longer than the array, so the array cannot contain the delimiter by chance, but this looks a bit .. crank and probably makes this solution `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 3):

given :

```
array=("something to search for" "a string" "test2000")
elem="a string"
```

then a simple check of :

```
if c=$'\x1E' && p="${c}${elem} ${c}" && [[ ! "${array[@]/#/${c}} ${c}" =~ $p ]]; then
  echo "$elem exists in array"
fi
```

where

```
c is element separator
p is regex pattern
```

(The reason for assigning p separately, rather than using the expression directly inside [[ ]] is to maintain compatibility for bash 4)

Comment: love your use of the word "simple" here... 

Answer (score 3):

## Using `grep` and `printf`

Format each array member on a new line, then `grep` the lines.

```
if printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | grep -x -q "search string"; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

example:

```
$ array=("word", "two words")
$ if printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | grep -x -q "two words"; then echo true; else echo false; fi
true
```

*Note that this has no problems with delimeters and spaces.*

Comment: This feels very elegant to me. Far more readable than other "one-liner" approaches.

Answer (score 3):

Combining a few of the ideas presented here you can make an elegant if statment without loops that does **exact word matches**.

```
find="myword"
array=(value1 value2 myword)
if [[ ! -z $(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | grep -w $find) ]]; then
  echo "Array contains myword";
fi
```

This will not trigger on `word` or `val`, only whole word matches. It will break if each array value contains multiple words.

Comment: There are dollar-signs in the "=" statements that should not be there, AFAICT.

Answer (score 3):

A small addition to @ghostdog74's answer about using `case` logic to check that array contains particular value:

```
myarray=(one two three)
word=two
case "${myarray[@]}" in  ("$word "*|*" $word "*|*" $word") echo "found" ;; esac
```

Or with `extglob` option turned on, you can do it like this:

```
myarray=(one two three)
word=two
shopt -s extglob
case "${myarray[@]}" in ?(*" ")"$word"?(" "*)) echo "found" ;; esac
```

Also we can do it with `if` statement:

```
myarray=(one two three)
word=two
if [[ $(printf "_[%s]_" "${myarray[@]}") =~ .*_\[$word\]_.* ]]; then echo "found"; fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Great answers here, but I feel there is still a lack of a truly reusable function that allows easy calls in an `if` for example and proper testing.

Borrowing a bit here and there from some of the answers above, the following function is what always works, on every case, no matter if the array or the search string contains line breaks, null bytes, weird encoding, etc:

```bash
in_array() {
    local needle="$1"
    shift 1
    local haystack=("$@")

    local value
    for value in "${haystack[@]}"; do
        [ "$value" = "$needle" ] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}
```

The function above can be used as follows. Notice how the arguments are quoted when calling the function, specially the one referring to the array contents. This is extremely important to preserve the correct separation between the elements of the array:

```bash
my_array=(foo bar 'fizz buzz')

if in_array foo "${my_array[@]}"; then
    # "foo" is in the array, do stuff...
fi

if ! in_array fizz "${my_array[@]}"; then
    # "fizz" is not in the array, do stuff...
fi
```

And here is the test coverage using `bats`. Feel free to suggest more test cases!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

setup() {
    load /usr/lib/bats/bats-support/load
    load /usr/lib/bats/bats-assert/load

    source "$PROJECT_ROOT/src/in_array.sh"

    # Literal line break
    export lb=$'\n'
    # Literal null byte
    export nb=$'\0'
}

@test "sanity check: exported var \$lb works as expected" {
    str_with_linebreak="$(echo -e 'foo\nbar')"
    assert [ "$str_with_linebreak" = "foo${lb}bar" ]
}

@test "sanity check: exported var \$nb works as expected" {
    str_with_null_byte="$(echo -e 'foo\0bar')"
    assert [ "$str_with_null_byte" = "foo${nb}bar" ]
}

@test "in_array: never match in an empty array" {
    data=()
    refute in_array foo "${data[@]}"

    refute in_array '' "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array ' ' "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "$lb" "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "$nb" "${data[@]}"
}

@test "in_array: matches single words correctly" {
    data=(foo bar 123)

    assert in_array foo "${data[@]}"
    assert in_array bar "${data[@]}"
    assert in_array 123 "${data[@]}"

    refute in_array baz "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array fo "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array ar "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array 12 "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array 'foo bar' "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array 'ar 12' "${data[@]}"

    refute in_array '' "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array ' ' "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "$lb" "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "$nb" "${data[@]}"
}

@test "in_array: matches terms containing spaces" {
    data=(foo bar 'fizz buzz')

    assert in_array foo "${data[@]}"
    assert in_array bar "${data[@]}"
    assert in_array 'fizz buzz' "${data[@]}"

    refute in_array fizz "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array buzz "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array 'foo bar' "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array 'bar fizz' "${data[@]}"

    refute in_array '' "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array ' ' "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "$lb" "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "$nb" "${data[@]}"
}

@test "in_array: matches terms containing line breaks" {
    needle="fizz${lb}buzz"
    data=(foo bar "$needle")

    assert in_array foo "${data[@]}"
    assert in_array bar "${data[@]}"
    assert in_array "$needle" "${data[@]}"

    refute in_array fizz "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array buzz "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "foo${lb}bar" "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "bar${lb}fizz" "${data[@]}"

    refute in_array '' "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array ' ' "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "$lb" "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "$nb" "${data[@]}"
}

@test "in_array: matches terms containing null bytes" {
    needle="fizz${nb}buzz"
    data=(foo bar "$needle")

    assert in_array foo "${data[@]}"
    assert in_array bar "${data[@]}"
    assert in_array "$needle" "${data[@]}"

    refute in_array fizz "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array buzz "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "foo${nb}bar" "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "bar${nb}fizz" "${data[@]}"

    refute in_array '' "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array ' ' "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "$lb" "${data[@]}"
    refute in_array "$nb" "${data[@]}"
}
```

Output:

```bash
$ docker container run \
    --rm --volume "$PWD:/code" --workdir /code \
    bats/bats tests.bats

1..7
ok 1 sanity check: exported var $lb works as expected
ok 2 sanity check: exported var $nb works as expected
ok 3 in_array: never match in an empty array
ok 4 in_array: matches single words correctly
ok 5 in_array: matches terms containing spaces
ok 6 in_array: matches terms containing line breaks
ok 7 in_array: matches terms containing null bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

I see a few ways to approach the problem.

For index array using `grep`

```
grep ${value} <<< ${array[*]} && true || false
```

For associative array keys using `grep`

```
grep ${value} <<< "${!array[*]}" && true || false
```

One could use awk, but it's probably overkill.

```
awk --assign "v=${value}" '$v~$0 {print true}' <<<"${!array[*]}
```

Case statement.

```
case "${array[*]}" in (*${value}*) true ;; (*) false ;; esac
```

Bash conditional expressions in ksh88 style double square bracket:

```
[[ ${array[@]} =~ ${value} ]] && true || false
```

note: the order is important, the regex is on the right side of `=~` match operator.

Bash for loop

```
for ((i=0;i<"${#array[*]}";i++)) ; [[ ${array[i]} = $value ]] && break 0 &> /dev/null || continue; done
```

Note, in this special case the truthy logic is inversed, I.E. 1=true, 0=false. That is because we use `break 0` to force `break` builtin to have an exit code besides true, which is always the case unless the `break n` parameter is less than 1. We imperatively want to break the loop, and we want a boolean exit code besides default 'true', so in this case we flip the logic. For that reason it would probably make more sense to use a function with `return  true` semantics.

Comment: Guess what happens when you grep for _any_ of the letters contained in _any_ of the entries.

Answer (score 1):

I generally write these kind of utilities to operate on the name of the variable, rather than the variable value, primarily because bash can't otherwise pass variables by reference.

Here's a version that works with the name of the array:

```
function array_contains # array value
{
    [[ -n "$1" && -n "$2" ]] || {
        echo "usage: array_contains <array> <value>"
        echo "Returns 0 if array contains value, 1 otherwise"
        return 2
    }

    eval 'local values=("${'$1'[@]}")'

    local element
    for element in "${values[@]}"; do
        [[ "$element" == "$2" ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}
```

With this, the question example becomes:

```
array_contains A "one" && echo "contains one"
```

etc.

Comment: Can someone post an example of this used within an if, particularly how you pass in the array. I'm trying to check to see if an argument to the script was passed by treating the params as an array, but it doesn't want to work.

params=("$@")
check=array_contains ${params} 'SKIPDIRCHECK'
if [[ ${check} == 1 ]]; then ....

But when running the script with 'asas' as an argument, it keeps saying asas: command not found. :/

Answer (score 1):

Using parameter expansion:

> ${parameter:+word} If parameter is null or unset, nothing is
>   substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

```
declare -A myarray
myarray[hello]="world"

for i in hello goodbye 123
do
  if [ ${myarray[$i]:+_} ]
  then
    echo ${!myarray[$i]} ${myarray[$i]} 
  else
    printf "there is no %s\n" $i
  fi
done
```

Comment: `${myarray[hello]:+_}` works great for associaive arrays, but not for usual indexed arrays. The question is about finding a value in an aray, not checking if the key of an associative array exists.

Answer (score 1):

The OP added the following answer themselves, with the commentary:

> With help from the answers and the comments, after some testing, I came up with this:

```
function contains() {
    local n=$#
    local value=${!n}
    for ((i=1;i < $#;i++)) {
        if [ "${!i}" == "${value}" ]; then
            echo "y"
            return 0
        fi
    }
    echo "n"
    return 1
}

A=("one" "two" "three four")
if [ $(contains "${A[@]}" "one") == "y" ]; then
    echo "contains one"
fi
if [ $(contains "${A[@]}" "three") == "y" ]; then
    echo "contains three"
fi
```

Comment: Note that `==` should generally be avoided in favor of `=`, which is guaranteed by the POSIX standard for `test` to work as a string-comparison operator. `==` is an extension, and not all shells honor it. Also, `function funcname() {` is a combination of the POSIX-standard syntax `funcname() {` and the legacy ksh syntax `function funcname {`, and yet is compatible with _neither_ POSIX sh, nor with legacy ksh. Just use the POSIX syntax instead for new code.

Comment: ...see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: the above assertions regarding function declaration syntax.

Answer (score 1):

keep it simple :

```
Array1=( "item1" "item2" "item3" "item-4" )
var="item3"

count=$(echo ${Array1[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '$1 == "'"$var"'"{print $0}' | wc -l)
[ $count -eq 0 ] && echo "Not found" || echo "found"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
: NeedleInArgs "$needle" "${haystack[@]}"
: NeedleInArgs "$needle" arg1 arg2 .. argN
NeedleInArgs()
{
local a b;
printf -va '\n%q\n' "$1";
printf -vb '%q\n' "${@:2}";
case $'\n'"$b" in (*"$a"*) return 0;; esac;
return 1;
}
```

Use like:

```
NeedleInArgs "$needle" "${haystack[@]}" && echo "$needle" found || echo "$needle" not found;
```

- For `bash` v3.1 and above (`printf -v` support)
- No forks nor external programs
- No loops (except internal expansions within `bash`)
- Works for all possible values and arrays, no exceptions, nothing to worry about

Can also be used directly like in:

```
if      NeedleInArgs "$input" value1 value2 value3 value4;
then
        : input from the list;
else
        : input not from list;
fi;
```

For `bash` from v2.05b to v3.0 `printf` lacks `-v`, hence this needs 2 additional forks (but no execs, as `printf` is a `bash` builtin):

```
NeedleInArgs()
{
case $'\n'"`printf '%q\n' "${@:2}"`" in
(*"`printf '\n%q\n' "$1"`"*) return 0;;
esac;
return 1;
}
```

Note that I tested the timing:

```
check call0:  n: t4.43 u4.41 s0.00 f: t3.65 u3.64 s0.00 l: t4.91 u4.90 s0.00 N: t5.28 u5.27 s0.00 F: t2.38 u2.38 s0.00 L: t5.20 u5.20 s0.00
check call1:  n: t3.41 u3.40 s0.00 f: t2.86 u2.84 s0.01 l: t3.72 u3.69 s0.02 N: t4.01 u4.00 s0.00 F: t1.15 u1.15 s0.00 L: t4.05 u4.05 s0.00
check call2:  n: t3.52 u3.50 s0.01 f: t3.74 u3.73 s0.00 l: t3.82 u3.80 s0.01 N: t2.67 u2.67 s0.00 F: t2.64 u2.64 s0.00 L: t2.68 u2.68 s0.00
```

- `call0` and `call1` are different variants of calls to another fast pure-bash-variant
- `call2` is this here.
- `N`=notfound `F`=firstmatch `L`=lastmatch
- lowercase letter is short array, uppercase is long array

As you can see, this variant here has a very stable runtime, so it does not depend that much on the match position.  The runtime is dominated mostly by array length.  The runtime of the searching variant is highly depending on the match position.  So in edge cases this variant here can be (much) faster.

But very important, the searching variant is much mor RAM efficient, as this variant here always transforms the whole array into a big string.

So if your RAM is tight and you expect mostly early matches, then do not use this here.  However if you want a predictable runtime, have long arrays to match expect late or no match at all, and also double RAM use is not much of a concern, then this here has some advantage.

Script used for timing test:

```
in_array()
{
    local needle="$1" arrref="$2[@]" item
    for item in "${!arrref}"; do
        [[ "${item}" == "${needle}" ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

NeedleInArgs()
{
local a b;
printf -va '\n%q\n' "$1";
printf -vb '%q\n' "${@:2}";
case $'\n'"$b" in (*"$a"*) return 0;; esac;
return 1;
}

loop1() { for a in {1..100000}; do "$@"; done }
loop2() { for a in {1..1000}; do "$@"; done }

run()
{
  needle="$5"
  arr=("${@:6}")

  out="$( ( time -p "loop$2" "$3" ) 2>&1 )"

  ret="$?"
  got="${out}"
  syst="${got##*sys }"
  got="${got%"sys $syst"}"
  got="${got%$'\n'}"
  user="${got##*user }"
  got="${got%"user $user"}"
  got="${got%$'\n'}"
  real="${got##*real }"
  got="${got%"real $real"}"
  got="${got%$'\n'}"
  printf ' %s: t%q u%q s%q' "$1" "$real" "$user" "$syst"
  [ -z "$rest" ] && [ "$ret" = "$4" ] && return
  printf 'FAIL! expected %q got %q\n' "$4" "$ret"
  printf 'call:   %q\n' "$3"
  printf 'out:    %q\n' "$out"
  printf 'rest:   %q\n' "$rest"
  printf 'needle: %q\n' "$5"
  printf 'arr:   '; printf ' %q' "${@:6}"; printf '\n'
  exit 1
}

check()
{
  printf 'check %q: ' "$1"
  run n 1 "$1" 1 needle a b c d
  run f 1 "$1" 0 needle needle a b c d
  run l 1 "$1" 0 needle a b c d needle
  run N 2 "$1" 1 needle "${rnd[@]}"
  run F 2 "$1" 0 needle needle "${rnd[@]}"
  run L 2 "$1" 0 needle "${rnd[@]}" needle
  printf '\n'
}

call0() { chk=("${arr[@]}"); in_array "$needle" chk; }
call1() { in_array "$needle" arr; }
call2() { NeedleInArgs "$needle" "${arr[@]}"; }

rnd=()
for a in {1..1000}; do rnd+=("$a"); done

check call0
check call1
check call2
```

Answer (score 1):

### **What Makes The Solution That I Am Presenting Unique/Valuable?**

There are a lot of decent answers here, but due to some constraints, (self imposed), that I was facing in a script of my own (bash prompt), I bent over backwards to both avoid subshells, external programs, limitations on search terms or array values, bash loops and and bash regex.

The result of that is a reasonably simple, one-liner(ish) function that correctly identifies values within an array while handling spaces, quotes and other special characters correctly. It does this without the use of regex, without bash loops, without limitations on search terms or values and without setting any environment variables (apart from '_', which happens for every bash simple command).

It is also completely compatible with the restrictions of parameter expansion with Bash 4.2 + and most likely works with bash versions far lower than that so long as they support the parameter expansion features used.

Ok then, whats my fantastic solution to add to the pile of 30+?

## **EDIT: What Massive Tradeoffs Does This Have?**

---

Welp, it turns out that this is big **O**'l Big O notation downside attached to it.

Im pretty sure its O(n^{2})

.... yea ...

So is this useful ever? If you need precisely those things i mentioned for no apparent reason, and want to skip wasting way too much time figuring out that it was technically possible, then absolutely! If you are literally anyone else who wants a semblance of a reliable, linear solution, just go with any of the other list based option. Now that I've done it, I can confidently say this is a bad solution and does not work.

The big enemy is in the "${w//?/?(?)}", which does that for each character of each element of the entered array. Some arguments for a command? No problem. You want to use remotely sizable elements or arrays? LAAAAAAG.

Anyhow, I'll leave this just in case someone really really wants to know if its possible like I did, but I leave this more as a warning than a recommendation. I'd like to avoid someone else go designing a square wheel just to find out they're in for a bumpy ride.

### **Function In Its Shortest (one-liner-ish) Forms**

```
# Function (shortest) (assumes extglob is enabled)
#     Usage: item_in_array "search_term" "${target_array[@]}"
item_in_array() { [[ -n $1 ]] && local s="$1" && shift && local w="${s::-1}" && w="${w//?/?(?)}" && IFS='' w="${*##@(@(${s//?/?}+(?))|@($w)|!("$s"))}" && [[ -n $w ]]; }
```

```
# Function (shortest-er) (assumes extglob is enabled)
#     Usage: item_in_array "search_term" "${target_array[@]}"
#
#     Note: This function is the same as item_in_array, but uses
#           bad substitution to check for a non-empty search term
#           instead of the more readable [[ -n $1 ]]. It saves just
#           three characters, but is less readable.
item_in_array2() { local s="$1" && shift && local w="${s::-1}" &>/dev/null && w="${w//?/?(?)}" && IFS='' w="${*##@(@(${s//?/?}+(?))|@($w)|!("$s"))}" && [[ -n $w ]]; }
```

### **Function, With Shopt Enabled if Disabled**

```
# Function (short)
#     Usage: item_in_array "search_term" "${target_array[@]}"
item_in_array_short() {
    ! shopt extglob &>/dev/null && shopt -s extglob
    [[ -n $1 ]] && local s="$1" && shift && local w="${s::-1}" && w="${w//?/?(?)}" && IFS='' w="${*##@(@(${s//?/?}+(?))|@($w)|!("$s"))}" && [[ -n $w ]]
}
```

### **Function, Commented/Explained and Spaced for Readability**

```
# Function (commented and somewhat readable)
#     Usage: item_in_array "search_term" "${target_array[@]}"
item_in_array_long() {
    # Ensure extglob is enabled
    ! shopt extglob &>/dev/null && shopt -s extglob
    # Ensure that the search term is not empty, returning otherwise
    [[ -n $1 ]] &&
        # Take the first argument off of the argument list as the search term
        local s="$1" && shift &&
        # Create a pattern we will use later to set any elements shorter than
        # the search term to an empty string
        local w="${s::-1}" &>/dev/null && w="${w//?/?(?)}" &&
        # 1.Set IFS to an empty string to prevent empty spaces in final result
        # 2.Set the result to the target array with elements seperated with an
        #   empty string with the longest match of the following patterns
        #   removed from the beginning of the string:
        #       1. Any element that is longer than the search term
        #           @(${s//?/?}+(?))
        #       2. Any element that is the same as the search term
        #           @($w)
        #          Note: This is a pattern and is purposefully unquoted
        #       3. Any element that is not the search term
        #           !("$s")
        # 3. Return 0 if the result is not empty, 1 otherwise. This is as in
        #   step 2.2 we truncate the result with the search term to its last
        #   character, which is fine, as we truncate all elements of the same
        #   length as the search term to an empty string in step 2.3.
        IFS='' w="${*##@(@(${s//?/?}+(?))|@($w)|!("$s"))}" && [[ -n $w ]]
}
```

### **Test Results (run for all function variants)**

```
# RESULT: expected ?? received for search_term
# PASSED:    false == false    for '  '
# PASSED:    false == false    for ''-b {{}{($")}} -b''
# PASSED:    false == false    for 'third'
# PASSED:     true == true     for 'third third'
# PASSED:    false == false    for '-a -v'
# PASSED:     true == true     for '--help'
# PASSED:    false == false    for 'third item'
# PASSED:     true == true     for '-b {{}{($")}} -b'
# PASSED:    false == false    for '{{}{($")}}'
# PASSED:     true == true     for '-v -a -v'
# PASSED:     true == true     for 'item four'
# PASSED:     true == true     for ' '
# PASSED:     true == true     for '-v'
# PASSED:    false == false    for 'item third'
# PASSED:    false == false    for '-b'
# PASSED:    false == false    for 'item'
```

### **Full Test Script**

```
#! /bin/bash

# Description
#
# This is a function that returns whether or not an item is an exact match for an element of the passed in array.
#
# This function has the following attributes works with all the constraints of parameter expansion in bash 4.2.
# It avoids for loops, while loops, sub-shells and bash regex (to avoid changing BASH_REMATCH).
# It uses just shell parameter expansions and string comparisons
# It is also the shortest function for this purpose vs all the other functions of a similar goal that I have seen,
# hence this gist.
#
# Note: This function requires extglob to be available.

# Function (commented and somewhat readable)
#     Usage: item_in_array "search_term" "${target_array[@]}"
item_in_array_long() {
    # Ensure extglob is enabled
    ! shopt extglob &>/dev/null && shopt -s extglob
    # Ensure that the search term is not empty, returning otherwise
    [[ -n $1 ]] &&
        # Take the first argument off of the argument list as the search term
        local s="$1" && shift &&
        # Create a pattern we will use later to set any elements shorter than
        # the search term to an empty string
        local w="${s::-1}" &>/dev/null && w="${w//?/?(?)}" &&
        # 1.Set IFS to an empty string to prevent empty spaces in final result
        # 2.Set the result to the target array with elements seperated with an
        #   empty string with the longest match of the following patterns
        #   removed from the beginning of the string:
        #       1. Any element that is longer than the search term
        #           @(${s//?/?}+(?))
        #       2. Any element that is the same as the search term
        #           @($w)
        #          Note: This is a pattern and is purposefully unquoted
        #       3. Any element that is not the search term
        #           !("$s")
        # 3. Return 0 if the result is not empty, 1 otherwise. This is as in
        #   step 2.2 we truncate the result with the search term to its last
        #   character, which is fine, as we truncate all elements of the same
        #   length as the search term to an empty string in step 2.3.
        IFS='' w="${*##@(@(${s//?/?}+(?))|@($w)|!("$s"))}" && [[ -n $w ]]
}

# Function (short)
#     Usage: item_in_array "search_term" "${target_array[@]}"
item_in_array_short() {
    ! shopt extglob &>/dev/null && shopt -s extglob
    [[ -n $1 ]] && local s="$1" && shift && local w="${s::-1}" && w="${w//?/?(?)}" && IFS='' w="${*##@(@(${s//?/?}+(?))|@($w)|!("$s"))}" && [[ -n $w ]]
}

# Function (shortest) (assumes extglob is enabled)
#     Usage: item_in_array "search_term" "${target_array[@]}"
item_in_array() { [[ -n $1 ]] && local s="$1" && shift && local w="${s::-1}" && w="${w//?/?(?)}" && IFS='' w="${*##@(@(${s//?/?}+(?))|@($w)|!("$s"))}" && [[ -n $w ]]; }

# Function (shortest-er) (assumes extglob is enabled)
#     Usage: item_in_array "search_term" "${target_array[@]}"
#
#     Note: This function is the same as item_in_array, but uses
#           bad substitution to check for a non-empty search term
#           instead of the more readable [[ -n $1 ]]. It saves just
#           three characters, but is less readable.
item_in_array2() { local s="$1" && shift && local w="${s::-1}" &>/dev/null && w="${w//?/?(?)}" && IFS='' w="${*##@(@(${s//?/?}+(?))|@($w)|!("$s"))}" && [[ -n $w ]]; }

# Tests

test_array=(
    'first item'
    ' '
    'second item'
    'third third'
    '-v -a -v'
    '-b -b -b'
    'item four'
    '-v'
    '--help'
    '-b {{}{($")}} -b'
)

declare -A test_searches=(
    ['item']=false
    ['third item']=false
    ['third']=false
    ['-a -v']=false
    ['item third']=false
    ['third third']=true
    ['item four']=true
    ['-v -a -v']=true
    ['-a -v']=false
    ['-v']=true
    ['-b']=false
    ['  ']=false
    [' ']=true
    ['--help']=true
    ['{{}{($")}}']=false
    ["'-b {{}{($\")}} -b'"]=false
    ['-b {{}{($")}} -b']=true
)

test_item_in_array_function() {
    local function_name="$1"
    shift
    printf '\n\e[48;2;50;50;25mTESTING: %-35s\e[0m\n' "$function_name"
    printf '\e[48;2;40;40;40mRESULT: expected ?? received for search_term\e[0m\n'
    for search_term in "${!test_searches[@]}"; do
        expected="${test_searches[$search_term]}"
        if "$function_name" "$search_term" "${test_array[@]}"; then
            received=true
        else
            received=false
        fi

        if [[ $received == "$expected" ]]; then
            printf "\e[48;2;0;20;0mPASSED: %8s == %-8s for '%s'\e[0m\n" "$expected" "$received" "$search_term"
        else
            printf "\e[48;2;20;0;0mFAILED: %8s != %-8s for '%s'\e[0m\n" "$expected" "$received" "$search_term"
        fi
    done
}

test_item_in_array_function item_in_array_long
test_item_in_array_function item_in_array_short
test_item_in_array_function item_in_array
test_item_in_array_function item_in_array2
```

**Side Notes**

- I created this with the intent of being a faster, smaller solution that would not use bash regex as I did not want to have to try to deal with the consequences of potential situations where I might use this before retrieving $BASH_REMATCH
- I have not actually timed this vs the other solutions here, I am just assuming it should be faster given that while of course loops go on somewhere along the path in this code, it is all done in the c implementation of parameter expansion which I assume should make this faster, though I think its possible it is not, due to the increased amount of string comparisons necessary.
- Why would I waste the time coming up with such a weird, unique, shell parameter expansion based solution instead of settling for the answer I kept getting; That it wasn't possible? I felt like there must be a way, and after posting a prior solution that was wrong in many edge cases, I decided I had to find the answer, which is this solution that has solved for those previous cases.

Comment: Nice idea! Clever and efficient!! You may have to *localize* `IFS` in order to not alter them. At begin of your func: `local s="$1" IFS=; ...`

Comment: Sorry, I've missed to upvote when I posted my previous comment! +1: really impressive! ( I can't upvote more, but I could try to drawn other user's attention... ;)

Comment: ... But please do localize `IFS`!! And maybe could you add a kind of preamble, with the shortest reliable function.

Comment: There is one case where this won't work: if `array=('something' '' '...')`, and you are testing for presence of *empty string*  `item_in_array '' "${array[@]}"` in your array, then answer will be wrong!  `FAILED:     true != false    for ''`

Comment: I've finally posted [my comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78070423/1765658), Bad news: your method isn't quickest.

Comment: Interesting comparison, though I will say, my post does include disclaimers about the abysmal performance and use case its suited for (which is somewhat niche, but still globally relevant if that makes sense).

I actually would have expected it to perform *worse* than that.

Comment: U said: *I created this with the intent of being a faster, smaller solution that would not use bash regex *. For this, you could use `case` instead of *regex*, with Keegan's solution. This function will still be ~3x faster and keep *`$BASH_REMATCH`* unchanged.

Comment: I edited the comment soon after posting after discovering the pretty big performance trade off and in large bold font stated "What Massive Tradeoffs Does This Have?" followed by explaining the tradeoffs.

The sentence you quote is accurate, as in that was my intent. The warning above is also accurate.

The case solution certainly is clever however.

Answer (score 0):

After having answered, I read another answer that I particularly liked, but it was flawed and downvoted. I got inspired and here are two new approaches I see viable.

```
array=("word" "two words") # let's look for "two words"
```

### using `grep` and `printf`:

```
(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | grep -x -q "two words") && <run_your_if_found_command_here>
```

### using `for`:

```
(for e in "${array[@]}"; do [[ "$e" == "two words" ]] && exit 0; done; exit 1) && <run_your_if_found_command_here>
```

*For not_found results add `|| <run_your_if_notfound_command_here>`*

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this.

I'd rather not use a bash for loop if I can avoid it, as that takes time to run. If something has to loop, let it be something that was written in a lower level language than a shell script.

```
function array_contains { # arrayname value
  local -A _arr=()
  local IFS=
  eval _arr=( $(eval printf '[%q]="1"\ ' "\${$1[@]}") )
  return $(( 1 - 0${_arr[$2]} ))
}
```

This works by creating a temporary associative array, `_arr`, whose indices are derived from the values of the input array. (Note that associative arrays are available in bash 4 and above, so this function won't work in earlier versions of bash.) We set `$IFS` to avoid word splitting on whitespace.

The function contains no explicit loops, though internally bash steps through the input array in order to populate `printf`. The printf format uses `%q` to ensure that input data are escaped such that they can safely be used as array keys.

```
$ a=("one two" three four)
$ array_contains a three && echo BOOYA
BOOYA
$ array_contains a two && echo FAIL
$
```

Note that everything this function uses is a built-in to bash, so there are no external pipes dragging you down, even in the command expansion.

And if you don't like using `eval` ... well, you're free to use another approach. :-)

Comment: What if the array contains square brackets?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - seems to be fine if square brackets are balanced, but  I can see it being a problem if your array includes values with unbalanced square brackets. In that case I'd invoke the `eval` instruction at the end of the answer. :)

Comment: It's not that I don't like `eval` (I have nothing against it, unlike most people who cry _`eval` is evil,_ mostly without understanding what's evil about it). Just that your command is broken. Maybe `%q` instead of `%s` would be better.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I only meant the "another approach" bit (and I'm totally with you re `eval`, obviously), but you're absolutely right, `%q` appears to help, without breaking anything else that I can see. (I didn't realize that %q would escape square brackets too.) Another issue I saw and fixed was regarding whitespace. With `a=(one "two " three)`, similar to Keegan's issue: not only did `array_contains a "two "` get a false negative, but `array_contains a two` got a false positive. Easy enough to fix by setting `IFS`.

Comment: Regarding whitespaces, isn't it because there are quotes missing? it also breaks with glob characters. I think you want this instead:  `eval _arr=( $(eval printf '[%q]="1"\ ' "\"\${$1[@]}\"") )`, and you can ditch the `local IFS=`. There's still a problem with empty fields in the array, as Bash will refuse to create an empty key in an associative array. A quick hacky way to fix it is to prepend a dummy character, say `x`: `eval _arr=( $(eval printf '[x%q]="1"\ ' "\"\${$1[@]}\"") )` and `return $(( 1 - 0${_arr[x$2]} ))`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Just posted [my comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78070423/1765658)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me (Almquist shell [no declare, shift, i++ ... ] - Android 11) was reconstructing the array.
Create a file called array_contains.sh

```
 #!/bin/sh

build_array_from_arguments() {
    array=()
    va=""
    i=0
    arr=( "$@" )
    for ix in "${arr[@]}"; do
        if [ "$i" -eq 0 ]; then
            va="$ix"
        else
            array+=("$ix")
        fi
        i=$((i + 1))
    done
    for elem in "${array[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$elem" == "$va" ]]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}

build_array_from_arguments "$@"
```

call it like this

```
array_of_numbers=( "1" "2" "3" )
sh /sdcard/array_contains.sh "1" "${array_of_numbers[@]}" # or chmod if you have the rights
```

Answer (score 0):

My method is particularly advantageous for handling entries that include spaces, sentences, or special characters, thanks to its explicit demarcation of element boundaries. By using a unique delimiter `\4` to separate array elements, the script ensures precise matching, effectively mitigating the risk of partial matches and the complexities introduced by special characters.

This is an alternative to Oneliner as mentioned in the comments above: `[[ " ${branches[@]} " =~ " ${value} " ]] && echo "YES" || echo "NO";` - The one-liner method, while concise, is more susceptible to partial matches and may struggle with special characters due to its less rigorous boundary definition. Consequently, this script stands out as a robust solution for scenarios requiring exact matches, particularly when dealing with complex array elements that could be misinterpreted by simpler matching techniques.

`\4` represents the character with ASCII code 4, which is the "**[End of Transmission](https://www.ascii-code.com/character/%E2%90%84)**" (**EOT**) control character. In can be interpreted as a delimiter or separator in data processing or transmission systems

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# define your array
myArray=("CPU" "RAM" "GPU")

# the value you are looking for
value="RAM"

# unique delimiter using ASCII control character
delimiter=$'\4'

# converts array into string, where each element is prefixed by the unique delimiter
arrayString=$(printf "${delimiter}%s" "${myArray[@]}")

# removes the first delimiter
arrayString="${arrayString:1}"

# check if a value is in an array
# using unique delimiters to mark word boundaries ensures exact matches
# using the delimiter '\4' ensures RA would not match RAM or AM to RAM
# this approach prevents a word from being considered a part of another word
# for example, comparing ${delimiter}CPU${delimiter}RAM${delimiter}GPU${delimiter} with ${delimiter}RAM${delimiter}
if [[ "${delimiter}${arrayString}${delimiter}" == *"${delimiter}${value}${delimiter}"* ]]; then
    echo "Found"
else
    echo "Not Found"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Although there were several great and helpful answers here, I didn't find one that seemed to be the right combination of performant, cross-platform, and robust; so I wanted to share the solution I wrote for my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# array_contains "$needle" "${haystack[@]}"
#
# Returns 0 if an item ($1) is contained in an array ($@).
#
# Developer note:
#    The use of a delimiter here leaves something to be desired. The ideal
#    method seems to be to use `grep` with --line-regexp and --null-data, but
#    Mac/BSD grep doesn't support --line-regexp.
function array_contains()
{
    # Extract and remove the needle from $@.
    local needle="$1"
    shift

    # Separates strings in the array for matching. Must be extremely-unlikely
    # to appear in the input array or the needle.
    local delimiter='#!-\8/-!#'

    # Create a string with containing every (delimited) element in the array,
    # and search it for the needle with grep in fixed-string mode.
    if printf "${delimiter}%s${delimiter}" "$@" | \
        grep --fixed-strings --quiet "${delimiter}${needle}${delimiter}"; then
        return 0
    fi

    return 1
}
```

Comment: Why did you downvote and deletevote this? It's a valid way to solve the problem, and I documented it well.

Answer (score -1):

My version of the regular expressions technique that's been suggested already:

```
values=(foo bar)
requestedValue=bar

requestedValue=${requestedValue##[[:space:]]}
requestedValue=${requestedValue%%[[:space:]]}
[[ "${values[@]/#/X-}" =~ "X-${requestedValue}" ]] || echo "Unsupported value"
```

What's happening here is that you're expanding the entire array of supported values into words and prepending a specific string, "X-" in this case, to each of them, and doing the same to the requested value. If this one is indeed contained in the array, then the resulting string will at most match one of the resulting tokens, or none at all in the contrary. In the latter case the || operator triggers and you know you're dealing with an unsupported value. Prior to all of that the requested value is stripped of all leading and trailing whitespace through standard shell string manipulation.

It's clean and elegant, I believe, though I'm not too sure of how performant it may be if your array of supported values is particularly large.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my take on this problem. Here is the short version:

```
function arrayContains() {
        local haystack=${!1}
        local needle="$2"
        printf "%s\n" ${haystack[@]} | grep -q "^$needle$"
}
```

And the long version, which I think is much easier on the eyes.

```
# With added utility function.
function arrayToLines() {
        local array=${!1}
        printf "%s\n" ${array[@]}
}

function arrayContains() {
        local haystack=${!1}
        local needle="$2"
        arrayToLines haystack[@] | grep -q "^$needle$"
}
```

Examples:

```
test_arr=("hello" "world")
arrayContains test_arr[@] hello; # True
arrayContains test_arr[@] world; # True
arrayContains test_arr[@] "hello world"; # False
arrayContains test_arr[@] "hell"; # False
arrayContains test_arr[@] ""; # False
```

Comment: I haven't been using bash for such a long time now that I have a hard time understanding the answers, or even what I wrote myself :)
I cannot believe that this question is still getting activity after all this time :)

Comment: What about `test_arr=("hello" "world" "two words")`?

Answer (score -1):

I had the case that I had to check if an ID was contained in a list of IDs generated by another script / command.
For me worked the following:

```
# the ID I was looking for
ID=1

# somehow generated list of IDs
LIST=$( <some script that generates lines with IDs> )
# list is curiously concatenated with a single space character
LIST=" $LIST "

# grep for exact match, boundaries are marked as space
# would therefore not reliably work for values containing a space
# return the count with "-c"
ISIN=$(echo $LIST | grep -F " $ID " -c)

# do your check (e. g. 0 for nothing found, everything greater than 0 means found)
if [ ISIN -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "not found"
fi
# etc.
```

You could also shorten / compact it like this:

```
if [ $(echo " $( <script call> ) " | grep -F " $ID " -c) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "not found"
fi
```

In my case, I was running jq to filter some JSON for a list of IDs and had to later check if my ID was in this list and this worked the best for me.
It will not work for manually created arrays of the type `LIST=("1" "2" "4")` but for with newline separated script output.

---

PS.: could not comment an answer because I'm relatively new ...

Answer (score -2):

The following code checks if a given value is in the array and returns its zero-based offset:

```
A=("one" "two" "three four")
VALUE="two"

if [[ "$(declare -p A)" =~ '['([0-9]+)']="'$VALUE'"' ]];then
  echo "Found $VALUE at offset ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
  echo "Couldn't find $VALUE"
fi
```

The match is done on the complete values, therefore setting VALUE="three" would not match.

Answer (score -2):

This could be worth investigating if you don't want to iterate:

```
#!/bin/bash
myarray=("one" "two" "three");
wanted="two"
if `echo ${myarray[@]/"$wanted"/"WAS_FOUND"} | grep -q "WAS_FOUND" ` ; then
 echo "Value was found"
fi
exit
```

Snippet adapted from: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/
I think it is pretty clever.

EDIT:
You could probably just do:

```
if `echo ${myarray[@]} | grep -q "$wanted"` ; then
echo "Value was found"
fi
```

But the latter only works if the array contains unique values. Looking for 1 in "143" will give false positive, methinks.

Answer (score -2):

A little late, but you could use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# isPicture.sh

FILE=$1
FNAME=$(basename "$FILE") # Filename, without directory
EXT="${FNAME##*.}" # Extension

FORMATS=(jpeg JPEG jpg JPG png PNG gif GIF svg SVG tiff TIFF)

NOEXT=( ${FORMATS[@]/$EXT} ) # Formats without the extension of the input file

# If it is a valid extension, then it should be removed from ${NOEXT},
#+making the lengths inequal.
if ! [ ${#NOEXT[@]} != ${#FORMATS[@]} ]; then
    echo "The extension '"$EXT"' is not a valid image extension."
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

I came up with this one, which turns out to work only in zsh, but I think the general approach is nice.

```
arr=( "hello world" "find me" "what?" )
if [[ "${arr[@]/#%find me/}" != "${arr[@]}" ]]; then
    echo "found!"
else
    echo "not found!"
fi
```

You take out your pattern from each element only if it starts `${arr[@]/#pattern/}` or ends `${arr[@]/%pattern/}` with it. These two substitutions work in bash, but both at the same time `${arr[@]/#%pattern/}` only works in zsh.

If the modified array is equal to the original, then it doesn't contain the element.

Edit:

This one works in bash:

```
 function contains () {
        local arr=(${@:2})
        local el=$1
        local marr=(${arr[@]/#$el/})
        [[ "${#arr[@]}" != "${#marr[@]}" ]]
    }
```

After the substitution it compares the length of both arrays. Obly if the array contains the element the substitution will completely delete it, and the count will differ.

Answer (score -2):

Expanding on the above answer from Sean DiSanti, I think the following is a simple and elegant solution that avoids having to loop over the array and won't give false positives due to partial matches

```
function is_in_array {
    local ELEMENT="${1}"
    local DELIM=","
    printf "${DELIM}%s${DELIM}" "${@:2}" | grep -q "${DELIM}${ELEMENT}${DELIM}"
}
```

Which can be called like so:

```
$ haystack=("needle1" "needle2" "aneedle" "spaced needle")
$ is_in_array "needle" "${haystack[@]}"
$ echo $?
1
$ is_in_array "needle1" "${haystack[@]}"
$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score -3):

A combination of answers by Beorn Harris and loentar gives one more interesting one-liner test:

```
delim=$'\x1F' # define a control code to be used as more or less reliable delimiter
if [[ "${delim}${array[@]}${delim}" =~ "${delim}a string to test${delim}" ]]; then
    echo "contains 'a string to test'"
fi
```

This one does not use extra functions, does not make replacements for testing and adds extra protection against occasional false matches using a control code as a delimiter.

---

**UPD:** Thanks to @ChrisCogdon note, this incorrect code was re-written and published as https://stackoverflow.com/a/58527681/972463 .

Comment: Just curious: will anyone of the downvoters care to explain? What's the use of just voting down at the cost of one's points silently? Is there anything really wrong about this answer?

Comment: Also strictly not a one-liner

Comment: It doesn't work because the array expansion doesn't work the way you think. If `array=(one two three)` then `":${array[@]}:"` generates three words: `:one`, `two`, `three:`

Comment: @ChrisCogdon Thank you for pointing out the flaw in array concatenation. The corrected version is now published as https://stackoverflow.com/a/58527681/972463 .