# How to find the presence of element in bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash: check if an array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/bash-check-if-an-array-contains-a-value)

i have list like

```
list = ['pic1','pic2','pic3'];
```

i am in array like

```
for a in /dir/star
if(a is in list then skip the loop)
do
echo "hello";
done
```

I want to skip the loop if element is in list

Comment: The `list = ['pic1','pic2','pic3'];` notation is not an assignment in bash; it is an invocation of the command `list` with two arguments, one of which is an equals sign and the other of which is "`[pic1,pic2,pic3]`" when the command sees it.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan. Please either fix this question or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for path in /dir/*
do
    for val in pic1 pic2 pic3
    do
        if [ "$(basename -- "$path")x" = "${val}x" ]
        then
            continue 2 # Next path
        fi
    done
    # No match, do whatever you want
done
```

If you want to end processing completely after finding the first match, just replace `continue` with `break`.