# Check if a variable exists in a list in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a script in bash that check the validity of a user input.
I want to match the input (say variable `x`) to a list of valid values.

what I have come up with at the moment is:

```
for item in $list
do
    if [ "$x" == "$item" ]; then
        echo "In the list"
        exit
    fi
done
```

My question is if there is a simpler way to do this,
something like a `list.contains(x)` for most programming languages.

Say list is:

```
list="11 22 33"
```

my code will echo the message only for those values since `list` is treated as an array and not a string,
all the string manipulations will validate `1` while I would want it to fail.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

```
[[ $list =~ (^|[[:space:]])$x($|[[:space:]]) ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```

or create a function:

```
contains() {
    [[ $1 =~ (^|[[:space:]])$2($|[[:space:]]) ]] && exit(0) || exit(1)
}
```

to use it:

```
contains aList anItem
echo $? # 0： match, 1: failed
```

Comment: should be `[[ $list =~ (^| )$x($| ) ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'`

Comment: May give false positive if the user input contains regular expression special characters, for example `x=.`

Comment: This will give no false positives/negatives: `contains () { [[ "$1" =~ (^|[[:space:]])"$2"($|[[:space:]]) ]]; }`.

Comment: a more succinct solution: `[[ " $list " =~ " $x " ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'`.
it's correct assuming space is the separator and `$x` doesn't contain space

Comment: I think it's better to use a "is in" function `isIn()` so you can write the item first in parameters. Also you can `echo` something instead of using `exit` like this : `[[ $2 =~ (^|[[:space:]])$1($|[[:space:]]) ]] && echo 1 || echo 0` So you can use the function this way : `result=$(isIn "-t" "-o -t 45") && echo $result`

Comment: the answer just errors out; syntax error near unexpected token. And @skozin's version always returns 1, even if the string isn't in the list.

Comment: `scripts/1.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token \`0' `                                                                                                                                                                                           
`scripts/1.sh: line 5: \`    [[ $1 =~ (^|[[:space:]])$2($|[[:space:]]) ]] && exit(0) || exit(1)'`

Comment: I'm getting the same error as Kamil. Switching to the "echo-return" version (`...]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"`) works as expected, but that's not how a function should return <citation needed>.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673700/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-0) seems to be the solution (`exit 0` instead of `exit(0)`)

Comment: "_that's not how a function should return_" - I was wrong, it appears that in Bash that is exactly how a function (which is expected to be used as a condition in an if-statement) should return: https://velenux.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/how-to-use-a-bash-function-in-an-if-statement/

Answer (score 97):

how about

```
echo $list | grep -w -q $x
```

you could either check the output  or  `$?` of above line to make the decision.

`grep -w` checks on whole word patterns. Adding `-q` prevents echoing the list.

Comment: wouldn't this validate "val" if "value" is valid (i.e. in the list) since it is its substring

Comment: Yes, it would, as does the accepted answer. @glennjackman gives a working solution.

Comment: you can use grep -q to make grep to be quiet

Comment: this would also accept partial matches, which may not be what the user wants

Comment: @carnicer then just use grep -w $x to have an exact match

Comment: I'm doing `RESULT=$(echo " a b c " | grep -oP " $INPUT ")`. My specific use case is simple enough that relying on spaces to surround everything will work.

Comment: This only works on a string and not a declared list / array

Comment: This needs grep, but given this tool is available on almost any modern Linux/Unix system, it is by far the more simple  and legible solution.

Comment: This solution is wonderful!  I'm using it to check a cURL HTTP response code matches one of the codes in a list.  It's incredibly concise.  Nice work!

Comment: `grep -w` has its pitfalls, for example the dash is considered a word separator, therefore `echo foo-bar | grep -w foo` matches. It might or might not be what you want. More precisely, from the man page: « _Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore_ »

Answer (score 49):

Matvey is right, but you should quote $x and consider any kind of "spaces" (e.g. new line) with

```
[[ $list =~ (^|[[:space:]])"$x"($|[[:space:]]) ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```

so, i.e.

```
# list_include_item "10 11 12" "2"
function list_include_item {
  local list="$1"
  local item="$2"
  if [[ $list =~ (^|[[:space:]])"$item"($|[[:space:]]) ]] ; then
    # yes, list include item
    result=0
  else
    result=1
  fi
  return $result
}
```

end then

```
`list_include_item "10 11 12" "12"`  && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

or

```
if `list_include_item "10 11 12" "1"` ; then
  echo "yes"
else 
  echo "no"
fi
```

Note that you must use `""` in case of variables:

```
`list_include_item "$my_list" "$my_item"`  && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

Comment: This solution works even if `$item` contains special chars, like `.` (but the `$list` variable probably needs to be quoted inside the test). And the function may be defined even simpler: `contains () { [[ "$1" =~ (^|[[:space:]])"$2"($|[[:space:]]) ]]; }`.

Comment: doesn't work in cases like:
`list="aa bb xx cc ff"` and `x="aa bb"`

Comment: hello. I'm trying to learn bashscript fundamentals and I wanted to know how you could parse string of list, into list, and you do the exist check in that list. I can understand you split using space but I couldn't fully understand the expression. Can you provide me the keywords to Google the fundamentals of this expression: `$list =~ (^|[[:space:]])"$item"($|[[:space:]])`. Or, if you have time, I would be glad to hear your explanation for this expression. Note: I  guess it's a regex expression (starts with ^ etc) but I don't know what =~ means. So I'd love an overall explanation:P

Answer (score 47):

IMHO easiest solution is to prepend and append the original string with a space and check against a regex with `[[ ]]`

```
haystack='foo bar'
needle='bar'

if [[ " $haystack " =~ .*\ $needle\ .* ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

this will not be false positive on values with values containing the needle as a substring, e.g. with a haystack `foo barbaz`.

(The concept is shamelessly stolen form JQuery's `hasClass()`-Method)

Comment: if the separator is not space, the solution is more obvious.
it can also be done without regex:

`haystack="foo:bar"` and
`[[ ":$haystack:" = *:$needle:* ]]`

Comment: If you're using =~ and quote the needle, you don't need any wildcards (no matter the separator): `[[ " $haystack " =~ " $needle " ]]` (see [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15394738/8672460)).

Answer (score 26):

There's a cleaner way to check if string is in the list:

```
if [[ $my_str = @(str1|str2|str3) ]]; then
    echo "string found"
fi
```

Comment: Where is this notation documented?

Comment: I too have never seen this before. It is documented here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching. _"@(pattern-list): Matches one of the given patterns."_

This also requires the `extglob` shell option to be enabled: _"If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, the shell recognizes several extended pattern matching operators."_ There are some similar operators listed which are also interesting.

Comment: How do you use this with an array? Feels like an incomplete answer at the moment.

Answer (score 23):

If it isn't too long; you can just string them between equality along a logical OR comparison like so.

```
if [ $ITEM == "item1" -o $ITEM == "item2" -o $ITEM == "item3" ]; then
    echo In the list
fi
```

I had this exact problem and while the above is ugly it is more obvious what is going on than the other generalized solutions.

Comment: Used this but with `||` instead of `-o`.

Comment: If I have 300 items?, based on your answer seems to me that I have to add 300 conditionals.

Answer (score 20):

You can use  (* wildcards) outside a case statement, too, if you use double brackets:

```
string='My string';

if [[ $string == *My* ]]
then
echo "It's there!";
fi
```

Comment: This will give false positive if "My" is a substring of another string, e.g. string='MyCommand string'.

Comment: It's worth noting that the wildcards (`*My*`) must be on the right side of the test.

Answer (score 18):

If your list of values is to be hard-coded in the script, it's fairly simple to test using `case`.  Here's a short example, which you can adapt to your requirements:

```
for item in $list
do
    case "$x" in
      item1|item2)
        echo "In the list"
        ;;
      not_an_item)
        echo "Error" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
```

If the list is an array variable at runtime, one of the other answers is probably a better fit.

Answer (score 11):

Consider exploiting the keys of [associative arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays). I would presume this outperforms both regex/pattern matching and looping, although I haven't profiled it.

```
declare -A list=( [one]=1 [two]=two [three]='any non-empty value' )
for value in one two three four
do
    echo -n "$value is "
    # a missing key expands to the null string, 
    # and we've set each interesting key to a non-empty value
    [[ -z "${list[$value]}" ]] && echo -n '*not* '
    echo "a member of ( ${!list[*]} )"
done
```

Output:

> ```
> one is a member of ( one two three )
> two is a member of ( one two three )
> three is a member of ( one two three )
> four is *not* a member of ( one two three )
> ```

Comment: ...and you can simplify that replacement (and not rely on `echo -n`) with creative use of parameters: `do is="${list[$value]+is }"; echo "$value ${is:-is *not* }a member of ( ${!list[*]} )"; done`.

Comment: Is there an easy way to create such an array if I have just a (long) list like `list="one two three x y z ..."?

Comment: @OttToomet iterate over your list: `for i in $original_list; do list[$i]=1; done`. this relies on shell word-splitting, which has its quirks and potential problems...would be more reliable if your original list was an indexed array, it's easy to convert an indexed array to an associative array: `for i in "${original_list[@]}"; do list[$i]=1; done`.

Answer (score 10):

If the list is fixed in the script, I like the following the best:

```
validate() {
    grep -F -q -x "$1" <<EOF
item 1
item 2
item 3
EOF
}
```

Then use `validate "$x"` to test if `$x` is allowed.

If you want a one-liner, and don't care about whitespace in item names, you can use this (notice `-w` instead of `-x`):

```
validate() { echo "11 22 33" | grep -F -q -w "$1"; }
```

Notes:

- This is POSIX `sh` compliant.
- `validate` does *not* accept substrings (remove the `-x` option to grep if you want that).
- `validate` interprets its argument as a fixed string, not a regular 
  expression (remove the `-F` option to grep if you want that).

Sample code to exercise the function:

```
for x in "item 1" "item2" "item 3" "3" "*"; do
    echo -n "'$x' is "
    validate "$x" && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"
done
```

Answer (score 6):

I find it's easier to use the form `echo $LIST | xargs -n1 echo | grep $VALUE` as illustrated below:

```
LIST="ITEM1 ITEM2"
VALUE="ITEM1"
if [ -n "`echo $LIST | xargs -n1 echo | grep -e \"^$VALUE`$\" ]; then
    ...
fi
```

This works for a space-separated list, but you could adapt it to any other delimiter (like `:`) by doing the following:

```
LIST="ITEM1:ITEM2"
VALUE="ITEM1"
if [ -n "`echo $LIST | sed 's|:|\\n|g' | grep -e \"^$VALUE`$\"`" ]; then
   ...
fi
```

Note that the `"` are required for the test to work.

Comment: This will cause `LIST="SOMEITEM1 ITEM2"` to return true even though `ITEM1` is not in it

Comment: Good catch, I updated the example with grep -e to exclude partial match.

Comment: I believe there's an extra ` at the end of the "if" statement. Correct form is: [ -n "`echo $LIST | xargs -n1 echo | grep -e \"^$VALUE$\" ]

Answer (score 5):

Thought I'd add my solution to the list.

```
# Checks if element "$1" is in array "$2"
# @NOTE:
#   Be sure that array is passed in the form:
#       "${ARR[@]}"
elementIn () {
    # shopt -s nocasematch # Can be useful to disable case-matching
    local e
    for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done
    return 1
}

# Usage:
list=(11 22 33)
item=22

if elementIn "$item" "${list[@]}"; then
    echo TRUE;
else
    echo FALSE
fi
# TRUE

item=44
elementIn $item "${list[@]}" && echo TRUE || echo FALSE
# FALSE
```

Answer (score 5):

The shell built-in compgen can help here. It can take a list with the -W flag and return any of the potential matches it finds.

```
# My list can contain spaces so I want to set the internal
# file separator to newline to preserve the original strings.
IFS=$'\n'

# Create a list of acceptable strings.
accept=( 'foo' 'bar' 'foo bar' )

# The string we will check
word='foo'

# compgen will return a list of possible matches of the 
# variable 'word' with the best match being first.
compgen -W "${accept[*]}" "$word"

# Returns:
# foo
# foo bar
```

We can write a function to test if a string equals the best match of acceptable strings. This allows you to return a 0 or 1 for a pass or fail respectively.

```
function validate {
  local IFS=$'\n'
  local accept=( 'foo' 'bar' 'foo bar' )
  if [ "$1" == "$(compgen -W "${accept[*]}" "$1" | head -1)" ] ; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}
```

Now you can write very clean tests to validate if a string is acceptable.

```
validate "blah" || echo unacceptable

if validate "foo" ; then
  echo acceptable
else 
  echo unacceptable
fi
```

Comment: Clever use of compgen.

Answer (score 4):

Prior answers don't use [**tr**](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) which I found to be useful with [grep](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html). Assuming that the items in the list are space delimited, to check for an exact match:

```
echo $mylist | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -F -x -q "$myitem"
```

This will return exit code 0 if the item is in the list, or exit code 1 if it isn't.

It's best to use it as a function:

```
_contains () {  # Check if space-separated list $1 contains line $2
  echo "$1" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -F -x -q "$2"
}

mylist="aa bb cc"

# Positive check
if _contains "${mylist}" "${myitem}"; then
  echo "in list"
fi

# Negative check
if ! _contains "${mylist}" "${myitem}"; then
  echo "not in list"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Late to the show?  Following very easy variant was not clearly mentioned yet.  I use `case` for checking simple lists, which is a general Bourne Shell idiom not relying on anything external nor extended:

```
haystack='a b c'
needle='b'

case " $haystack " in (*" $needle "*) :;; (*) false;; esac
```

- Please note the use of the separator (here: `SPC`) to correcyly delimit the pattern: At the beginning and end of `" $haystack "` and likewise in the test of `" $needle "`.
- This statement returns `true` (`$?=0`) in case `$needle` is in `$haystack`, false otherwise.
- Also you can test for more than one `$needle` very easily.  When there are several similar cases like
  `if (haystack.contains(needle1)) { run1() } elif (haystack.contains(needle2)) { run2() } else { run3() }`
  you can wrap this into the `case`, too:
  `case " $haystack " in (*" $needle1 "*) run1;; (*" $needle2 "*) run2;; (*) run3;; esac`
  and so on

This also **works for all lists with values which do not include the separator itself**, like comma:

```
haystack=' a , b , c '
needle=' b '

case ",$haystack," in (*",$needle,"*) :;; (*) false;; esac
```

Note that if values can contain anything including the separator sequence (except `NUL`, as shells do not suport `NUL` in variables as you cannot pass arguments containing `NUL` to commands) then you need to use arrays.  Arrays are ksh/bashisms and not supported by "ordinary" POSIX/Bourne shells.  (You can work around this limitation using `$@` in POSIX-Shells, but this is something completely different than what was aked here.)

Can the `(*) false` part be left away?

- No, as this is the critical return value.  By default `case` returns `true`.
- Yes if you do not need the return value and put your processing at the location of the `:`

Why the `:;;`

- We could also write `true;;`, but I am used to use `:` instead of `true` because it is shorter and faster to type
- Also I consider not writing anything bad practice, as it is not obvious to everybody that the default return value of `case` is true.
- Also "leaving out" the command usually indicates "something was forgotten here".  So putting a redundant ":" there clearly indicates "it is intended to do nothing else than return true here".

In `bash` you can also use ksh/bashisms like `;&` (fallthroug) or `;;&` (test other patterns) to express `if (haystack.contains(needle1)) { run1(); }; if (haystack.contains(needle2)) { run2(); }`

Hence usually `case` is much more maintainable than other regex constructs.  Also it does not use regex, it only use shell patterns, which might even be faster.

---

Reusable function:

```
: Needle "list" Seperator_opt
NeedleListSep()
{
  if [ 3 -gt $# ]; 
  then NeedleListSep "$1" "$2" " ";
  else case "$3$2$3" in (*"$3$1$3"*) return 0;; esac; return 1;
  fi;
}
```

In `bash` you can simplify this to

```
: Needle "list" Seperator_opt
NeedleListSep()
{
  local s="${3-" "}";
  case "$s$2$s" in (*"$s$1$s"*) return 0;; esac; return 1;
}
```

Use like this

```
Test() {
NeedleListSep "$1" "a b c"           && echo found $1 || echo no $1;
NeedleListSep "$1" "a,b,c"     ','   && echo found $1 || echo no $1;
NeedleListSep "$1" "a # b # c" ' # ' && echo found $1 || echo no $1;
NeedleListSep "$1" "abc"       ''    && echo found $1 || echo no $1;
}
Test a
Test z
```

As shown above, this also works for degerated cases where the separator is the empty string (so each character of the list is a needle).  Example:

```
Test
```

returns

```
no
no
no
found
```

As the empty string is cleary part of `abc` in case your separator is the empty string, right?

> Note that this function is Public Domain as there is absolutely nothing to it which can be genuinely copyrighted.

Answer (score 3):

Simple oneliner...

```
if [[ " 11 22 33 " == *" ${x} "* ]]; then echo "${x} is in the list"; fi;
```

Add before fi: `else echo "${x} is NOT in the list";`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution inspired by the accepted response, but that uses an inverted logic:

```
MODE="${1}"

echo "<${MODE}>"
[[ "${MODE}" =~ ^(preview|live|both)$ ]] && echo "OK" || echo "Uh?"
```

Here, the input ($MODE) must be one of the options in the regular expression ('preview', 'live', or 'both'), contrary to matching the whole options list to the user input. Of course, you do not expect the regular expression to change.

Answer (score 1):

### Examples

```
$ in_list super test me out
NO

$ in_list "super dude" test me out
NO

$ in_list "super dude" test me "super dude"
YES

# How to use in another script
if [ $(in_list $1 OPTION1 OPTION2) == "NO" ]
then
  echo "UNKNOWN type for param 1: Should be OPTION1 or OPTION2"
  exit;
fi
```

### in_list

```
function show_help()
{
  IT=$(CAT <<EOF

  usage: SEARCH_FOR {ITEM1} {ITEM2} {ITEM3} ...

  e.g. 

  a b c d                    -> NO
  a b a d                    -> YES
  "test me" how "test me"    -> YES

  )
  echo "$IT"
  exit
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  show_help
fi

SEARCH_FOR=$1
shift;

for ITEM in "$@"
do
  if [ "$SEARCH_FOR" == "$ITEM" ]
  then
    echo "YES"
    exit;
  fi
done

echo "NO"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming TARGET variable can be only 'binomial' or 'regression', then following would do:

```
# Check for modeling types known to this script
if [ $( echo "${TARGET}" | egrep -c "^(binomial|regression)$" ) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "This scoring program can only handle 'binomial' and 'regression' methods now." >&2
    usage
fi
```

You could add more strings into the list by separating them with a | (pipe) character.

Advantage of using egrep, is that you could easily add case insensitivity (-i), or check more complex scenarios with a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost your original proposal but almost a 1-liner. Not that complicated as other valid answers, and not so depending on bash versions (can work with old bashes).

```
OK=0 ; MP_FLAVOURS="vanilla lemon hazelnut straciatella"
for FLAV in $MP_FLAVOURS ; do [ $FLAV == $FLAVOR ] && { OK=1 ; break; } ; done
[ $OK -eq 0 ] && { echo "$FLAVOR not a valid value ($MP_FLAVOURS)" ; exit 1 ; }
```

I guess my proposal can still be improved, both in length and style.

Answer (score 0):

The script below implements contains function for a list.

```bash
    function contains {
      local target=$1
      shift
    
      printf '%s\n' "$@" | grep -x -q "$target"
      out=$?
      (( out = 1 - out ))
      return $out
    }
```

If you convert a string based on white space into a list and use it, it seems to be solved as follows.

```bash
    list="11 22 33"
    IFS=" " read -ra parsed_list <<< "$list"
    
    # parsed_list would be ("11" "22" "33")
    
    contains "11" "${parsed_list[@]}"
    echo $?  # 1
    
    contains "22" "${parsed_list[@]}"
    echo $?  # 1
    
    contains "1" "${parsed_list[@]}"
    echo $? # 0
    
    contains "11 22" "${parsed_list[@]}"
    echo $? # 0
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality), and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It may be obvious to you. To others it may not. Please explain what it does, and how it's different from existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter version of Kent's answer, without the `echo`:

```
grep -wq term <<< "item1 item2 item3"
```