# IF statement multiple and or conditions

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using if statement with multiple condition in bash.

How can I reduce the following line syntax. So that it looks good from design point of you.

```
 if [ "$1" != "-l" ] && [ "$1" != "-a" ] && [ "$1" != "-h" ] && [ "$1" != "" ] && [ "$1" =  "-d" ] || [ "$1" = "-mv" ] || [ "$1" = "-dv" ] || [ "$1" = "-mr" ] || [ "$1" = "-dr" ];
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps make a list of valid/invalid values, then [check if that list does/doesn't contains `$1`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063228/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-a-list-in-bash)

Comment: Maybe you want to use the `getopt` command to parse command line options for you?

Comment: @G.Sliepen, [the best-practice approaches](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) don't involve `getopt`.

Comment: @John1024, why did you delete your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern matching.

```
if [[ $1 && $1 != -[lah] && $1 == -@(d|mv|dv|mr|dr) ]]; then
```

`@(...)` is an example of an extended pattern, which should be recognized by default inside `[[ ... ]]` in recent versions of `bash`. If you version is not so recent, add `shopt -s extglob` to the beginning of your script.

---

In fact, you can drop the `$1 && $1 != -[lah]` because its truth would be implied by the truth of `$1 == -@(...)`.

```
if [[ $1 == -@(d|mv|dv|mr|dr) ]]; then
```

---

You could also just use a POSIX-compliant `case` statement:

```
case $1 of
 -d|-mv|-dv|-mr|-dr) echo good option ;;
 *) echo bad option ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 arrays for matching and non matching values and check if element $1 matches any element in the array or not like below.

```
nonmatch_array=( "-l" "-a" "-h" "" )
match_array=(  "-d" "-mv" "-dv" "-mr" "-dr" )

if [ `echo ${match_array[@]} | grep "$1"` ] || ! [ `echo ${nonmatch_array[@]} | grep "$1"` ] ; then 
    echo "is in array"
else 
    echo "is not in array"
fi
```

Hope it should work for you.

Comment: `grep -q` always emits nothing, and ```[ `...` ]``` is evaluating the stdout of your `...` as a test (if it's a single word without meaning to the test command, checking whether that word is or is not empty; but with `grep -q`, it's **always** empty).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: My bad, somehow missed that.. updated the answer. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: There's still improvement to be made here -- using `grep` is very slow; consider rewriting to use an associative array to do all the tests in-process in O(1) time.

Comment: ...or, even if you don't do that, `[[ $string = $target ]]` will tell you whether `$string` matches `$target` much faster than calling out to `grep` will. (Also, `grep` is looking for a substring, but if the OP wants nonmatch_array to be empty, *everything* is a substring of `""`, so that's obviously an incorrect interpretation).

Comment: Agreed for pattern match. But in the case of substring match,  it can match other strings as well, which is not needed. As per the OP's question, he wants to match exact.

Comment: `grep` is not an exact match without arguments you aren't giving it. Thus, I was explaining a substring match (pre-editing) *because that's what your code already did*.

Comment: `[[ $string = "$target" ]]` is already implicitly anchored, and is thus not a substring match; it would be `[[ $string = *"$target"* ]]` to be a substring match.

Answer (score 0):

First try to limit the length of the code on 1 line.

```
if [  [ "$1" != "-l" ] 
   && [ "$1" != "-a" ]
   && [ "$1" != "-h" ] 
   && [ -n "$1" ] 
   && ( [ "$1" = "-d" ]
   || [ "$1" = "-mv" ]
   || [ "$1" = "-dv" ]
   || [ "$1" = "-mr" ]
   || [ "$1" = "-dr" ] ) ];
```

I added braces, to make clear what you mean with the or's.

Now you can combine all matches with a regular expression:

```
   if [[ ! ("$a" =~ ^-(l|a|h|d|)$)
      &&    "$a" =~ ^-(mv|dv|mr|dr)$ ]]; then
      echo "Yes $a matches"
   fi
```

but reconsider what you are testing. The test will only be true when it matches `-mv/-dv/-mr/-dr`, so you do not need to test for the options `lah`.

```
   if [[ "$a" =~ ^-(d|mv|dv|mr|dr)$ ]]; then
      echo "Yes $a matches"
   fi
```

You can use a variable for extracting the options:

```
   options="d|mv|dv|mr|dr"
   if [[ "$a" =~ ^-(${options})$ ]]; then
      echo "Yes $a matches"
   fi
```

Everytime the code is becoming hard to read (and also for long code or repeating statements), you should consider using a function.
The next function is short, but hard to read:

```
options="d|mv|dv|mr|dr"
function checkoption1 {
   [[ "$a" =~ ^-(${options})$ ]]
}
checkoption1 "$a" &&
   echo "Yes $a matches"
```

I would choose for a slightly more verbose function. I will include your original tests for `lah` for showing the possibilities.

```
# checkoption return 0 for match,
# returns 1 for forbidden option
# returns 2 for undefined option
function checkoption2 {
   case "$1" in
      -d|-mv|-dv|-mr|-dr) return 0 ;;
      -l|-a|-h|"")  return 1;;
      *) return 2;;
   esac
}
checkoption2 "$a" &&
   echo "Yes $a matches"
```

You should make some testruns before accepting your code.
I have made some tests with a small loop (now all answers together)

```
function checkoption1 {
   [[ "$a" =~ ^-(${options})$ ]]
}

# checkoption return 0 for match,
# returns 1 for forbidden option
# returns 2 for undefined option
function checkoption2 {
   case "$1" in
      -d|-mv|-dv|-mr|-dr) return 0 ;;
      -l|-a|-h|"")  return 1;;
      *) return 2;;
   esac
}

for a in -mv mv -mvx -ms -mr -dr; do
       if [[ ! ("$a" =~ ^-(l|a|h|)$)
          &&    "$a" =~ ^-(d|mv|dv|mr|dr)$ ]]; then
          echo "Yes $a matches"
       fi
       if [[ "$a" =~ ^-(d|mv|dv|mr|dr)$ ]]; then
          echo "Yes $a matches"
       fi
       options="d|mv|dv|mr|dr"
       if [[ "$a" =~ ^-(${options})$ ]]; then
          echo "Yes $a matches"
       fi
       checkoption1 "$a" &&
          echo "Yes $a matches"
       checkoption2 "$a" &&
          echo "Yes $a matches 2"
 done
```

Comment: Some of this I'm quite sure is nonportable, if correct at all -- such as nested `[`s, or native logic operators (such as `&&`) within that nested context. And using `( ... )` instead of `{ ...; }` for grouping is taking a nontrivial efficiency hit.