# Syntax error near unexpected token "0"

Tags: bash, shell, syntax-error, exit

Ok I know this has been posted a lot by bash newcomers but still, this is the program a teacher gave me, and it's not working properly.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "month"
read month
case $month in
   january)
       echo "31" ;;
   february)
       echo "30" ;;
   *)
       echo "INVALID" ;;
esac
exit(0)
```

The terminal gives me two errors,

> ./shell2: line 15 : syntax error near unexpected token "0"
>
> ./shell2: line 15 : `exit(0)'

Could someone explain me one time for all?
Thank you

Comment: Where's line #15? There are 12 in your code sample.

Comment: hehe sorry, i forgot to add two lines, march) and echo "31" ;;

Comment: Don't mark a question "solved" by editing the title - rather accept the answer that solved it for you. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In bash parameters are not put in braces.  It should be `exit 0` instead of `exit(0)`

Comment: Thank you! Now I know it, I won't reproduce this mistake twice.