# Checking whether any file staged for git commit does not match a whitelist

Tags: bash, git, shell, whitelist

Due to some problems with a script which commits and pushes automatically, i'd like to implement a whitelist.

The plan is, that only commits with the pattern 'foo' and 'bar' in path, are allowed.

```
#!/bin/sh

WHITELIST="foo bar"
WRKDIR=/home/athur/workwork/test/repo


cd $WRKDIR
git add -A

for file in `git diff --cached -p --name-status | cut -c3-`; do
  if [[ "$file" == *"$WHITELIST"* ]] ; then
    echo "$file is on whitelist"
  else
    echo "$file is not on whitelist. Commit aborted."
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

The problem is, it's always uses the 'else' clause.
I can't find the problem. Thanks

Comment: If you print out the value of `$file` inside your loop, does it have the values you expect?

Comment: Yes. It has the correct path of that file. E.g. foo/file1.txt

Comment: You're checking if the string `foo bar` is included in your filename. Is that what you want, or do you want to check for the presence of *either* `foo` or `bar`?

Comment: BTW, if you want to read the output of `git diff` line-by-line, a `for` loop is the wrong way to do it; see [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), and [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a discussion of the best-practice alternative.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'd like to test if `foo`,`bar` or both are in the filename.

Comment: `[[ $file = *@(foo|bar)* ]]` would be one valid way to do that (if `shopt -s extglob` is run earlier in your script). See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language

Comment: (BTW, `=` rather than `==` is intentional, as the former is the only version guaranteed to work in `[ ]` in all POSIX-compliant shells; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a best-practices approach, consider:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ important: [[ ]] is not guaranteed to work with bin/sh

whitelist_re='(foo|bar)'
workdir=/home/athur/workwork/test/repo

cd -- "$workdir" || exit
git add -A

while IFS= read -r filename; do
  if [[ $file =~ $whitelist ]]; then
    echo "$file is on whitelist" >&2
  else
    echo "$file is not on whitelist; commit aborted." >&2
    exit 1
  fi
done < <(git diff --cached --name-only)
```

To walk through the changes:

- The shebang specifies `bash` as a shell, which guarantees that extensions like `[[ ]]` and `<(...)` will be available -- a guarantee not made with `/bin/sh`.
- A `while read` loop is used rather than attempting to iterate over line-oriented data with `for`; see [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) for an explanation of the reasoning behind this change.
- The whitelist is specified as an ERE-compliant regular expression, such that `=~` can be used to test whether a value matches.
- Instead of using `git diff --cached --name-status` and then using `cut` to remove the status data after-the-fact, we use `--name-only` to generate only names in the first place.
- Using lowercase variable names complies with the conventions given in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, specifying that POSIX-defined tools will use all-caps shell and environment variable names for their own purposes, and that names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use. (Keep in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so these conventions apply even when `export` is not in use).

---

By the way, if you just wanted to find out if any non-matches exist, without knowing which files those are, you could use:

```
#!/bin/sh
#      ^^ actually safe here, as no non-POSIX functionality is used

whitelist_re='foo|bar'

if git diff --cached --name-only | grep -qEv "$whitelist_re"; then
  echo "At least one file is not on whitelist; commit aborted" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using an explicit list**

The `==` is not symmetric in this case and `**` seems to be used badly.

Try `"$WHITELIST" == *"$file"*`.

(Inspired by [How do I check if a variable exists in a list in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063228/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-a-list-in-bash))

Note that using your `WHITELIST`, only files `foo` and `bar` will be whitelisted.

**Detecting a pattern**

If you need to detect individual patterns, you may need to construct a function such as:

```
for entry in $WHITELIST ; do 
  if [[ "$file" =~ $entry ]] ; then
    return 0
  fi
done
return 1
```

Comment: Still always in the else clause

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. That's it. Using your solution solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @qwertbert23, ...glad to hear! Since the author of this answer hasn't amended it to accept the suggestion, I'll add my own with it present.