# Check list of hosts for hostname and run if app isn't installed

Tags: bash, shell

Having some issues checking whether the hostname of the current host matches a whitelist  and running an if statement that only runs if the host matches the whitelist and an application is installed. Here's what I have.. where am I going wrong? It's always returning `exit 1` no matter what.

```
#!/bin/bash

WHITELIST=(host1 host2 host3)

printf -- '%s\n' "${WHITELIST[@]}" | grep $HOSTNAME

if [ -e "/Applications/myapp.app" ] && [ $? = 1 ];
then
    echo "myapp exists and hostname doesn't match whitelist"
    exit 0
else
    echo "myapp doesn't exist or hostname matches whitelist"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a variable exists in a list in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063228/check-if-a-variable-exists-in-a-list-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that `$?` is the result of `[ -e "/Applications/myapp.app" ]`. You'll want to avoid the antipattern anyway; see
[Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

I'm guessing you also want to avoid using the host name as a regular expression for `grep` (add `-F`), or check whether it's a substring of anything on the whitelist (add `-x` to match whole lines only).

Tangentially, [avoid upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

whitelist=(host1 host2 host3)

if [ -e "/Applications/myapp.app" ] &&
    ! printf -- '%s\n' "${whitelist[@]}" | grep -xF "$hostname"
then
    echo "myapp exists and hostname doesn't match whitelist"
    exit 0
else
    echo "myapp doesn't exist or hostname matches whitelist"
    exit 1
fi
```

The `--` in `printf` isn't strictly necessary, since you are in complete control over the format string, and it doesn't start with a dash.

Ideally, you'd probably want to avoid using an external process (`grep`) for anything the shell can handle natively; see also [Check if a variable exists in a list in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063228/check-if-a-variable-exists-in-a-list-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks - all of your points make a lot of sense. Unfortunately it still doesn't look like it's working, I'm getting exit 1 each time even if I change the whitelist. I'll keep working on it and see what I can do - any more ideas?

Comment: I've narrowed it downto the printf statement + grep. If I remove that out then the exit codes work as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the negation; fixed now, I hope.