# Bash script with multiline variable

Tags: bash

Here is my code

```
vmname="$1"
EXCEPTLIST="desktop-01|desktop-02|desktop-03|desktop-04"
if [[ $vmname != @(${EXCEPTLIST}) ]]; then
    echo "${vmname}"
else
echo "Its in the exceptlist"
fi
```

The above code works perfectly but my question is , the EXCEPTLIST can be a long line, say 100 server names. In that case its hard to put all that names in one line. In that situation is there any way to make the variable EXCEPTLIST to be a multiline variable ? something like as follows:

```
    EXCEPTLIST="desktop-01|desktop-02|desktop-03| \n
                desktop-04|desktop-05|desktop-06| \n
                desktop-07|desktop-08"
```

I am not sure but was thinking of possibilities.

Apparently I would like to know the terminology of using `@(${})`- Is this called variable expansion or what ? Does anyone know the documentation/explain to me  about how this works in bash. ?

Comment: See "Pattern Matching" section of bash manual: `@(pattern-list)` Matches one of the given patterns

Comment: A backslash, immediately followed by a carriage return, marks  a continuation line. However, for checking whether one string is part of the list, I would rather use an associative array (where its keys are the listelement) instead of a single string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a variable exists in a list in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8063228/7939871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can declare an array if the data/string is long/large. Use `IFS` and `printf` for the format string, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exceptlist=(
 desktop-01
 desktop-02
 desktop-03
 desktop-04
 desktop-05
 desktop-06
)

pattern=$(IFS='|'; printf '@(%s)' "${exceptlist[*]}")

[[ "$vmname" != $pattern ]] && echo good
```

---

> In that situation is there any way to make the variable EXCEPTLIST to be a multiline variable ?

With your given input/data an array is also a best option, something like:

```
exceptlist=(
  'desktop-01|desktop-02|desktop-03'
  'desktop-04|desktop-05|desktop-06'
  'desktop-07|desktop-08'
)
```

---

Check what is the value of `$pattern` variable one way is:

```
declare -p pattern
```

Output:

```
declare -- pattern="@(desktop-01|desktop-02|desktop-03|desktop-04|desktop-05|desktop-06)"
```

---

- Need to test/check if `$vmname` is an empty string too, since it will always be true.
- On a side note, don't use all upper case variables for purely internal purposes.
- The `$(...)` is called `Command Substitution`.

  - See `LESS=+'/\ *Command Substitution' man bash`

---

In addition to what was mentioned in the comments about `pattern matching`

- See `LESS=+/'(pattern-list)' man bash`
- See `LESS=+/' *\[\[ expression' man bash`

Answer (score 1):

> s there any way to make the variable EXCEPTLIST to be a multiline variable ?

I see no reason to use matching. Use a bash array and just compare.

```
exceptlist=(
   desktop-01
   desktop-02
   desktop-03
   desktop-04
   desktop-05
   desktop-06
)

is_in_list() {
   local i
   for i in "${@:2}"; do
      if [[ "$1" = "$i" ]]; then
          return 0
      fi
   done
   return 1
}

if is_in_list "$vmname" "${EXCEPTLIST[@]}"; then
    echo "is in exception list ${vmname}"
fi
```

> @(${})- Is this called variable expansion or what ? Does anyone know the documentation/explain to me about how this works in bash. ?

`${var}` is a variable expansion.

`@(...)` are just characters `@` `(` `)`.

From `man bash` in `Compund commands`:

```
   [[ expression ]]

          When the == and != operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules
          described below under Pattern Matching, as if the extglob shell option were enabled. ...
```

From `Pattern Matching` in `man bash`:

```
          @(pattern-list)
                 Matches one of the given patterns
```

`[[` command receives the `@(a|b|c)` string and then matches the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need to use Bash specific regex or arrays and loop for a match, if using `grep` for raw string on word boundary.
The exception list can be multi-line, it will work as well:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/sh

exceptlist='
desktop-01|desktop-02|desktop-03|
deskop-04|desktop-05|desktop-06|
desktop-07|deskop-08'

if printf %s "$exceptlist" | grep -qwF "$1"; then
  printf '%s is in the exceptlist\n' "$1" 
fi
```

Comment: Well done for making it work with `grep`. Normally `grep` would take regex which could lead to unintended regex handling which you disabled with the use of `-F`. The other caveat is sanitizing of inputs to avoid unintended sequences, which you've avoided using quotes. However, there are issues with your solution with "desktop" and "01" appearing as false positive matches.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with multiple lines of text. This is would be just fine:

```bash
EXCEPTLIST='desktop-01|desktop-02|desktop-03|'
EXCEPTLIST+='desktop-04|desktop-05|desktop-06|'
EXCEPTLIST+='desktop-07|desktop-08'
```

The `@(...)` construct is called *extended globbing pattern* and what it does is an extension of what you probably already know -- wildcards:

```bash
VAR='foobar'
if [[ "$VAR" == fo?b* ]]; then
    echo "Yes!"
else
    echo "No!"
fi
```

A quick walkthrough on extended globbing examples: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to load a multiline string into a variable:

```bash
fn() {
  cat <<EOF
desktop-01|desktop-02|desktop-03|
desktop-04|desktop-05|desktop-06|
desktop-07|desktop-08
EOF
}

exceptlist="$(fn)"
echo $exceptlist
```

As to solving your specific problem, I can think of a variety of approaches.

Solution 1, since all the desktop has the same `desktop-0` prefix and only differ in the last letter, we can make use of {,} or {..} expansion as follows:

```bash
vmname="$1"
found=0
for d in desktop-{01..08}
do
  if [[ "$vmname" == $d ]]; then
    echo "It's in the exceptlist"
    found=1
    break
  fi
done
if (( !found )); then
  echo "Not found"
fi
```

Solution 2, sometimes, it is good to provide a list in a maintainable clear text list. We can use a while loop and iterate through the list

```bash
vmname="$1"
found=0
while IFS= read -r d
do
  if [[ "$vmname" == $d ]]; then
    echo "It's in the exceptlist"
    found=1
    break
  fi
done <<EOF
desktop-01
desktop-02
desktop-03
desktop-04
desktop-05
desktop-06
desktop-07
desktop-08
EOF
if (( !found )); then
  echo "Not found"
fi
```

Solution 3, we can desktop the servers using regular expressions:

```bash
vmname="$1"
if [[ "$vmname" =~ ^desktop-0[1-8]$ ]]; then
  echo "It's in the exceptlist"
else
  echo "Not found"
fi
```

Solution 4, we populate an array, then iterate through an array:

```bash
vmname="$1"
exceptlist=()
exceptlist+=(desktop-01 desktop-02 desktop-03 deskop-04)
exceptlist+=(desktop-05 desktop-06 desktop-07 deskop-08)
found=0
for d in ${exceptlist[@]}
do
  if [[ "$vmname" == "$d" ]]; then
    echo "It's in the exceptlist"
    found=1
    break;
  fi
done
if (( !found )); then
  echo "Not found"
fi
```

Comment: You don't need the `found` "boolean" variable: `for d in "${exceptlist[@]}"; do [[ "$vmname" == "$d" ]] && break; done && printf '%s is in the exceptlist\n' "$vmname"`

Comment: Thanks @LéaGris, when I was writing it I was mentally thinking about both the `found` and `!found` cases mentally. The idea being was to show it being calculated but leave it up to the OP to adapt, but, since your feedback, I decided to explicitly show messages for both cases.

Comment: The method without boolean variable, works as well to deal with both cases found and not found `if for d in "${exceptlist[@]}"; do [[ "$vmname" == "$d" ]] && break; done then printf '%s is in the exceptlist\n' "$vmname"; else printf '%s not found\n' "$vmname"; fi`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

set +o posix
shopt -s extglob

vmname=$1

EXCEPTLIST=(
    desktop-01 desktop-02 desktop-03
    ...
)

if IFS='|' eval '[[ ${vmname} == @(${EXCEPTLIST[*]}) ]]'; then
    ...
```