# like clause in if

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

The following is working as expected.

```
for schema in `mysql -e"show databases"`
do
if [[ $schema = 'test' ]];then
echo $schema
fi
done
```

But when I need to select all values starting with test, the following does not work for obvious reasons...

```
if [[ $schema = 'test%' ]];then
```

I want to select the other values like test_db, test123 etc.

Comment: Check if an array contains a value in bash: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3685970/1007273

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use bash regexes:

```
if [[ $schema =~ ^test ]]; then
```

Answer (score 4):

Plain shell patterns will work too, since this does not really require a regular expression:

```
if [[ $schema == test* ]]; ...
```

See the documentation for `[[  ]]` -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-g_t_005b_005b-57

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use wildcards (regular expressions) in `bash`:

```
pax> if [[ test123 =~ ^test.* ]] ; then echo yes ;fi
yes
```

From the `bash` manpage:

> An  additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched  accordingly  (as in  regex(3)).
>
> The  return  value  is  0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.  If the regular expression is syntactically incorrect, the conditional expression's return value is 2.
>
> If  the  shell  option nocasematch  is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters.  Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string.
>
> Substrings matched by parenthesized  sub‐expressions  within  the  regular  expression  are  saved  in the array variable BASH_REMATCH.  The element of BASH_REMATCH with index 0 is the portion of the string matching the entire regular expression.  The element of BASH_REMATCH with index n is the portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to move the check and do:

```
for schema in $( mysql -e"show databases" | grep ^test )
```