# if queue $name== "already there" then

Tags: bash, if-statement

is ist Possible, that i check the names in a until queue ?

```
b=1      
 read -p "Enter how much databases you want to install: " COUNTER
    until [ ${a} -eq ${COUNTER} ]; do

    a=$((a+1))


    echo "What is the name for the $((b++)) database ?"
        read name

    if [ $name == "already there" ]; then
    echo " Please, don't use the same name for a database!"
    exit 1
    else
    :
    fi
```

I want, that the script exit when the name is already there...

any ideas ?

Comment: Is the name a filename, or what?  How do you know if it is "already there"?

Comment: No that was only a synonym for you guys, that you know what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATED

you need to save entered name into array, and check whether newly inserted name is in there or not  . array array checking is came from here. [Check if an array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/bash-check-if-an-array-contains-a-value)

```
#!/bin/bash

has_element ()
{
  local e
  for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}

b=1
read -p "Enter how much databases you want to install: " COUNTER

let -a CONTAINER

a=0
until [ ${a} == ${COUNTER} ]
do
    a=$((a+1))

    echo "What is the name for the $((b++)) database ?"
    read name


    if has_element "$name" "${CONTAINER[@]}"
    then
        echo "already has"
        exit
    fi

    CONTAINER+=($name)

done
```

### Orig. Answer

I think you're almost there. modified some error.

```
b=1
read -p "Enter how much databases you want to install: " COUNTER

a=0
until [ ${a} == ${COUNTER} ]
do
    a=$((a+1))

    echo "What is the name for the $((b++)) database ?"
    read name

    if [ "$name" == "already there" ]
    then
        echo " Please, don't use the same name for a database!"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "stay..."
    fi

done
```

Comment: That "already there" was only a synonym for you that you know what i mean.

Comment: @user3057030 So, my script is still not working? What is real value? could you give us same value?

Comment: it is running in an until queue so the variable "name" gets everytime a new value..

Comment: For example, when i tipp in in the first time "CHERRY" for the name and the second time "APPLE" and than for the third time again "CHERRY" that the script exit 1

Comment: @user3057030 Aha~ I got it. but, currently I'm working my job. wait a minute or somebody

Comment: @user3057030 you're very welcome. I have also googled. I learned alot. thanks.

Comment: You probably want your shebang line to be `#!/bin/bash`, or your script will break on distributions where `/bin/sh` is not Bash (e.g. Ubuntu, where it's Dash).

Answer (score 1):

Use double brackets to enclose your condition or double quote your variable :

```
if [[ $name == "already there" ]]; then
    echo " Please, don't use the same name for a database!"
    exit 1
else
    #...
fi
```

or

```
if [ "$name" == "already there" ]; then
    echo " Please, don't use the same name for a database!"
    exit 1
else
    #...
fi
```

Comment: I will use `if [ "x$name" == "xalready there" ]; then` in case user just presses Enter without giving any value to $name