# grep through array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

Is it possible to grep an array in bash?  Basically I have two arrays, one array I want to loop through and the other array I want to check to see if each string is in the other array or not.

Rough example:

```
for CLIENTS in ${LIST[@]}; do
    #lost as to best way to grep a array with out putting the values    in a file.
    grep ${server_client_list[@]}
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash provides **substring matching**. This eliminates the need to spawn external processes and subshells. Simply use:

```
for CLIENTS in ${LIST[@]}; do
    if [[ "${server_client_list[@]}" =~ "$CLIENTS" ]]; then
        echo "CLIENTS ($CLIENTS) is in server_client_list"
    fi
done
```

**Note:** this works for `bash`, not `sh`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `grep -f` using **process substitution**:

```
grep -Ff <(printf "%s\n" "${LIST[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${server_client_list[@]}")
```

Comment: Do I need to add a for loop, so that it loops though each string in LIST[@ array?

Comment: @doanerock Try it yourself... `a=(1 2) ; printf "%d\n" "${a[@]}"`

Comment: @doanerock: You don't need to loop. This command will find matching elements of `LIST` that are present in `server_client_list` array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function :

```
function IsInList {
    local i
    for i in "${@:2}"; do
        [ "$i" = "$1" ] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

for CLIENT in "${LIST[@]}"; do
    IsInList "$CLIENT" "${server_client_list[@]}" && echo "It's in the list!"
done
```

Note that the quotes around `${LIST[@]}` and `${server_client_list[@]}` are very important because they guarantee the array expansion to expand the way you want them to, instead of having a bad surprise when a space make its way into one of those array values.

Credits : I took this function from patrik's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-an-array-contains-a-value) when I needed something like that.

**Edit :**

If you were looking for something with regexp capabilities, you could also use the following :

```
function IsInList {
    local i
    for i in "${@:2}"; do
        expr match "$i" "$1" && return 0
    done
    return 1
}
```