# How to check array doesn't contain line in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am reading data from a file line by line and storing it to array, so that I can access later that array to compare with other files data.

Now, my input file has redundancy, how to add only unique lines to array. I need to check while adding to array itself?

Below is the code I am using to read data from file:

```
while read line
do
    //How to check array already contains this line???
        <Code to adding to array>
done <"$file"
```

Comment: What version of bash? How are you planning to use this array later?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-an-array-contains-a-value

Comment: @springuser you should check to see if anyone asked the same trivial question previously. You'll enlighten yourself with wisdom of the ancients of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use associative array for this:

```
declare -A ulines

while IFS= read -r line; do
   [[ ! ${ulines["$line"]} ]] && echo "$line" && ulines["$line"]=1
done < "$file"
```

This will print unique lines on stdout **preserving** original order in input file.

Comment: it's changing the order of lines, how to avoid this, I want to retain order, in which file is read