# Get substring based on position and delimiter in unix

Tags: unix

I have files in some path. Say when i do `ls -lrt` , i get

```
20160401_RM_ARN_MAPPING-M_RTL_NORTH_DELH_101.csv
20160401_RM_ARN_MAPPING-M_RTL_NORTH_DELH_102.csv
20160401_RM_ARN_MAPPING-M_BND_NORTH_DELH_102.csv
20160405_RM_ARN_MAPPING-M_RTL_NORTH_DELH_101.csv
20160405_RM_ARN_MAPPING-M_RTL_NORTH_DELH_102.csv
20160401_MAP_RTL_BANK-M_RTL_NORTH_DELH_101.csv
20150401_RM_ARN_MAPPING-M_RTL_NORTH_DELH_101.csv
```

I want the distinct file names after the date and before the "-" delimiter.

I tried

```
ls -lrt | awk '{print $9}' | sed '1d' | awk -F'-' '{print $1}'
```

It gives

```
20160401_RM_ARN_MAPPING
20160401_RM_ARN_MAPPING
20160401_RM_ARN_MAPPING
20160405_RM_ARN_MAPPING
20160405_RM_ARN_MAPPING
20160401_MAP_RTL_BANK
20150401_RM_ARN_MAPPING
```

But I want only

```
RM_ARN_MAPPING 
MAP_RTL_BANK
```

as output, i.e distinct names after removing the date. Here the first 8 characters are fixed and it will be YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: are you using bash? are you in linux? these are things that may be relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can be done this way:-

```
ls -ltr|sed 1d|awk '{print $9}'|cut -d"-" -f1  |cut -d_ -f2-|sort|uniq
```

**explanation**

ls -ltr --> list file

sed 1d --> ignore first

awk '{print $9}' --> print 9th column

others I guess self explanatory

Answer (score 3):

[Do not parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead, loop through the elements in your directory and [keep track of the new names with an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15394738/1983854). To get the clean data, use [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```bash
for file in your_dir/*; do
   no_date=${file#*_}              # remove up to the first _
   no_dash=${no_date%%-*}          # remove from the first -
   [[ " ${var[@]} " =~ " ${no_dash} " ]] || var+=($no_dash)
done
```

Then, check the elements with:

```bash
$ printf "%s\n" "${var[@]}"
RM_ARN_MAPPING
MAP_RTL_BANK
```

Comment: Note that the question specifies `ls -lrt` -- which is (reverse) sort based on modification time.

Comment: @MichaelBack I don't think the sorting is important here

Answer (score 1):

Add `cut -d '_' -f 2-`

That is

```
ls -lrt | awk '{print $9}' | sed '1d' | awk -F'-' '{print $1}' | cut -d '_' -f 2-
```

THe 2- means second part and everything to the end..

Comment: @PavaniSrujana check the other answers and please choose one as accepted.. the other ones are better, mine is just dumbly adding the cut, but its better to not use ls and parse that..

Comment: @otoplosky .I went through all options and using 3 of them in fact at many different palces of my code.thanks a lot

Comment: @PavaniSrujana even so you use more than one, you must look at it as you asked only about one way.. so choose the best answer for your question - in this way you help other people seeking advice on the question you posted. Otherwise the question will forever remain unanswered which would be sad..

Answer (score 1):

This answer avoids parsing `ls` output -- protecting against file names containing odd characters -- emulating `-lrt` safely using `stat` with null character record delimiter output and complementary `sort`.  The `\0` can also be used as an `awk` delimiter, and we can use that tool for the remainder of text manipulation.  The removal of leading numbers and underscore is handled with the regex `/^[^_]+_/`.  The removal of repeated "names" is accomplished via an associative array lookup.

```
stat --printf '%Y %n\0' *_*-*.csv |
    sort -nz |
    awk -v RS='\0' '{
            sub(/^[^_]+_/, "")
            sub(/-.*$/, "")
            if ($0 in y)
                next
            y[$0]=1
            print
    }'
```