# How to simplify the comparison in the bash?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, comparison

how to make several comparisons in the bash by placing the condition and comparison points next to instead of the long queue ?

that something like this

before :

```
if [[ $var == "aaa" || $var == "bbb" || $var == "ccc" || $var == "ddd" ]];
then
 echo "good";
fi
```

after (what I want):

```
if [[ $var==["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"] ]];
then
 echo "good";
fi
```

Comment: A string cannot have more than one content at a time. Describe what you want to compare.

Comment: I think you meant `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: There are several suggestions to build a `contains` function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value#3689445)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using [bash *regex*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/RegularExpression) with the keywork `=~`:

```
if [[ $var =~ ^(aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd)$ ]];
then
 echo "good";
fi
```

### Edit :

As seen in comments, for real you need to compare `int`, not `strings`, so :

```
((var%3 == 0)) && echo "ok"
```

Using [*bash arithmetic*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression)

Comment: I suggest to add `^` and `$`: `^(aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd)$`

Comment: You really need `^` and `$` outside the parentheses just like [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843438/how-to-simplify-the-comparison-in-the-bash/48843617#comment84691216_48843511) suggested. This will match strings like `qbbbq`.

Comment: Oops, doing too much things at the same time, thanks :)

Comment: I will compare the hours of the day, I need every third hour, I will compare the current hour with 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 and send an email, I do not need to compare the lines yet, but thanks a lot, if necessary I will do according to your example

Comment: @ДмитрийСмирнов You might consider using something like `if ! ((var%3)); then echo "good"; fi`.

Comment: @ДмитрийСмирнов: or `[[ $((var%3)) == 0 ]]`

Answer (score 2):

With [extended pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html):

```
shopt -s extglob
[[ $var = @(aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd) ]] && echo "good"
```