# bash check is string contains substring not working

Tags: bash

When I execute below script it works fine:

```
if [[ "[1,2,3]" =~ .*1.* ]]; then
techStatus=1
else 
techStatus=0;
fi
echo $techStatus
```

Output is 1

But when we changes it to variable it does not work.

```
var1=[1,2,3]
var2=1
if [[ "$var1" =~ .*"$var2".* ]]; then
techStatus=1
else 
techStatus=0;
fi
echo $techStatus
```

Output is 0.

Please help me figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: edited it. Missed it last time

Comment: `var2` → `$var2` (or even `"$var2"`)

Comment: tries, not working

Comment: Can’t reproduce; works fine for me (*with* `"$var2"`).

Comment: It works for me, the output is 1

Comment: Try var1=“[1,2,3]”  putting quotes on your variables also you are supposed to write vars ${var1} opposed to $var1 but unrelated minor comment.

Comment: @MikeQ While both good habits, they make no difference in this case.

Comment: @Biffen  wasn’t sure if the quotes were the problem

Comment: See your code with no changes whatsoever working in the online interpreter at https://ideone.com/rtECyG

Comment: Also, note that this doesn't generalize to JSON documents as a whole. You don't want to match `10` because it contains `1`, or a list that contains `"This is a string, not a number at all, but it contains ,1, in its text"` but no entry with just a `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better & readable approach would be to convert `var1` to array and loop through `var1`.

```
var1=(1 2 3)
var2=1
for elem in "${var1[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$elem" -eq "$var2" ]]; then
        techStatus=1
        break
    else
        techStatus=0
    fi
done
echo "$techStatus"
```

Comment: Key by array indices and you don't even have to loop. `var1=( [1]=1 [2]=1 [3]=1 ); if [[ ${var1[$var2]} ]]; then techStatus=1; else techStatus=0; fi` -- if the keys can be non-numeric that means making it an associative array, but that's not much of a change.

Comment: ...that said, posing this as an answer implies that you think the question could be closed as a duplicate of [check if a bash array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value), insofar as the essential elements are all covered there.