# Bash : Accessing array elements (unexpected behavior)

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to run a loop from 1 through 12, match the current loop number against pre-defined arrays then output which array is matched.

Each type of month gets an array.

```
lm #has 4,6,9,11 
hm #has 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 
feb #special case, if its not an hm or lm, its feb
```

Here is my current code :

```
#!/bin/bash
lm=()
lm+=(4)
lm+=(6)
lm+=(9)
lm+=(11)

hm=()
hm+=(1)
hm+=(3)
hm+=(5)
hm+=(7)
hm+=(8)
hm+=(10)
hm+=(12)

feb=()
feb+=(2)

ld=(1 2)
hd=(1 2)
fd=(1 2)
for m in {1..12}
do
echo "current month is $m"
    if [[ " ${hm[*]} " == *"$m"* ]];
    then
        echo "high month"
    elif [[ " ${lm[*]} " == *"$m"* ]];
    then
        echo "low month"
    elif [[ " ${feb[*]} " = *"$m"* ]];
    then
        echo "feb"
    else
        echo "weird month input"
    fi
done
```

Its output :

```
$ ./old2.sh
current month is 1
high month
current month is 2
high month
current month is 3
high month
current month is 4
low month
current month is 5
high month
current month is 6
low month
current month is 7
high month
current month is 8
high month
current month is 9
low month
current month is 10
high month
current month is 11
low month
current month is 12
high month
```

Look at **2**, it is shown as high month (**hm**), ie, it has 31 days.

I have commented out the line that would add 12 or December in the array :

```
#!/bin/bash
lm=()
lm+=(4)
lm+=(6)
lm+=(9)
lm+=(11)

hm=()
hm+=(1)
hm+=(3)
hm+=(5)
hm+=(7)
hm+=(8)
hm+=(10)
#hm+=(12)

feb=()
feb+=(2)

ld=(1 2)
hd=(1 2)
fd=(1 2)
for m in {1..12}
do
echo "current month is $m"
    if [[ " ${hm[*]} " == *"$m"* ]];
    then
        echo "high month"
    elif [[ " ${lm[*]} " == *"$m"* ]];
    then
        echo "low month"
    elif [[ " ${feb[*]} " = *"$m"* ]];
    then
        echo "feb"
    else
        echo "weird month input"
    fi
done
```

New output :

```
$ ./old2.sh
current month is 1
high month
current month is 2
feb
current month is 3
high month
current month is 4
low month
current month is 5
high month
current month is 6
low month
current month is 7
high month
current month is 8
high month
current month is 9
low month
current month is 10
high month
current month is 11
low month
current month is 12
weird month input
```

Now the output is as expected.

Why is my script accepting **2** as **hm**, instead of **feb**, as it should?

Comment: Did the answer work out for you?

Comment: In the future, try to follow [mcve] rules -- distilling your question to *the shortest possible code* (ideally just a few lines!) that shows the misbehavior. See also the "Tricks for Trimming" section at http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Note too that concatenating your array into a string and then doing a substring match on that resulting string is **really** not a reliable way to check membership. We already have Q&A entries that cover doing that right; ie. [Check if a bash array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value).

Comment: thank you Charles Duffy, I'll keep that in mind. Hello Inian, I cannot see your answer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you are using `*"$m"*` as the matching pattern, as a result, when you try to match 2 y also match 12.

In your algorithm you used the whole array as a string and tried to match one element. One quick and dirty solution would be using spaces around your match like:

```
for m in {1..12}
do
echo "current month is $m"
    if [[ " ${hm[*]} " == *" $m "* ]];
    then
        echo "high month"
    elif [[ " ${lm[*]} " == *" $m "* ]];
    then
        echo "low month"
    elif [[ " ${feb[*]} " == *" $m "* ]];
    then
        echo "feb"
    else
        echo "weird month input"
    fi
done
```

There it will work, as " 2 " won't match " 12 ".

However I don't think that is the best approach... Unluckily, bash does not have a syntax to find an element inside an array, but if you check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8574392/6316852 there is a function that perfectly fits your needs.

So, another alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash
lm=(4 6 9 11)
hm=(1 3 5 7 8 10 12)
feb=(2)

containsElement () {
  local e match="$1"
  shift
  for e; do [[ "$e" == "$match" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}

for m in {1..12}; do
    echo "current month is $m"
    if containsElement "$m" "${hm[@]}"; then
        echo "high month"
    elif containsElement "$m" "${lm[@]}"; then
        echo "low month"
    elif containsElement "$m" "${feb[@]}"; then
        echo "feb"
    else
        echo "weird month input"
    fi
done
```

hope it helps

Comment: If you believe a question to be duplicative (and I agree with you, it is!), note the bullet point regarding questions which "*...have already been asked and answered many times before*" in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: BTW, even `containsElement` is slow (being O(n)) compared to an associative-array lookup; if the OP wants to be able to test whether a value exists in an array, they should store that in the *key* field, not as a value. (Bash "arrays" are quite misleadingly named -- they're really what other languages call hashes or maps).