# How to insert dynamic matching pattern in bash?

Tags: bash

I was looking at this link [Check if a Bash array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value) which says how to check for existence of an item in a list as follows:

```
if printf '%s\n' ${myarray[@]} | grep -q -P '^mypattern$'; then
    # ...
fi
```

However, I want `mypattern` value to be passed as a variable as follows:

```
mynewpattern="xyz"
```

then I was expecting the following to work

```
if printf '%s\n' ${myarray[@]} | grep -q -P '^"$mynewpattern"$'; then
    # ...
fi
```

But it is not picking the new pattern of `xyz`. What is the appropriate syntax to insert the new pattern?

I have just started learning bash.

Comment: Use: `grep -q -P "^$mynewpattern$"` that is using double quotes only.

Comment: @anubhava nope, it is not working. My confusion without double quotes is how will bash differentiate between `$` of my variable and `$` of the regex?

Comment: It does work, your pattern may be incorrect. You've got 2 similar answers below. and `$` without anything afterwards is not expanded as variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes are wrong; you want double quotes instead of single.

However, `grep -P` is also slightly wrong here; it's not properly portable, and your pattern doesn't use any of the syntax which `-P` enables; also, you should quote your array properly.

```sh
if printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}" |
    grep -q "^$mypattern\$"
then
    ...
```

Text between single quotes is passed through verbatim. If you want the shell to perform variable interpolation, use double quotes (and then you need to escape any literal backslash, dollar sign, or backtick).

Comment: Thanks it worked and also thank you very much for the explanation. Since, I have just started learning bash and you seem to have mastered bash, could you please recommend me a few resources which I can read more about bash programming?

Comment: There's a brief link collection near the end of tae [Stack Overflow `bash` tag info page.](/tags/bash/info)

Comment: There is no need to escape last `$` however it will work with escaping as well.

Comment: Yeah, I cut a few corners there. The circumstances under which dollar signs *must* be escaped are somewhat more complex but I felt this was adequate for a beginner's understanding.

Comment: @anubhava, yes you are right sir, it works with escaping not sure why for OP it is not working. I just tested on repl site and worked(mentioned in mine example) too, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using like `grep -q -P "^$var$"(in your script)`
Here is an example script for same scenario for an Input_file(since no samples for array elements were provided so explaining it with an sample/example script here).

```
##Shell variable
var="bla"

##A sample Input_file
cat << EOF > Input_file
blabla test test
123abcd123test
bla
EOF

##Following is the code to check.
if grep -q -P "^$var$" Input_file
then
     echo "match found."
fi
```

Above will only match lines which are starting with variable `val`'s value.