# checking if a string exists in an array of strings in bash

Tags: bash

I know how to compare two string in bash:

```
if [ "$build_type" = "devite" ]; then
  echo "building'"
fi
```

But what I need is to check if "$build_type" is in ["devite", "relite"]

so something similar to this:

```
if [ "$build_type" in ["devite", "relite"] ]; then
  echo "building'"
fi
```

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: `bash` doesn't have lists. The closest analogy would be to check if a string is a key in a given associative array.

Comment: @chepner how can I achieve the above like this: if "$build_type"="dev" or "$build_type"=rel?

Comment: Agreed, don't do this. If you happen to have a bash array variable and you want to know if it contains a particular piece of text, I would expand it to a string using printf, and then check that.

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Join two `test`/`[` commands with `||`:

```
if [ "$build_type" = devite ] || [ "$build_type" = relite ]; then
  echo "building"
fi
```

or use a `case` statement.

```
case $build_type in
  devite|relite) echo "building" ;;
esac
```

If the targets are in an associative array, you can check for the existence of a key.

```
declare -A targets=([devite]= [relite]=)

if [[ -v targets[$build_type] ]]; then
    echo "building"
fi
```

Comment: I would propose to always use double quotes around a variable use (`"$build_type"` instead of `$build_type`).  Who knows what's in that variable, maybe spaces?  Then it would give weird errors in the `case` case.

Comment: The expansion used for an array index isn't subject to pathname expansion or word-splitting.

Comment: But in the `case` case it is necessary (`case $build_type in`), isn't it?  EDIT: doesn't seem to be, interesting.  That sounds like a weird exception to me …  I would still propose to use them, just because memorizing all the different cases can be error-prone so that in the end one might leave them away in a different case where they would have been necessary, and they never are wrong.  To me a use without double quotes already looks like "I explicitly want the word split here in this case".

Comment: `case`, as a special compound statement, doesn't have to follow the usual rules for evaluating a simple command. Since the purpose is to compare the value of `$build_type` to the patterns inside the statement, there is no reason to perform either word-splitting or pathname expansion on parameter expansions following the keyword `case`, which is the only reason you would have to quote it.

Comment: Yeah, I see the reasoning.  I still would always use double quotes unless I really want a word splitting.  But of course that's rather a personal opinion.

Answer (score 7):

I would use a `case` for this, hmm, case:

```
case "$build_type" in
  devite|relite)
    echo "building"
    ;;
esac
```

The pipe symbol (`|`) specifies an `or` logic.

Of course with the `case` shell builtin you can do much more like have several cases with different handling code, but it is the easiest to read thing for a fixed list of fixed simple strings (with special characters in the strings it might become a quoting nightmare).

If you really want to use a list array, I would use a loop:

```
names=( devite relite )
for name in "${names[@]}"
do
  if [ "$build_type" = "$name" ]
  then
    echo "building"
    break  # leave the loop
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends how you have the target strings.  If they are in an array (eg `a=(devite relite)`, you could do:

```
if [[ "${a[@]}" =~ $build_type ]]; then ...
```

Comment: That's also brittle. This will match if `build_type` is something like `ite rel`.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option is to use arrays and `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a types=("devite" "relite")
type=devite
neg=dovite

if grep -q "${type}" <<< "${types[*]}" ; then
        echo "building"
else
        echo "not building"
fi

if grep -q "${neg}" <<< "${types[*]}" ; then
        echo "building"
else
        echo "not building"
fi
```

```
=> building
   not building
```

So many ways to skin that cat :)

Edit: If you cannot trust the input to be valid:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a types=("devite" "relite")
type=devite
neg="ite rel"

function j { local IFS=$'\n'; echo "$*"; }

if grep -q "${type}" <<< $(j "${types[@]}") ; then
        echo "building"
else
        echo "not building"
fi
if grep -q "${neg}" <<< $(j "${types[@]}") ; then
        echo "building"
else
        echo "not building"
fi
```

Comment: A type like `ite rel` will cause a false positive.

Comment: @chepner well, unlikely in real life scenarios, I'd say - and avoidable by localy modifying IFS accordingly (see edit) - but anyway, this is just a pointer in a possible direction

Comment: Why jump through those hoops when there are more efficient solutions (i.e., don't run external programs) that don't need to?