# Compare array elements with an element

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to compare an array with a value and print an error statement if the match is not found.

```
arraylist="$(ls new-dir/ | cut -d' ' -f1)"
```

For example, this stores values such as small, large and medium which are the files present in `new-dir`.
The value to be compared with will be entered by the user viz. var

I have tried something like following:

```
(for i in "${arraylist[@]}"; do [[ "$i" == "$var"]] && exit 0; done) && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

Also tried, however, doesn't work:

```
arraylist="$(ls new-dir/ | cut -d' ' -f1)"
count=0

for((i=0; i<${#arraylist[@]}; i++)); do
  if [ "$arraylist[$i]" == "$var" ] ; then
    count=1
  fi
done

if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Not found"
fi
```

Is there any other way to do this comparison?

Comment: Your syntax to access an array element is wrong. It should have been `${arraylist[$i]}` or `${arraylist[i]}`, since this is an indexed array. And, [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: The whole snippet above could be reduced to `[[ -e new-dir/$var ]] || echo "Not found"` (if it was syntactically correct).

Comment: `arraylist="$(` that's not an array. That's a normal variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value answers your question?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any way in which fetch the files from the directory and store it in an array without manually forming an one?

Comment: @AishwaryaK I don't know what you mean by "without manually forming", but this can be done easily: `files=(dirname/*)`. Note that the array will also contain non-regular files, if any, and won't contain filenames beginning with a `.`, by default.

Answer (score 1):

This code works. Just replace `arraylist` with your array.

```
arraylist=('hello' 'world')
var='hello'
count=0

for i in "${arraylist[@]}"
do
    if [ "$i" == "$var" ]; then
        count=1
    fi
done

if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Not found"
fi
```

Comment: It'd be better to break on first match after `count=1` since there is no need to continue looping.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the first "word" from each filename, I'd do

```sh
declare -A prefixes
cd new-dir
for file in *; do
    read -r prefix _ <<< "$file"
    prefixes["$prefix"]=1
done
cd -
```

then to look for a match:

```sh
# $var is somehow provided
result=""
for p in "${!prefixes[@]}"; do
  if [[ $p == "$var" ]]; then
    result=found
    break
  fi
done
echo "${result:-not found}"
```

This requires bash v4.0+ for the use of an associative array.

If you have bash v4.3+ you can do

```sh
[[ -v prefixes[$var] ]] && echo found || echo not found
```

---

Alternately:

```sh
shopt -s nullglob
files=( new-dir/"$var "* )
(( ${#files[@]} > 0 )) && echo found || echo not found
```

Answer (score -1):

The `arraylist` might be an array with just **one index**.

The command:
`arraylist="$(ls new-dir/ | cut -d' ' -f1)"`
might just assign whole "ls new-dir" output to `${arraylist[0]}`

You can check the index value in an array by `echo ${arraylist[1]}` (to confirm).

Try changing the command to generate an array for a list of files/dirs to:

```sh
arraylist=($(ls new-dir/))
```

The complete script:

```sh
arraylist=($(ls new-dir/))

(for i in "${arraylist[@]}"; do [[ "$i" == "$var" ]] && exit 0; done) && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

---

You can also ignore the whole array assignment and just use subshell-command in for loop, eg:

```sh
(for i in $(ls -1 new-dir/); do [[ "$i" == "$var" ]] && exit 0; done) && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

Remember, no quotes `"` around `$(ls -1 new-dir/)`

---

Another one-liner without any array or loops:

```sh
ls -1 new-dir/ | grep -q "$var" && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

Edit:
As *@M. Nejat Aydin* suggested, use `[[ -e new-dir/$var ]] && echo "found" || echo "Not found"` and [do not use `ls` in the script](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: "a simple one-liner" could be even simpler without external commands `ls` and `grep` and subshell: `[[ -e k8s_apps/$var ]] && echo "found" || echo "Not found"`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin
 Well, you have already shared the same one-liner as a comment to OPs question. I didn't think it is a good idea to repeat the answer. The idea here is to provide alternatives.

Comment: The problem is that, it isn't an alternative; it may fail in many cases. For example, the variable `var` may contain spaces or wildcard characters (such as `*`). Also filenames may contain some weird characters. The use of `ls` isn't a correct way to get the list of files within a script.

Answer (score -1):

This is what shell programming is about. Keep it simple :

```
Array1=( "item1" "item2" "item3" "item-4" )
var="item3"

count=$(echo ${Array1[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '$1 == "'"$var"'"{print $0}' | wc -l)
[ $count -eq 0 ] && echo "Not found" || echo "found"
```

Comment: I've downvoted just because I don't find this answer useful and it may fail in many cases; for example when array elements contain spaces or wildcard characters. And my comment wasn't intended as a solution.