# User input in while loop for Linux scripts

Tags: shell

I am writing a script that accepts a user input to start a while loop, right now my syntax for it is

```
echo -e "Would you like to run the script? (Y or N): \c"
read ans
while [ $ans = "Y" ]
do
     #the script
```

My question is how can I make this accept multiple inputs? I would like for the script to be able to accept other forms of Y, such as Yes, yes, or y. I tried to this by changing the code to:

```
echo -e "Would you like to run the script? (Y or N): \c"
read ans
while [ $ans = "Y","Yes","y","yes" ]
do
     #the script
```

but it still gave me errors. Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: I am incredibly new to linux and didn't know what syntax to try out to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -e "Would you like to run the script? (Y or N): \c"
read ans
y_arr=("Y" "Yes" "y" "yes")
while [[ " ${y_arr[@]} " =~ " $ans " ]]; do echo 'y' && break; done;
```

Store the accepted forms in an array, and check whether the input parameter in them.

Reference from ["Check if a Bash array contains a value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value)