# How do I see if the output of one command is in the output of another?

Tags: bash, comm

I have two commands. The first, when stored in a script variable, gives output like this:

```
one two three four five
```

The second also gives a list, but some of the items may be missing that were in the first command:

```
one three five
```

I want my script to do something if an item is in the first command but not the second. None of the items will have spaces (they tend to be `kabab-format`). How can I do this in Bash?

Comment: Save those 2 outputs to an array, that will give you all the control you'll need.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value/15394738#15394738 for how to test if an array contains a value. Loop over the first array, and test if the second array contains the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using the current variables, and relying on the fact that individual values do not contain embedded white space:

```
$ var1='one two three four five'
$ var2='one three five'
$ comm -23 <(printf "%s\n" ${var1} | sort) <(printf "%s\n" ${var2} | sort)
four
two
```

**NOTE:** do **not** wrap the `${var1}` and `${var2}` references in double quotes, ie, we **want** word splitting to occur when feeding the `printf` calls

---

Another idea using an associative array to track unique values:

```
var1='one two three four five'
var2='one three five'

unset      arr
declare -A arr

for f in ${var1}          # use ${var1} values as indices for arr[]
do
    arr[${f}]=1           # '1' has no meaning other than to fill requirement of assigning a value in order to create the array entry
done

for f in ${var2}          # delete ${var2} indices from arr[]
do
    unset arr[${f}]
done


for i in "${!arr[@]}"     # display arr[] indices that remain
do
    echo "${i}"
done

# one-liners (sans comments)

for f in ${var1}; do arr[${f}]=1; done
for f in ${var2}; do unset arr[${f}]; done
for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do echo "${i}"; done
```

This generates:

```
two
four
```

**NOTES:**

- again, do **not** wrap the `${var1}` and `${var2}` references in double quotes, ie, we **want** word splitting to occur
- if so inclined OP could perform the same add/remove array operations in a single `awk` script
- the first loop (populating `arr[]` from `${var1}`) will eliminate duplicates from `${var1}`, eg, `var1='one one one'` would lead to a single array entry: `arr[one]=1`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding my comment <sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69181602/how-do-i-see-if-the-output-of-one-command-is-in-the-output-of-another/69181723#comment122274895_69181602)</sup>, I'd tackle this like following:

- Loop over `res1`

  - [If current value does not exist in `res2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value)

    - Preform action
    - Stop `for` if needed

```sh
#!/bin/bash

res1=(one two three four five)
res2=(one three five)

for value in "${res1[@]}"; do
    if [[ ! "${res2[*]}" =~ "${value}" ]]; then

        # Do action
        echo "'$value' does not exist in res2"

        # Possibly stop for loop
        break
    fi
done
```

With the `break`, this will show:

```
'two' does not exist in res2
```

Without the `break`, it will show:

```
'two' does not exist in res2
'four' does not exist in res2
```