# Selecting values based on parameter in bash

Tags: bash

I am writing my first bash script and I can't find the solution to my problem.
Lets say I am calling `ls -l` and I want to save the names of certain files to a variable.

Output of `ls -l`:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1     125 Apr 19  2021  aaa
drwxrwxr-x  5 user2 user2    4096 Sep  7 15:54  bbbb
drwxr-xr-x  4 user3 user3    4096 Mär 16  2021  cccc
drwxr-xr-x  7 user1 user1    4096 Mai 18 15:32  asdf
```

To parse the output I use the following command:

```
`ls -l | while read a b c d e f g h j; do echo $c $j
```

Which results to:

```
user1 aaa  
user2 bbbb
user3 cccc
user1 asdf
```

Now the step I cant figure it out is how to filter out based on on the values of `j`. Lets say, we have an array `values=(aaa cccc)`. How could I extend my command, so that it prints out the users only if the value of `j` is a value in the array `values` ?

Final result should be:

```
user1 aaa
user3 cccc
```

Comment: [Do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). `find -printf '%u %p\n' | while IFS=' ' read -r u p; do....` Check your scripts with shellcheck - it will help you.

Comment: Or, `ls -l -- "${values[@]}"`.

Comment: `ls -l | grep '  aaa$|  ccc$' | ...`

Answer (score 0):

> How could I extend my command, so that it prints out the users only if the value of j is a value in the array values ?

For each line, check if the second column is in the array. [Check if a Bash array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value)

```
containsElement () {
  local e match="$1"
  shift
  for e; do [[ "$e" == "$match" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}

result="user1 aaa  
user2 bbbb
user3 cccc
user1 asdf"

values=(aaa cccc)

printf "%s\n" "$result" |
while IFS=' ' read -r user file; do
    if containsElement "$file" "${values[@]}"; then
        printf "%s %s\n" "$user" "$file"
    fi
done
```

A more crude solution would be to:

```
... | grep -f <(printf ' %s$\n' "${values[@]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be simpler if your array was an associative one (supported by recent versions of bash):

```sh
declare -A values=([aaa]=1 [cccc]=1)
ls -l | while read a b c d e f g h j; do [ -v values[$j] ] && echo "$c $j"; done
```

If your bash version supports associative arrays but not yet the `[ -v var ]` test, you can replace it by `[ -n "${values[$j]+ok}" ]`.

But as explained in comments parsing the `ls` output is strongly discouraged. In your case any file name with spaces or tabs, or even worse, newline characters, would break all this.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the owner of each file, use `stat`. (If a single call to `stat` per file is too big a bottleneck compared to one call to `ls`, then you shouldn't be using `bash` in the first place: use a language which provides direct access to the underlying system calls to retrieve the owner.)

```
for v in "${values[@]}"; do
    user=$(stat ... "$v")  # See man stat for the correct invocation
    echo "$user $v"
done
```