# Bash diference between quotes with/without space

Tags: linux, bash, shell, posix, contains

I was trying to check if an array contained a value and I found [Check if a Bash array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value)

It did not work for me, and it was because I decided to remove the spaces surrounding the quotes, like this:

```bash
words=(aa bb cc)
[[ " ${words[@]} " =~ " a " ]] && echo "YES" || echo "NO"; # This is the real answer, and it works
------
[[ "${words[@]}" =~ "a" ]] && echo "YES" || echo "NO"; # This does not work. Why???
```

1. Whats the difference when you surround them with spaces or when you dont?

And for my curiosity. In the previous question I mentioned, some answers/comments go with:

`${array[*]}`, and others with `${array[@]}`

2. Do they both "iterate" through the loop in the same way?

Comment: `Do they both "iterate" through the loop in the same way?` No, that's why `*` should be used here. `This does not work. Why???` What do you "not work"? It executes with no errors on my terminal. Does your shell crashes? What happens? What does not happen? What did you expect to happen? `Do they both "iterate" through the loop in the same way?` Please one question per question. I am _sure_ there is already a question how `@` differs from `*` and I am sure it is explained in bash manual.

Comment: @KamilCuk It does not work, since I expect it to find only "aa", or "bb", or "cc", in the array, but in the first case, it says "a" is contained on ("aa", "bb", "cc")

Comment: `words=(aa bb cc); [[ "${words[@]}" =~ "a" ]] && echo "YES" || echo "NO";` outputs `YES` for me. Och, you mean it should output `NO`, because there is no array element with exactly `a`? Ok, now I get you. Doesn't the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value explain what is happening? What is unclear to you?

Comment: There is no iteration in your code. As for the quotes, the double quotes to the right of the regexp operator tells bash to **not** treat the quoted part as a regexp. For instance, `[[ x =~ . ]]` is true while `[[ x =~ "." ]]` is false.

Comment: `" ${words[@]} "` normally expands to three words: `" aa"`, `"bb"`, and `"cc "`. But, _word splitting_ isn't performed inside the `[[...]]` construct. So, it expands to a single word, `" aa bb cc "`, and is equivalent to `" ${words[*]} "`, _in this context_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[ string =~ regex ]]` checks if `regex` matches any substring of `string`. That operator does **not** iterate over your array entries as `for entry in "${words[@]}"` would do. It cannot even handle arrays.

`[[ " ${words[@]} " =~ " a " ]]` is only a **hack** for finding array elements. The array is converted into a single string where all array entries are surrounded by spaces. Then, we search for an element using a string search. This only works reliably, if the array entries themselves do not contain any spaces.

For the difference between `${array[*]}` and `${array[@]}` see [bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> If the word is double-quoted, **`${name[*]}` expands to a single word** with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS variable *[= a space by default]*, and **`${name[@]}` expands each element** of name **to a separate word**.

So in this case, `*` would be the logical way to write `[[ " ${words[*]} " =~ " a " ]]`, because it is equivalent to `[[ " aa bb cc " =~ " a " ]]`.
That `@` works here too is somewhat strange, because `[[ " aa" "bb" "cc " =~ " a " ]]` gives a syntax error. Bash tolerating the misused `@` in `[[` is probably an undocumented "feature" related to the (documented) disabled word-splitting inside `[[`. For the basic POSIX test command `[` the difference between `*` and `@` works as expected, meaning `a=("x" "=" "y"); [ "${a[@]}" ]` fails because x != y.