# Check if a Bash array contains a value from another array

Tags: arrays, bash, pattern-matching

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970), how can one use Bash to check if an array contains values from another array?

The reason this comes up is because I'd like to get a list of commands available to a user into an array and then check that against the dependencies for my script, as a way to test the "environment is ready" before continuing. The reason I use `compgen` for this is because it's a builtin and is also available on shared hosts that have jailshells.

Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray available_commands < <(compgen -c)

required_commands=(
  grep
  sed
  rsync
  find
  something-to-fail
)

for required_command in "${required_commands[@]}"; do
  if [[ ${available_commands[*]} =~ ${required_command} ]]; then
    echo "${required_command} found"
  else
    echo "${required_command} not found"
  fi
done
```

It seems to work, but reading through the other answer about `IFS` and so forth, what am I missing here? Or how could the approach be improved, sticking with pure Bash?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `comm` which takes two sorted lists, and outputs a list of items, indented into three columns according to whether they appeared only in the one list, the other list, or both. Individual columns can be suppressed using the `-1`, `-2`, and `-3` flags.

```bash
missing_commands=($(
  comm -23 <(printf "%s\n" "${required_commands[@]}" | sort) <(compgen -c | sort)
))
```

```bash
$ printf "%s\n" "${missing_commands[@]}"
rsync
something-to-fail
```

Comment: As OP's checking the existence of `grep`, `sed`, `find`, etc... then don't you think that `comm` and `sort` might not be available?

Comment: Fair point. They could be tested separately with a static list, while this approach can then be used with a dynamic list of all the other commands.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `compgen` as you can directly check the existence of a command with `command -v`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

required_commands=(
  grep
  sed
  rsync
  find
  something-to-fail
)

for cmd in "${required_commands[@]}"
do
    if command -v "$cmd" >&3
    then
        echo "$cmd found"
    else
        echo "$cmd not found"
    fi
done 3>/dev/null
```

Comment: That's handy, thanks---especially as I see `command` is also a bash built-in. :+1:

Answer (score 2):

You need `readarray -t`, and here it's easier to use pattern (instead of regex) for comparison :

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t available_commands < <(compgen -c)

required_commands=(
  grep
  sed
  rsync
  find
  something-to-fail
)

for required_command in ${required_commands[@]}; do
  if [[ " ${available_commands[*]} " = *\ ${required_command}\ * ]]; then
    echo "${required_command} found"
  else
    echo "${required_command} not found"
  fi
done
```

`-t` is mandatory, otherwise, `newline(\n)` is the last character of each command.

If you use regex, a `dot(.)` in the command would match any character.

Comment: That's great, thanks. Why do you think `-t` is better in this case for `readarray` though? And I assume pattern matching is faster than regex, and that's also a bonus?