# Mysqldump launched by cron and password security

Tags: security, mysql

I wrote a script to backup my MySQL databases using:

```
mysqldump --opt --all-databases -u user -pmypassword > myDump.sql
```

A cron launches it every night and scp the result to another server.
`mypassword` appears in clear in my script, everyone can see it with the appropriate rights. I have been told about /proc issues too (where the cmd run can be seen).

MySQL documentation says:

> Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure. See Section 7.6, "Keeping Your Password Secure".

I have not found this magic 7.6 sections anywhere.

What is the good practice to deal with automatic mysqldump and password security?

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13058 Read the answer posted to the bug report. It leads on to adding password as an options file: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html. Don't know if this will help.

Comment: A bit more infomation: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?s=044cd482ca45a726660c48eff2dfb704&p=5066589&postcount=10

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Quoting the MySQL docs(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html):

> Store your password in an option file. For example, on Unix you can list your password in the [client] section of the .my.cnf file in your home directory:
>
> ```
> [client]
> password=your_pass
> ```
>
> To keep the password safe, the file should not be accessible to anyone but yourself. To ensure this, set the file access mode to 400 or 600. For example:
>
> ```
> shell> chmod 600 .my.cnf
> ```
>
> To name from the command line a specific option file containing the password, use the `--defaults-file=file_name` option, where `file_name` is the full path name to the file.

Comment: Trying this.  I'll know in a few days if it does what I need, once logrotate runs again.

Comment: Bad thing is that MySQL will not ask any password after that. What was wanted is just that password does not become exposed when running _mysqldump_.

Comment: One you add the `--defaults-file=file_name` you must drop the `-p` flag from your command.

Comment: This method stores the password in a plain text file. A more secure method would be to use `mysql_config_editor` to create an encrypted login path. I have posted another answer explaining how to do this.

Answer (score 26):

to add to Sahil's answer above, use --defaults-extra-file

--defaults-extra-file 
is used to tell a program to read a single specific option file in addition to the standard option files.

whereas --defaults-file is read instead of the default my.cnf file.

Comment: Must be the *first* argument to mysqldump, in the form `--defaults-extra-file=my-file`. Took me a few iterations to finally read the documentation...

Comment: This will do the job as expected.

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer stores the password in a plain text file, which could be read by anyone with administrative (root) access. If your database is in a shared hosting environment, this is undesirable.

A better option would be to use `mysql_config_editor` to create an encrypted login path named `mysqldump`. According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html):

> **mysql_config_editor** encrypts the .mylogin.cnf file so it cannot be read as cleartext, and its contents when decrypted by client programs are used only in memory. In this way, passwords can be stored in a file in non-cleartext format and used later without ever needing to be exposed on the command line or in an environment variable.

The following command will create your `mysqldump` login path:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=mysqldump --host=your_hostname --user=your_username --password
```

You will be prompted to enter your password, and the login path you created will be stored in encrypted format. `mysqldump` will automatically use this login path whenever you call it in the future, unless you specify a different login path with the `--login-path` command line option.

Here is how you would invoke `mysqldump` after creating an encrypted login path:

```
mysqldump database_name > output_file
```

Comment: Your command foesn't work, you forgot "set" after mysql_config_editor. Otherwise, this should be the correct answer.

Comment: @SimZal Thanks for noticing that!  I've updated my post.

Comment: I keep getting `Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect`, but the username and password are correct. Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: I figure out why I was getting that error. My credentials weren't correct. Actually, the **hostname** wasn't right. Turns out Hostgator uses another hostname.

Comment: Does this command work only with a single database? What if I need to backup two databases which have different username and password?

Comment: @a.barbieri as I mentioned in the answer, you should be able to use an alternate `--login-path` if you need to store an additional set of credentials. So something like `mysql_config_editor set --login_path=other_account` etc., and then when you invoke mysqldump, you just call the other login_path: `mysqldump --login_path=other_account database_name > output_file`. Docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_login-path

Comment: amazing. Thank you @blendenzo

Answer (score 5):

All answers here are in pieces so sharing **a complete command** which will do the required and must be used if database are heavy in size, `--single-transaction` and `--lock-tables` are very important here

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/home/dangi/.my.cnf -u root --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false --all-databases (or) DATABASE | gzip > OUTPUT.gz;
```

Note: Answer is in add of Avibodha and sahil answer, they have already made the point. I am just putting their answer in single piece of code with `important measure should be taken at time of backing up live database`

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Keeping Passwords Secure](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-security.html) for a good answer. You can store your password in the my.cnf file changing the permissions on that file to keep the password secure.

You can also check the last comment on this page too:

MYSQL_PWD="tinkerbell" mysqldump -ubackup --all-databases > dump.sql

Answer (score 2):

The following method works for me on a Windows machine, if you have 2 versions of MySQL installed, and you are not sure which my.ini is used when you run mysqldump, this will also help:

1, C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini, fine [client], replace it to:

```
[client]
user=my_user
password=my_password
```

2, Use this command:

C:\Program Files\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqldump --default-extra-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" -u my_user db_to_export > db_to_export.sql