# Mysqldump without password in crontab

Tags: backup, mysql, cron

I try to backup my database with mysqldump and cronjobs.

Well, I added the following command to the crontab of user root:

```
*/30 * * * * mysqldump -u root -pVERYSECUREPASSWORD --all-databases > /var/www/cloud/dump_komplett.sql &> /dev/null
```

This works fine so far, but the problem is that the password is set in this command.

So I want to include a .database.cnf file that look like this

```
[mysqldump]
user=root
password=VERYSECUREPASSWORD
```

and changed the mysqldump command to

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/var/crons/mysql/.database.cnf" --all-databases -u root > /var/www/cloud/dump_komplett.sql
```

to solve this problem.

But this command fails with the error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Here are some commands I also tried:

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/var/crons/mysql/.database.cnf" --all-databases > /var/www/cloud/dump_komplett.sql
mysqldump --defaults-file="/var/crons/mysql/.database.cnf" --all-databases > /var/www/cloud/dump_komplett.sql
mysqldump --defaults-file="/var/crons/mysql/.database.cnf" --all-databases -u root > /var/www/cloud/dump_komplett.sql
```

and .database.cnf contents I also tried:

```
[client]
user=root
password=VERYSECUREPASSWORD

[mysqldump]
host=localhost
user=root
password=VERYSECUREPASSWORD

[client]
host=localhost
user=root
password=VERYSECUREPASSWORD
```

Comment: Do any of those commands work from your command line?

Comment: I tried any of these commands from command line, too. (Not only crontab)

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/6861458/1860929

Comment: Thanks for the Link, the user has to be specified in the command and not in the file with the "u" parameter.

Comment: Cool then, have added that as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The user has to be specified in the command and not in the file with the `u` parameter.

For more details on scheduling `cron` jobs using `mysqldump`, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861355/mysqldump-launched-by-cron-and-password-security/6861458#6861458)

Answer (score 10):

I found out that password should be between quotes

```
[client]
user=root
password="VERYSECUREPASSWORD"
```

Took me a while to figure out why it didn't work with passwords with lots of non alfanumeric symbols

Comment: Use quotes in long passwords with @#%^! characters in the password