# Why won't cron execute this mysql routine properly?

Tags: cron, mysql

I have a cron job set up

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u omeka_admin -h localhost omeka > /home/groups/omeka/database/omeka.sql > /dev/null
```

Pass is stored in .my.cnf. It works great from the command line but everytime cron executes it, the resulting file is size zero

I tried putting in the pass, but got the same result. Again, it works great from the command line. Just in case there was some weird process going that interfered with the output but it's still not working

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Did you mean to do `&> /dev/null` in the end of the task? Also, just for clarification, your cron doesn't work even if you put the password within the cron command itself?

Comment: Also, check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6861458/1860929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove last redirection

```
... omeka > /home/groups/omeka/database/omeka.sql
```

or redirect stderr

```
... omeka > /home/groups/omeka/database/omeka.sql 2> /dev/null
```