# Cron Job mysqldump to daily folder

Tags: mysql, cron, cpanel

I've created a cron job to dump a table from a database and it works fine:

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword dbname tablename > .../backups/matches.sql
```

This saved the file (note the ... is just the prefix of the location).

What I'd like to do is save this daily to a folder within backups.   For example, backups/20150909/matches.sql

How can I achieve this with a variable?
Will the cron job create the folder if it does not exist?

Any help would be appreciated.   There will be numerous tables that I want to backup daily, so I'd like to simply set up each cron job to do this.

Comment: Why do you save on same dir and use dat on filename such backups/20150909.sql with mysqldump -u username -ppassword dbname tablename > .../backups/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)-matches.sql
: Another question, use -u username -ppassword it's insecure. Best way use .my.cnf on user that run cron. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861355/mysqldump-launched-by-cron-and-password-security

Comment: without php, only cron... date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d); mkdir /path/backups/$(date); mysqldump -u username -ppassword dbname tablename > /path/backups/$(date);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using PHP for my backup.

```
if(!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir);
}
if(!file_exists($dir)) {
    echo "Directory (" . $dir . ") was not created.<br />";
} else {
    echo "Directory (" . $dir . ") successfully created.<br />";
}
```

I then proceeded to get the tables

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
$search = "SHOW TABLES";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $search);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
  {
    $tables[] = $row['Tables_in_p3pro_p3live'];
}
```

Next was to write the sql files

```
foreach($tables as $key=>$value) {
    $string = "mysqldump -u *username* -p*password* *dbname* " . $value . " > *path_to_dir*/backups/" . $foldername . "/" . $value . ".sql";

    exec($string);
    echo $value . " backup completed. <br />";
}
```