# Information about MySQL Cron jobs

Tags: mysql, cron

I've one small question about the cron job, 
Do I have to insert my data plain text in here?

```
mysql --user=[MyUser] --password=[Mypassword] --database=[mydbname] --execute="Query Here"
```

I've seen one topic saying not to put the password plaintext in there but to use -ppassword.
but I'm not sure how is that not plaintext if I am going to put my password after the -p anyway?
Some information about it would be appreciated :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: the main thing is that if someone has access to the bash script, command history, and the like, then there is a good chance they can have a field day with your data

Comment: So I take it as a yes

Comment: I didn't see it as a yes or no question. Rather, what is going to happen. One is going to forget all the places passwords are baked in. PHP, bash, up arrow on command history. At that point access to your scripts are less important than the perpetrator making off with the password and tomfoolery.

Comment: dozens of ways. Like reading from vaults. Others are reading from secured files http://stackoverflow.com/q/6861355