# expect script not working in cron but runs successfully in terminal

Tags: bash, cron, scripting, expect

Here is my expect script named as script.exp which runs successfully when executed from terminal. But it doesn't run when scheduling through cronjob.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn /home/user1/sql_backup.sh
match_max 100000
expect -exact "Enter password: "
send -- "pass123\r"
expect eof
```

my bash script named as sql_backup.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > /home/user1/mysql/mysql-bkp.sql
```

and my cronjob is:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/expect -f /home/user1/script.exp
```

Thanks

Comment: Use absolute path for all the executables in your script, or define/set the PATH via cron entry.

Comment: @Jetchisel : I don't think that setting `PATH` would have an effect on starting the script, because if a program is started by giving a relative path, the PATH variable is not used. Of course an incorrect setting of PATH may affect what happens _inside_ the invoked shell script.

Comment: See: [Mysqldump launched by cron and password security](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6861355/3776858)

Comment: @user1934428, Right I forgot to add that if you set the PATH then don't use the `./` for the executable.

Comment: @user1934428 Both the scripts are in same directory. I've also tried setting full path. it doesn't run with cronjob. But it runs successfully when executing from terminal.

Comment: try adding `set env(TERM) linux` before `spawn`.

Answer (score 0):

The working directory of the script does not contain a `sql_backup.sh`. Do a

```
cd /home/user1
```

(or whereever your Shell script is stored). See [here](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl35.html) for the Tcl `cd` command.

Comment: Both the scripts are in same directory. I've also tried setting full path. it doesn't run with cronjob. But it runs successfully when executing from terminal.

Comment: It is not relevant whether or not the scripts are in the same directory. I said that you need to make sure that the **working directory** is set correctly.

Comment: @NitinKumar: And, if you did place your full path in the script, update your question so that one can see, how you did it. Finally, _doesn't run_ is an unusuable error description. What does it mean? If things go wrong, you usually get some error message. I don't see in your posting that you would collect the error logs from your cron job. How are you then going to debug the problem?

Comment: I don't see any error in logs
Nov  1 11:10:01 bitsify CRON[102105]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/expect -f /home/user1/script.exp)
Nov  1 11:10:01 bitsify CRON[102104]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Nov  1 11:11:01 bitsify CRON[102111]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/expect -f /home/user1/script.exp)
Nov  1 11:11:01 bitsify CRON[102110]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Nov  1 11:12:01 bitsify CRON[102121]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/expect -f /home/user1/script.exp)
Nov  1 11:12:02 bitsify CRON[102119]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: @NitinKumar change your crontab to `* * * * * /usr/bin/expect -f /home/user1/script.exp > /tmp/crontab.log 2>&1` You should be able to see some messages in /tmp/crontab.log

Comment: @NitinKumar : Don't place such information into a comment. Put it nicely formatted into your question. Note that you can *edit* your question, for providing additiional information. BTW - AFIK, cron sends you the stderr of the jobs by email, so you won't find it in the logs anyway.