# Mysqldumper: Dumping each table separately

Tags: mysql, git

How can I dump each mysql table separately with mysqldump?

Background: I want to track those dumps with git and using the pre-commit hook

Example:
I have a schema with 10 tables (table1 - table10).
now I want a file per table:
table1.sql
table2.sql
...

So how gonna this work?

Snd why stackoverflow don't like my question?

Comment: What do you mean with `Snd why stackoverflow don't like my question?`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669121/dump-all-mysql-tables-into-separate-files-automagically/6300583

Answer (score 36):

This should work in a shell:

```
for x in `mysql --skip-column-names -u [username] -p[password] [dbname] -e 'show tables;'`; do
     mysqldump -u [username] -p[password] [db name] $x > "$x.sql"
done
```

Comment: Actually Naveen Kumar's answer is better than mine.

Comment: No, your answer is better :) thanx

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqldump -t -u [username] -p test mytable
```

will dump the table 'mytable' from the database 'test'.

If you want to automate the procedure, you will need to write a script, that 
selects the table_names from the schema for you and apply the operation above
for each table. You can automate the git operations as well.

Comment: Depends on your operation system. If you're using Linux - bash scripting probably.