# How to export all tables in separate sql files

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, backup, database-backups

I have to upload my database on *godaddy* host but it restricted to upload more than 8 MB file. So I have decided to upload my table one by one. I am looking for a query or a way to export each table one by one, is there any way available to do this job easily? That I get each table sql with the data?

I am using PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: How do you access the MySQL?

Comment: through its account, whats up?

Comment: I mean are you using shell command to access MySQL or via PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: I am accessing PHPMyAdmin

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan  are you importing from phpmyadmin only ? or from mysql workbench ?

Comment: using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 8):

You can import tables from phpmyadmin as follows :

[image: importing table wise]

You also get option to include data along with table schema.

Comment: which version you are using? it is not available

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan : Phpmyadmin-4.6.5.2, MySQL-10.1.21-MariaDB

Comment: i have mysql 5.6.12  and this option is not available

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan : try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359053/mysqldumper-dumping-each-table-separately