# MySQLdump with arguments

Tags: bash, mysql

Hello to professionals !
There was a good and simplest script idea to make mysqldump of every database - taken from
[dump all mysql tables into separate files automagically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669121/dump-all-mysql-tables-into-separate-files-automagically)
author - https://stackoverflow.com/users/1274838/elias-torres-arroyo
with script as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
# Optional variables for a backup script
MYSQL_USER="root"
MYSQL_PASS="PASSWORD"
BACKUP_DIR="/backup/01sql/";
# Get the database list, exclude information_schema
for db in $(mysql -B -s -u $MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS -e 'show databases' | grep -v information_schema)
do
# dump each database in a separate file
mysqldump -u $MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS "$db" | gzip > "$BACKUP_DIR/$db.sql.gz"
done
sh
```

but the problem is that this script does not "understand" arguments like

```
--add-drop-database
```

to perform

```
      mysqldump -u $MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS "$db" --add-drop-database | gzip > "$BACKUP_DIR/$db.sql.gz"
```

Is there any idea how to force this script to understand the additional arguments listed under

```
    mysqldump --help
```

because while all my tests shows it doesn't.
Thank you in advance for any hint to try !

Comment: `but the problem is that this script does not "understand" arguments like`, WHat error do you get ? What do you mean by "does not understand"?

Comment: no errors at all. Just no reaction. If I add --add-drop-database - it does not perform it. So I try to guess while.

Comment: ...can't understand local comments system...I mean - no errors at all. Just no reaction. If I add --add-drop-database - it does not perform it. The basic code looks very direct and simple - but does not react to any arguments listed under mysqldump --help. So I try to guess why.  May be a specific syntax should be used ?

Comment: What if you give some garbage option? does it give you syntax error or something? if it does, then I guess `--add-drop-database` is doing what it is supposed to do, just that it does not throw any output on hte screen.

Comment: Of course I check the dump file output after performing of the script above. Even with --add-drop-database - as I said above - nothing in dump file. So this argument (under this code) does nothing.

Comment: tagged the question with `mysqldunp` hoping some one good at mysqldump will help you.

Answer (score 0):

`--add-drop-database` works only with `--all-databases` or `--databases`.
See please the reference in [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_add-drop-database)

So in your case mysqldump utility ignore mentioned parameter because you are going to dump one database.

Comment: Thank you ! Yes, you're right... it's sad but true :) Best regards !