# Postgresql: How to export tables into separate csv files

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I want to export the entire database to aws S3 to later import into BI tools. I need to export each database table into its own csv file. But I dont wanna do it manually or do some script-fu. [MySQL have something for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669121/dump-all-mysql-tables-into-separate-files-automagically). Is there an easy way to achieve this with Postgresql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this query you can list all tables in the schema `public`:

```
select table_schema, table_name 
from information_schema.tables
where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
and table_schema = 'public';
```

You can use the query in a function, which will execute appropriate `copy` command for each table_name:

```
create or replace function copy_my_tables ()
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
    r record;
begin
    for r in
        select table_schema, table_name 
        from information_schema.tables
        where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
        and table_schema = 'public'
    loop
        execute format ('copy %s.%s to ''c:\data\%s_%s.csv'' (format csv)',
            r.table_schema, r.table_name, r.table_schema, r.table_name);
    end loop;
end $$;

select copy_my_tables();
```

Comment: Plus 1. Can I also insert column name into csv?

Comment: @MAK - Yes, add `header` as an option in `copy` command, i.e. `copy ... (format csv, header)`.

Comment: Hey yup! I got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

we can export All table in separate csv with Header with in schema ,from bash scripts

```
#set -x
read -p "Please provide Schema name   " Schema
if [ -z $Schema ]
then
    echo "No Schema name provided set default schema public."
Schema=public
fi
read -p "Please provide Database name  " Db
if [ -z $Db ]
then
    echo "No Database name provided set default database postgres."
Db=postges
fi
read -p "Please provide Postgres Role/User name  " User
if [ -z $User ]
then
    echo "No User/Role name provided set default User?Role postgres."
User=postgres
fi

echo " Schema Name is-->$Schema   Database Name--> $Db   User Name-->$User "

psql -U $User -h localhost -Atc "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname='$Schema'" $Db |\
  while read TABLENAME; do
        echo "$TABLENAME"
    psql -U $User -h localhost -c "COPY $Schema.$TABLENAME TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER" $Db  > $TABLENAME.csv
  done
```

In  above mention script you have to provide 
Schema 
database and 
User/Role 
 if there is required to provide port and host name then you can use -p and -h Option