# How to mysqldump only database data without structure in separate sql scripts for each table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have quite large database and if I generate only one file for all inserts for all databases it is too much to handle.
I would need separate SQL scripts for inserting data for each table in database.

When I first dumped structure with this command it was perfect, I got one SQL script for each table containing create statements:

```
mysqldump --user=dbuser --password --no-data --tab=/output/ dbname
```

If I use same configuration only with other options like `--no-create-info`, `--no-create-db`, `--extended-insert`, `--complete-insert` like this:

```
mysqldump --user=dbuser --password \
  --complete-insert --extended-insert \
  --no-create-info --tab=/output/ dbname
```

I get for each table one empty SQL script and one .txt file with only data (without insert into statement).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dump all mysql tables into separate files automagically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669121/dump-all-mysql-tables-into-separate-files-automagically)

Comment: You're going to have to iterate over a list of tables and run this command once each time.