# How do i dump all the tables from a single database in a sql file except for the ones mentioned?

Tags: mysql

I wanted to know if it was possible can do a db dump of all the tables in a database, but leaving a couple of tables specified on the command line. this is for mysql. i know there is one for adding specific tables on an sql, but i dont know if you can exclude specific tables. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425158/skip-certain-tables-with-mysqldump I'm pretty sure this has the answer that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqldump has an --ignore-table option.

Comment: awesome, i was looking in the man page and it didnt have it, but it did on --help page. i do have a question, how is this set up on the --help page its --ignore-table=database.table, what if i want multiple tables?

Comment: nm, the above link answered it thanx