# ignore one table with mysqldump?

Tags: mysql

I have this big database (100+ tables and 30+ million rows) that is being a pain in the ass to import back from a full backup.

Problem is that one table contains most of the data (about 27 million rows) and is entirely static. So I was wondering if it was possible to specify 1 table to ignore when creating a backup with mysqldump (instead of listing every table but the one I want to ignore)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skip certain tables with mysqldump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425158/skip-certain-tables-with-mysqldump)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use ['--ignore-table=db_name.tbl_name'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table).