# Dump only the data with mysqldump without any table information

Tags: mysql, database, dump, database-table, database-dump

I am looking for the syntax for dumping all data in my mysql database. I don't want any table information.

Comment: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-definition-data-dumps.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-definition-data-dumps.html)

Answer (score 681, accepted):

```
mysqldump --no-create-info ...
```

Also you may use:

- `--skip-triggers`: if you are using triggers
- `--no-create-db`: if you are using `--databases ...` option
- `--compact`: if you want to get rid of extra comments

Comment: Here is the full cmd for the copy pasters `mysqldump -u USERNAME -h HOST --no-create-info --skip-triggers YOURDATABASENAME YOURTABLENAME --where='id=12345678'`

Comment: If you get ``Access denied for user ... to database '...' when doing LOCK TABLES``, use ``--single-transaction``

Comment: @YzmirRamirez thanks but FYI on windows I had to use double-quotes for `--where`. For example, `--where="id=2"`

Answer (score 192):

This should work:

```bsh
# To export to file (data only)
mysqldump -u [user] -p[pass] --no-create-info mydb > mydb.sql

# To export to file (structure only)
mysqldump -u [user] -p[pass] --no-data mydb > mydb.sql

# To import to database
mysql -u [user] -p[pass] mydb < mydb.sql
```

**NOTE:** there's no space between `-p` & `[pass]`

Comment: `--no-create-db` is redundant when using `--no-create-info`

Comment: A space after `-p` is fine

Comment: @JamesMcMahon Unless you are using `--databases` as well.

Comment: It's generally better to just use -p without supplying the password so that the password isn't stored in your bash history (you'll be prompted to enter the password after you run the command).

Comment: In addition to @Dan's advice, it also makes password visible to any user who can list current processes (`ps -ef`)

Comment: Good explanation

Comment: Leaving out password after the `-p` option makes `mysqldump` prompt for password.

Comment: Regarding password argument I prefere to use the explicit version  
`--password='MyOddlyLongPAssword2018'`
This way I don't have mistakes about spaces between -p and password and if I use single quotes it usually protects specific characters like `<` from screwing up the command.

Comment: unfortunately, mysql allocates a fixed buffer for -p input which is exceeded by a moderately strong password. unless this issue has been fixed in recent years.

Comment: @Thankyou A space after `-p` will prompt a password.

Answer (score 29):

If you just want the INSERT queries, use the following:

`mysqldump --skip-triggers --compact --no-create-info`

Comment: thank you for `--compact` which gets rid of the extra comment statements

Answer (score 24):

```
 >> man -k  mysqldump [enter in the terminal]
```

you will find the below explanation

> --no-create-info, -t
>
> Do not write CREATE TABLE statements that re-create each dumped table.
>   Note This option does not not exclude statements creating log file
>   groups or tablespaces from mysqldump output; however, you can use the
>   --no-tablespaces option for this purpose.
>
> --no-data, -d
>
> Do not write any table row information (that is, do not dump table
>   contents). This is useful if you want to dump only the CREATE TABLE
>   statement for the table (for example, to create an empty copy of the
>   table by loading the dump file).

```
# To export to file (data only)
mysqldump -t -u [user] -p[pass] -t mydb > mydb_data.sql

# To export to file (structure only)
mysqldump -d -u [user] -p[pass] -d mydb > mydb_structure.sql
```

Comment: is there a reason for using twice the '-t' and '-d' option ?

Answer (score 8):

Best to dump to a compressed file

```
mysqldump --no-create-info -u username -hhostname -p dbname | gzip > /backupsql.gz
```

and to restore using pv `apt-get install pv` to monitor progress

```
pv backupsql.gz | gunzip | mysql -uusername -hhostip -p dbname
```

Comment: Should `pv` and `gunzip` be swapped?

Comment: if it makes you happy, then treat yourself :)

Comment: My bad, it looks like `pv` can also be used this way.

Answer (score 3):

Would suggest using the following snippet. Works fine even with huge tables (otherwise you'd open dump in editor and strip unneeded stuff, right? ;)

```
mysqldump --no-create-info --skip-triggers --extended-insert --lock-tables --quick DB TABLE > dump.sql
```

At least mysql **5.x** required, but who runs old stuff nowadays.. :)

Comment: I ran into a situation recently, where had to connect to a system that was using 4.x in production.  They had spaces in table and column names, and in my opinion, they were doing basically everything wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For example, using [-t(--no-create-info)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-info), you can export only the data of the tables of `apple` database to `backup.sql` with `INSERT` statement which doesn't have column names as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77363989#77363989) explains how to export both the schema and data of the tables of a database:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -t apple person > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p --no-create-info apple > backup.sql
```

And, using [-c(--complete-insert)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_complete-insert), you can export only the data of the tables of `apple` database to `backup.sql` with [INSERT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) which has column names as shown below:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -t -c apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p --no-create-info --complete-insert apple > backup.sql
```

And, not using or using [--tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tables), you can export only the data of the specific tables `person` and `animal` of `apple` database to `backup.sql` with `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -t -c apple person animal > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p --no-create-info --complete-insert apple --tables person animal > backup.sql
```

And, using [--ignore-table=.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table), you can export only the data of the tables except `person` and `animal` of `apple` database to `backup.sql` with `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below. *You must use multiple `--ignore-table` to specify multiple tables and you must specify both a database and a table together `<database>.<table>` for `--ignore-table` otherwise there is error:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -t -c apple --ignore-table=apple.person --ignore-table=apple.animal > backup.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Just dump the data in [delimited-text format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump-delimited-text.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try to dump to a delimited file.

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p -t -T/path/to/directory [database] --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=,
```

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to export data using the accepted answer I got an error:

```
ERROR 1235 (42000) at line 3367: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'
```

As mentioned above:

```
mysqldump --no-create-info
```

Will export the data but it will also export the create trigger statements. If like me your outputting database structure (which also includes triggers) with one command and then using the above command to get the data you should also use '--skip-triggers'.

So if you want JUST the data:

```
mysqldump --no-create-info --skip-triggers
```