# mysqldump --no-create-table alternative

Tags: mysql

I have looked in the manual of mysql and I have not seen any parameter called `--no-create-table`  (although `--no-create-db` exists).

**Is there an alternative to not dumping the creation of the table block?**

I need to dump only triggers for that I use:

```
mysqldump --triggers --add-drop-trigger my_db my_table > /dump_path/my_table_triggers.sql
```

Comment: I presume what you want is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109993/mysqldump-data-only

Comment: Yes. You have reason `--no-create-info` Is the answer. Thank you