# How to mysqldump WITHOUT dropping any tables

Tags: mysql, sql, backup

Normally, when I backup the database, I run a command like this:

```
mysqldump -uuser -p -hhost -Ddatabase > C:\TEMP\db_2018-04-05.sql
```

Inside that file, there are `DROP table` statements. This is normally fine, but I've modified my localhost to have a different schema than the production database.

If I execute this file, it will blow away the important changes to the database schema on my localhost.

All I need is the `INSERT` statements. Is there any flag I can pass `mysqldump` to achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Include the command for the mysqldump ignore the structure.

> mysqldump --no-create-info ...

Comment: this one skips both dropping the table and creating the table

Comment: Also there is the short version `-t`

Answer (score 24):

All you need is add `--skip-add-drop-table` option when using `mysqldump`.

```
$ mysqldump -uuser -p -hhost -Ddatabase --skip-add-drop-table > C:\TEMP\db_2018-04-05.sql
```

Now no DROP TABLE IF EXISTS in SQL files.

see docs of [mysql on `--skip-add-drop-table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html).

Comment: This will still do `CREATE TABLE` statements so if the table exists (as OP mentions), you will get an error like `ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 24: Table 'my_table' already exists`

Answer (score 2):

for dumping only the table data as stated in [Dump only the data with mysqldump without any table information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109993/dump-only-the-data-with-mysqldump-without-any-table-information) do the following:

```
mysqldump --no-create-info ...
```

Also you may use:

`--skip-triggers`: if you are using triggers

`--no-create-db`: if you are using `--databases ...` option

`--compact:` if you want to get rid of extra comments