# Export data from database to sql file with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to export data (only the data, not the tables nor database) from the database to a `SQL` file and save it. How to write a PHP function that does that? I want to call this function in specific circumstances when running specific queries (updating a blog post, for example).

Something like:

```
/*
* Get the data from the database (already specified) and export it to a SQL file
*
* @param  string $dir Where to store the SQL file. Must be a full path.
* @return void
*/
function export_database_data(string $dir) {
  // some code that gets the data and store it in $data
  // don't know what to do here

  // create/update the file
  file_put_contents("$dir/data_backup.sql", $data);
}
```

**Why this?**

(You don't need to read the following to help me solve the problem. I'm including this because I'm sure if don't include this, someone will ask it).

I want to do that because I want to have a backup of the data (only the data; the tables do not matter because I already know how to handle them for backup).

I'm doing this because I will use the PHP function `exec` to run `git` commands and commit the change in the `SQL` file. The end goal is to keep track of the data in the database, which won't be updated often. I need the data in a `SQL` file and I aim to use `git` because it is easy to access and to collaborate with others (I could not think a better solution, and creating my own tracking system would require a lot of work and time).

Comment: Why not use `mysqldump -u [user] -p[pass] --no-create-info mydb > mydb.sql`? Check more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109993/mysqldump-data-only)

Comment: ReynierPm Can I run this command with PHP `exec` function? Is "mydb" the name of the database?

Comment: Fantastic! I'll try it out!  You should post it as the answer!

Comment: Pretty sure one of those tags doesn't belong there.

Comment: Yes, you can run it using `exec` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750531/using-a-php-file-to-generate-a-mysql-dump)

Comment: Much better. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a `mysqldump` command using PHP `exec` function to only export data. Ex:

```
exec('mysqldump -u [user] -p[pass] --no-create-info mydb > mydb.sql');
```

More info:

- [mysqldump data only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109993/mysqldump-data-only)
- [Using a .php file to generate a MySQL dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750531/using-a-php-file-to-generate-a-mysql-dump)

Comment: I'll try and let you know how that goes

Comment: I ran your code and, altough I got no error, it did not create the file. Can you help me again? Where I can post my code (here in the comments or on the post) ?

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong and your command worked !! Thanks!!