# Encrypting/Auto-Expiring Sensitive Information in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, encryption, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a database column that I am storing sensitive information in. It is encrypted and stored via the rubygem [strongbox](https://github.com/spikex/strongbox). Every hour I have a job that runs to clear out rows that have "expired" (are more than 24 hours old).

This all works well but the problem comes when I do a database backup. The data in those columns are never cleared out. I feel that this is not as secure as I once thought.

What would be the best way of storing information in a DB column that has an auto expiration date?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option at this point might be to move the sensitive column to its own DB table (linked via a foreign key) and exclude it from backups like this:
[Skip certain tables with mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425158/skip-certain-tables-with-mysqldump)

Of course, the BEST way is probably to not store the sensitive info at all. Let PCI-compliant services do that dirty work for you.