# Mysqldump, exclude data from tables by query

Tags: mysql

It's possible to ignore tables in *mysqldump* using:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database --ignore-table=database.table1 > database.sql
```

Is it possible to ignore certain records in tables while dumping?

Comment: Use this link - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425158/skip-certain-tables-with-mysqldump) Its already answered their.

Comment: @RohitDalal no, that is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Add this check with respective  table   --where="status='1'" you want to filter the data

mysqldump --opt --user=username --password=password table1 table2  --where="table2.status='1'" > test.sql

Comment: @RohitDalal more likely. Make it an answer.