# mysql dump - exclude some table data and no-data

Tags: mysql

I have a big database with 100 tables
I'm need to create dump. 
98 tables with data and 2 tables only structure

like this

```
mysqldump -u root -p {--no-data db.table99,  table10 } dbname > dump.sql
```

how can i do it with one request ?

Comment: use the --ignore-table, as it is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425158/skip-certain-tables-with-mysqldump

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip certain tables with mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425158/skip-certain-tables-with-mysqldump)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

mysqldump either includes the data, or doesn't. You can't do it with one query.

However, you can safely combine two `mylsqdumps` request into ONE file on bash. First one excludes the tables you don't want but has data, second one has only the 2 tables with no data:

```
{ command1 & command2; } > new_file
```

`command1` => `mysqldump -u root -p --ignore-table=dbname.table99 --ignore-table=dbname.table100 dbname`

`command2` => `mysqldump --no-data -u root -p dbname table99 table100`

Unfortunately, you'd have to supply the password twice. But since you want one line, you can put this in a bash script