# How to export all innodb tables?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am using this command to export all database.

> mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > alldb.sql

But it export all tables including MyISAM, However I want to only export and import innodb tables of all databases.

Comment: Since since is a rather unusual requirement, mysqldump or similar tools do not provide such a feature out of the box. You can (= "have to") list the tables you [want to export](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9306) or that you [want to skip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/425158) yourself. The first link contains a way to generate that list automatically (by filtering for, in your case, the engine-column of [information_schema.tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html)).

Comment: Easy fix: Make all your tables InnoDB! (except for `mysql.*` tables of course).

Comment: Use a `SELECT ... FROM information_schema.TABLES ...` to find the InnoDB tables and build the desired dump(s).

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful exporting and importing data from InnoDB tables.  InnoDB tables "might" contain foreign keys (child and parent table).   If the script executed the child table first, then there's a possibility MySQL might produce an error because the Parent table has not exist yet.     You can do well MyISAM since they are not strict, doesn't care about foreign keys.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps

```
use mysql;
show table status name where engine='innodb';
```

and do a rectangular copy/paste from the Name column:

```
+-----------+--------+---------+------------+-
| Name      | Engine | Version | Row_format |
+-----------+--------+---------+------------+-
| db1       | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |
| db2       | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |
| db3       | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |  |
+-----------+--------+---------+------------+-
```

to a text editor and convert it to a command

```
mysqldump -u username --databases db1 db2 db3 > DUMP.sql
```

Comment: Thank you but Its showing error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'name where
 engine=innodb' at line 1

Comment: This statement will give you the same result:


```
    select table_name, Engine, Version, Row_format FROM information_schema.tables WHERE Engine='InnoDB' AND table_schema = 'yourdbname';

```